# Why is this one-line, incorrect, only-code non-answer supposedly valid?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22751418/2888561) as NAA (declined), then a custom mod flag (declined).

```
background:url('url') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size:cover;
```

This:

- Is incomplete, as it does not explain the code or how to use it.
- Is so short that it does not include the code around the posted answer required to make it *syntactically valid*
- *Makes no attempt to answer my question* - it could be a comment.
- Is a copy-paste of a Google result of googling the question title

And another person agrees with me, as it has a score of -2. So why was my flag declined?

Comment: At the least, post a comment on the answer explaining why you are alleging that it is technically incorrect; that way even if you don't manage to get it deleted, you've at least communicated your objection and (if you feel it is necessary) warned off other readers.

Comment: Why? The answerer obviously didn't read the question or put any effort into the answer.

Comment: Why? Because your objection is a flawed one of principle.  You seem to hold that a single isolated line of code **which solved the problem** would not be a valid answer, when in fact it would be.  Thus, you cannot use the brevity of the answer as an obvious flaw - you need to actually *explain* why it is bad (why it does not solve your problem) if you want to persuade others to adopt and act upon your opinion.  Otherwise you'll have to be content with only the backing of those who reach the same opinion independently.

Comment: It didn't answer my question. It is a comment. It is a bad comment since my question asked how to not do exactly what the answer said.

Comment: You have yet to post a comment on the answer saying why it does not answer your question.  Simply click on the comment link and type "my question asked how to not do exactly what this answer proposes"

Comment: I am not required to explain downvotes, and I prefer not to in cases like this.

Comment: You are not required to explain anything, but when you don't **you will have to be content with only the backing of those who INDEPENDENTLY reach the same conclusion**.

Comment: Do you want that answer deleted because its author made a very simple reading mistake? or do you want that answer deleted because it highlights the fact that the first version of your question was very poorly worded in the first place? and very prone to being misread? After all, she's not the only one who misread the question the way she did. Another person who answered your question also made the exact same mistake she did.

Comment: @Stephan It's a crap answer. I'm sure that everyone can find some reason to think that.

Comment: Sure, it's not a good answer. It happens. People make mistakes. That's what the rating system is for. The next time you write a question, don't start it with "An Elephant, except something different", and then proceed to give us the class of an Elephant (which is the thing that you don't want). Some people on StackOverflow have short attention spans, they'll skim a question, look mostly at the code, and try to answer the question before having read everything. This does not mean that they didn't attempt to answer the question. From their (flawed) perspective, they did attempt to answer it.

Comment: I can make a bot that spams SO, but each time does a `console.log("I'm think this is an answer")`. That will make it "an attempt", so it's unflaggable as NAA. I could make it copy-paste random junk from the question to make it "look like an answer". Half the questions if finds could be n00b questions (it could look at the home page), so "the question is unclear, so I you can't expect me to write a good answer"… ***NO!*** The answer is as bad as spam, since it is of the quality that it might be spam. It deserves (from my point of view) deletion.

Comment: @bjb568 That's a disingenuous argument.  If it's a **good faith attempt** at answering the question, it's an answer.  Don't like it?  Downvote.  A wrong answer is not grounds for instant deletion.

Comment: Spam has a completely different incentive behind it, and therefore can not be dealt the same way. In the case of this particular answer, she's not a bot, she's a live human being, just look at her posting history, her answer was downvoted, she made a mistake, and the most likely outcome is that she will just end up deleting her own answer (the next time she logs back in). At least, that's what I'd do if that happened to me. I'd learn from that mistake, then I'd delete my own answer (because I don't like having negative ratings for my answers showing up in the recent history of my own profile).

Comment: 1) We don't know the intentions. 2) I know it isn't spam, but it has the same quality as spam. 3) It is pretty hard to ignore the question - even if the question is extremely unclear, posting confused answers is not going to help. If it's clear, then you have no excuse for a bad answer (that looks like you didn't read the question). If it's not, then you shouldn't be posting an answer.

Comment: Actually, some answers can help (even if they're bad initially). In your case, it clearly helped, because it made you delete the section of code that partially contributed to the original misunderstanding. Self-correction, self-editing, and self-deletion is an integral part of the process of StackOverflow. It's not like the mods have the time to double-check everything and clean up everything themselves (even if every post is supposedly flagged for them).

Comment: Yeah, that *is* really great. **AS A COMMENT**. Anyway, do you think a VLQ flag would have worked better?

Comment: No, the only that would have helped would have been a written out explanation of your objection.

Comment: This post is so contradicting, in [another post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253227/how-can-we-discourage-over-downvoting-on-questions) on meta you said down-voting and moving on is disrespectful, yet you flag for it to be completely removed and move on without a comment.

Comment: No, I that is not what I said. I said not letting OP learn with comments and edits is bad when you *can* help. This is way beyond the point of no possible help.

Comment: Saying that this answer has the same quality as spam is offensive and entitled -- the person who answered your question gave something that clearly they thought was a valid solution to your problem. Just because they didn't understand it correctly doesn't mean you need to nuke their answer from orbit. The point of SO is that not all answers are the best answer but the best ones will rise to the top. What do you gain by throwing a hissyfit and getting this answer deleted just because it was based on a misreading of your question, when you went out of your way to not give that feedback yourself?

Comment: @sphanley Oh, so going to an old question where I have learned better and saying that you're offended *by the existence of this post* is better?

Comment: @bjb568 For some reason this post had appeared as suggested in a sidebar for me, giving the impression it was a current discussion. My sincerest apologies for missing the fact that it was already settled and you feel you've learned better.

Comment: The sidebar? "Related" or "Community bulletin"?

Comment: It was the Community Bulletin sidebar. My mistake on not checking the comment dates to see that the thread had died down. And again -- apologies for my harsh tone, it just struck a nerve because as someone relatively new here, I feel like this site can sometimes feel unfriendly to people who haven't been here long enough to fully understand the expectations for conduct/answers/etc.

Comment: It shouldn't be on the community bulletin… Weird. I remember when I was unhappy about the treatment of low-reps, I think the situation is getting better tho, slowly.

Comment: Maybe it was related rather than community bulletin, but I don't think I was on meta, so I don't know. Anyway -- I was led here by a link, I didn't just come prowling for some old discussion to rip into, hah. I hope that things are in fact getting better around here rather than worse.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like an answer to me.  It might be a dreadfully shoddy answer by your standards, but it is an answer.

When in doubt, explain why you feel the answer should be deleted in a custom moderator flag, but don't expect moderators to evaluate it for technical content or accuracy, or arbitrarily remove posts unless they are actively harmful to the site and its participants.

The guidelines for using an NAA flag are *implied* in the description for the flag.

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question.  **It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted entirely.**

In other words, if this answer really is a comment, or an edit, or a question, or something that doesn't look like an answer, then it's not an answer.

Comment: Indeed. Some answers are bad. That doesn't make them not answers. It makes them bad answers. Bad answers get downvoted, not flagged.

Comment: It **doesn't** attempt to answer the question. My question said "how can I do y without x", the answer was "x". The answer would work as a comment much better, but I would prefer deletion.

Comment: A little bit of explanation goes a long way.  When in doubt, cast a custom moderator flag (instead of casting an NAA flag and leaving the moderators guessing why) and explain why the answer is harmful and should be removed.

Comment: I did that. "…It makes no attempt to answer the question, even if it did, it has no actual information - it doesn't explain what the code does or how to use it."

Comment: In case I haven't made myself clear, *NAA flags don't explain anything.*  If an answer *looks like an answer,* your flag is going to get declined.

Comment: But how could it look like an answer? I can't think of *any* (on-topic for SO) question which it would be a valid answer to.

Comment: Your last flag text was _This. Is. Not. An. Answer. Gawd! It makes no attempt to answer the question, even if it did, it has no actual information - it doesn't explain what the code does or how to use it._  Guess what, it looks like an answer when reviewed.  If the answer is wrong, then downvote it and move on.  Mods don't decide if an answer is technically correct.

Comment: It looks like an answer because it is not another question, it's not a comment, and it's not an edit that the OP should have put into the question.

Comment: It *would* be a valid comment.

Comment: OK, but you're asking moderators to evaluate the technical content.  We don't do that.  That's what votes are for.

Comment: It's a crap answer that's obviously crap. Mods don't need to evaluate the technical content, that isn't relevant.

Comment: @bjb568 You're providing arguments for why the post fails to complete its attempted goal of answering the question.  The NAA flag is for posts that *don't even attempt to answer the question in the first place*, not for posts that fail to answer the question.  If the post was, "Why do you want to do this?" or "[Click here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for discount Gucci handbags!", then it'd be NAA (and the later would also be spam).

Comment: @bjb568 That you think it's a crap answer is a reason to downvote it.  Not a reason to flag it.

Comment: I wasn't an answer, and I'm not a mind reader so I don't know if it was an attempt or not. How am I supposed to judge this?

Comment: @Servy I thot the point of moderators it to deal with crap.

Comment: @bjb568 No, that is not the case.  It is the responsibility of users to downvote poor quality answers, not the responsibility of moderators to do anything surrounding them.

Comment: Crap that you can't deal with, yes. But you can. Downvote.

Comment: @bjb568 - no, that's the point of toilet paper

Comment: Oh, all right. So when *can* I flag as NAA?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Looking at Q&A, it is just the code showcasing the way the OP explicitly rejected as not acceptable in his question. How can that be a valid answer, irrespective of quality?

Comment: When it's an obvious attempt to communicate with another user (a comment), an apparent edit to the question, or a brand new question.  Any of those things that clearly demonstrate that it's something other than an answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Rule of thumb: *if the moderator has to look at the question to evaluate whether an NAA flag is valid or not, don't use an NAA flag.*

Comment: @Deduplicator That makes the answer wrong which is supposed to be taken care of by the community via downvotes.  Moderators **do not** decide the technical validity of an answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is an *attempt* to answer the question.  Lacking an explanation and/or sufficient code makes it potentially of low quality, or not useful.  That is what downvoting is for.  It could be a *failed* attempt at answering the question, but it is still an *attempt*.

If it's plagiarized from some other source, then flag it claiming that; you should support this claim by including the alleged original source.

Comment: Cannot be an answer if it consists only of the code exemplifying the way the OP explicitly rejected as not acceptable in his question, imho.

Comment: @Deduplicator That makes it an incorrect answer, which is entirely different from not being an *attempt* at an answer.  If you ask me what color the sky is and I say "Green", that's a wrong answer.  If I say, "What's the sky?" then that's Not an Answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator That is when the OP should comment and downvote because the answer is wrong.  It is not a case that the answer should be flagged for the moderators to step in... In this case they flagged it 3 times for us.

Comment: So, if I ask for another word meaning "green", "green" itself is an answer?

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure.  It's a wrong answer, but it's an answer.  If someone posts, "I'm having the same problem, I also want to know some synonyms for green." then *that's* Not an Answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the flag be reworded to "obviously NAA" then, to make it clearer?

Comment: Yeah. NAA is unclear. Not an answer? Then what's an answer? "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question."? Well, you just said that the question is irrelevant in NAA flags, so the description is wrong.

Comment: @Deduplicator, If you say on TV "Iraq had no Weapons of Mass Destruction" and then show in the background image what looks like Weapons of Mass Destruction, it's been proven that people will ignore what was said in favor of what was shown instead. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironic_process_theory Here the problem is not just that he titled his question "Green, except something else". It's that he showed an incomplete code sample for green in his question, which then the answerer copied, pasted, and corrected herself (completely missing what was originally written in the title of the question)

Comment: @Deduplicator SO is not doing a good job as conveying what NAA means but rewording the flag to "obviously NAA" would not resolve the issue. When someone comes on Meta complaining that their NAA flag was denied they are sure that the answer was *obviously* NAA. It was obvious to them and should be obvious to anyone else. What needs to be conveyed with regards to what should and should not be considered NAA cannot be conveyed in just one word.

Comment: @Louis: So, "Not an answer to *any* question", perhaps?

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd expect the response from readers to be "What do you mean by 'not an answer to *any* question'?", which is not necessarily a bad response if they then take care to follow a link that leads them to read up on how this flag works. You could put it up as a feature-request and see how it is received.