# How can we discourage over-downvoting on questions?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, downvotes, voting

Some people go a bit [over the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/2888561) downvoting. It isn't exactly welcoming to new users. My process is this:

Is it a good question? Upvote. If not:

1. Spam? Flag. Otherwise:
2. *Very* obviously bad? Are you sure? OK, GOTO 5. Otherwise:
3. Looks hard to answer (code-wall, terrible formatting, etc.)? Leave a comment on how to improve.

   - Can I improve it myself?

     - Will it save it? Edit, otherwise GOTO 5.
   - No? You're not trying hard enough. Tried harder? Good. Fine, you can GOTO 5.
4. Off topic? Close vote, comment.
5. VLQ. Deserves downvote? Downvote.

Only after considering commenting (so OP can *learn*) and editing (to save a potentially good question) do I downvote. Why? Because downvotes discourage users. It basically says "Your question is bad ([and you should feel bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG2KMkQLZmI)) - nobody should bother reading it". It makes new users feel unwelcome, so they naturally (and partially correctly) assume that we **want** them to feel bad.

> Poorly written question? Down vote and move on.

^ This is such disrespectful behavior. Some people forget that there's a human being on the other end of the Internet who may not be fluent in English. Or the programming language. Or they might not understand Stack Exchange. (All can be forgiven, and eventually corrected.)

I believe that others should do the same as me - try to help, not discourage. 99 out of 100 users have potential, it is up to us to make them feel like using it.

What do you think about this? Can something be done about excessive downvoting?

<sub>I should note that I don't think downvoting is evil or anything. Downvoting is essential to the functioning of the site, and there are plenty of posts that deserve downvoting. I am complaining about overuse, not normal use of downvoting. And I also think a complaint about *underuse* of downvoting is just as valid.</sub>

Comment: My gut feeling is that 90% of bad questions are asked by people who could easily *realize* they're bad questions if they spent just enough to read over their question and check whether it makes sense to someone reading it without any extra context. For example, any question containing "I get error" without any description of what the error is - it really doesn't take a genius to realize that you need to explain what the error is. If you think about it that way, it's the OP who is being disrespectful by not caring about whether their question is answerable.

Comment: Bear in mind that before anyone asks a question, they already go through a page that explains how the site works, with explanations of what makes a good question and links to more details. If they've chosen to ignore that and ask a good question, don't you think that's disrespectful to the people who they're asking to give them time?

Comment: I disagree. I see plenty of terrible questions where nobody has bothered to vote.

Comment: No. People don't read things on the internet. They're not being disrespectful by not reading thru help, faq, and top meta posts, they're being practical. You can't just turn away new users just because they haven't put "enough time into understanding SE", these users are required for the site to function.

Comment: [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

Comment: Please expand "CV" to "Close vote". What's "LVQ"?

Comment: @Flexo Some bad questions aren't downvoted. So? This complains about overuse, underuse is not an argument against overuse.

Comment: @Cupcake Very Low Quality.

Comment: what do you call [overdownvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630713/is-it-true-that-in-python-you-can-import-specific-functions-from-a-module-unlike)? maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A-100--20) ?

Comment: @bjb568 anything you do to tweak the sensitivity of your detector at one end of the range will have an impact at the other end of it.

Comment: @mehow that first example user is suspended too, for good reason `:P` Deserves every downvote on that, and then some `:P`

Comment: @mehow No, I'm talking about drive-by downvoting, misuse of downvotes, and having too high of a quality mark. Bad stuff deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: "They're not being disrespectful by not reading thru help, faq, and top meta posts, they're being practical" They're asking people to spend time helping them, but they're not willing to spend any time making sure that they *can* be helped. That sounds disrespectful to me. If they're not willing to read anything that's written to make them write better questions, why should we believe they'll read comments and take action on them? Just how much effort do we have to put in before they put any in? Downvoting bad questions so that the site maintains good quality? *That* sounds practical.

Comment: @Flexo Minimally, if you do it right. Just general education about voting will make votes be used appropriately on both ends of the spectrum. I'm not advocating telling everyone to stop downvoting as much. Don't do more, do smart.

Comment: @bjb568 so, I used to be soft on users too, and I followed an algorithm much like yours. The problem is that it just doesn't scale. Giving tender love and care to every single question for every single user ***sucks up a lot of time and energy***. It's just easier to go straight to downvoting and move on. [main] gets [8000 questions per day](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday). Being soft just doesn't scale `:P`

Comment: @JonSkeet "I tried all these things, and it still doesn't work, maybe SO can help". They've put effort into it. They have created a good question that can benefit the community. Whether they word it correctly or explain their problem well is a different matter. Of course they can figure out the rules by researching for 3 hours… but seriously? They have *tried*. They want to do something, but they can't. So, obviously smack them with a shower of downvotes.

Comment: None of what you say is a misuse or abuse of voting. You might not like it, but that doesn't make it wrong. Users have a vote and are free to use it. They seem to regulate its use pretty well in general.

Comment: "They have created a good question that can benefit the community." If it's a *good* question, it won't be downvoted. Do you have examples of genuinely *good, helpful* questions which are being downvoted?

Comment: @Bart A downvote instead of bothering to edit it. Isn't that misuse?

Comment: @JonSkeet Almost all questions from low-rep users are downvoted - understandably. They don't format their code. They don't describe their problem. They don't have a clue what to do. If we help them, they won't come back the next time they have a question writing with the same problems.

Comment: @bjb568 I've been a member of [main] for [3 years and 7 months](http://stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake). In that time, [I've only asked 18 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake?tab=questions). I've spent plenty more time than 3 hours to read most (if not all) the rules on [main], plus blog posts by Stack Exchange and Jeff Atwood. Only after all that research, ***only then***, have I been posting more questions. If you post here, you better darn well make sure that you understand what's involved with it. If you don't, then you better ***learn fast.***

Comment: @Cupcake You're a great user. But not every user is born great. We have the tools to help them, but we aren't. If we had infinite time, we'd all be like you. And if anybody wasn't, they'd be educated. But people don't have infinite time. People need to educate users when they can. They need to understand that n00bs can't go reading every rule on SO before posting.

Comment: "They don't format their code. They don't describe their problem." Then they're not good questions which are helpful to the community then, are they? You need to decide: are you talking about good questions which are helpful to the community (they don't get downvoted) or bad questions (which aren't helpful, and would almost always be fixed if the OP had the courtesy to stop for 30 seconds and think what would *make* it a good question)?

Comment: @bjb568 "If we help them, they won't come back the next time they have a question writing with the same problems." This is already automated. Users who can't ask good questions [get question-banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/163250).

Comment: They have a good question in their mind. But they can't get it out to SO properly. They don't know how. Of course they're bad questions, but this is not reddit. Bad content shouldn't always be downvoted, if it can improve.

Comment: @bjb568 **Absolutely not**. Your posts being edited into shape is not a right you have. You are responsible for the content in your own posts. If it's not good and requires editing, a downvote is a possibility. That other users are so kind to go in and prevent that from happening is a gift from them to you. Not a right you as the OP have to prevent downvotes from happening.

Comment: @Cupcake That's real friendly… Well, I'll go create another account since this one is banned.

Comment: If you're banned, you've done something wrong for a significant amount of time. And you have not taken warnings into account. At that point I'm not sure if "friendly" is what matters any more. But hey, we're friendly enough to let you participate again if you put in the effort.

Comment: @Bart Of course. If you can't help, downvote. If it can't be saved, downvote. Downvoting is great, as long as you've exhausted other possibilities. Don't edit/comment on all bad posts. Edit/comment on posts that deserve it. "Give me teh codez" questions are obviously too bad to be saved.

Comment: @Bart If there *are* warnings…

Comment: Well then @bjb568, demonstrate to me that there is a big problem with posts that deserve to be on the site and are (besides a minor edit) clear enough to be answered, yet get downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: I don't mean a minor edit. I mean a major edit. Fundamentally changing OP's view of SO. We need to teach them that SO is not a help site *in a way that they can understand and improve easily*.

Comment: I agree here. It's not the job of "seniors" to brush up every question which may have an inkling of a real answerable problem at its core into a usable form. For one, there are too many question to do this consistently. You'd need a full time staff of people doing just that, and that simply won't happen. Secondly, we're not mind readers. If a user says "I get error" and nothing more, that question can only be salvaged by the user himself, not others. Downvotes just help to unclog the system for users who are conducting actual searches for their own problems.

Comment: @bjb568 "n00bs can't go reading every rule on SO before posting". Then they have no business posting anything to [main]. Users who can't be bothered to do any research and [Rubber Duck Solve Their Own Problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) have no business using the programming tool that is [main]. Also, don't underestimate the ability of mods to root out duplicate accounts trying to evade question bans `:P`

Comment: I totally agree that if you can't help (not enough time) or it can't be helped (i have err), you should downvote.

Comment: If there are warnings @bjb568? Aren't we talking downvotes here? Close votes? And with a ban that would have to happen several times .... if that is not a warning I don't know what is.

Comment: DV/CV/Ban: "You have done something wrong": "those annoying SO people don't like n00bs": "meanies"

Comment: If that is their first thought or indicative of their maturity level ... goodbye.

Comment: Obviously I'm exaggerating. But it discouraging especially if they aren't given a comment on how to improve. A simple comment takes no more than 15 seconds, yet it can benefit a noob so much.

Comment: And generally there are plenty. We're not exactly a shy or quiet community. And if you really don't get any or don't get it, come to Meta.

Comment: Yes. I know. Most questions are handled fine. I'm talking about the ones that aren't. Fine, you can call it too minor of a problem to think about, but I think it's a problem nonetheless.

Comment: @bjb568 regarding "simple comments", there is a reason why comments are optional. Never underestimate someone's willingness to be immature and petty. Besides, even "simple comments" take time and energy. Anything that requires turning thoughts into coherent writing takes time and energy. Again, it doesn't scale to many questions. This is why it takes so much effort to find the best questions on [main] when it's absolutely inundated with a flood of questions that most of the old-timers would rather not spend time and energy to read.

Comment: @bjb568: Oh *please*, **too high a quality standard**? The problem is that people have **quality standards that are too low**. Both when asking (not thinking about the quality of their question) and when voting (people are too timid still voting).

Comment: I also think @bjb568 should provide a few examples of abuse of downvoting... As it stands it's just an assumption and no real data highlighting this issue.

Comment: I didn't say "people have too high a quality standard". I said "sometimes experienced users have too high a quality standard". One implies millions of people, one implies hundreds.

Comment: @mehow This is a discussion, not a feature-request. I have no idea what I am doing and thus want to *discuss* it.

Comment: "They have a good question in their mind. But they can't get it out to SO properly. They don't know how." - Then they should read how *before* asking the question. As I said before, there are plenty of resources available... just 10 minutes of reading would be enough, but most people who ask bad question can't be bothered, apparently.

Comment: @bjb568 for what it's worth, I give up on downvoting questions. It's a big time suck, in terms of the confrontation that ends up coming out of it. It's just not worth it `:/`

Comment: @Cupcake y did u downvote me?! wut i does rong?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! so mean (\*proceeds to ask more questions of similar quality with "thanks in advance,\nmyname\n\n,no dwnvte pls, im just lernin"*)

Comment: @bjb568 `:P :P :P <3 <3 <3`

Comment: How can you go over the top on downvoting a question?  Surely, you can either downvote it, or not downvote it.  You can't partially downvote it, or extremely downvote it, or downvote it to the maximum.  It's like having an extremely large boolean.  Unless there's some privilege that I haven't earnt yet.

Comment: @DavidWallace I meant downvoting instead of making a simple edit to fix the problem. Anyway, why are you commenting on this old meta post, I've learned, all the opinions have been expressed.

Comment: @bjb568 Please consider voting to re-open the question here [ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272335/does-aggressive-down-voting-keep-away-novice-users-from-participating-actively-o ]

Comment: Man, this question has a lot of downvotes. How ironic. ;-)

Comment: @Aje It's a flawed question.

Comment: `GOTO 5` considered helpful.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yes I do have an example: [MSO: "Tags/terms used for data-science concepts: reshape/wide-form/long-form/tall-form/stacked data/unstacked/melt/cast"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338268/tags-terms-used-for-data-science-concepts-reshape-wide-form-long-form-tall-form). Your comment *"If it's a good question, it won't be downvoted. Do you have examples of genuinely good, helpful questions which are being downvoted?"* is nonsense.

Comment: @smci: That's on MSO, where downvotes have a different meaning. I was talking about the main site - as I believe most people have been.

Comment: While I agree that many questions deserve downvoting, I have been at the receiving end of spurious downvotes which resulted in a question having a negative score and therefore not read, not taken seriously, doesn't appear higher in searches etc.  One person raked me over the coals (I am assuming he downvoted too) and when I pointed out that he had obviously not read my question deleted his offending comment but continued to berate me in additional comments.  I do get upset at such outcomes - they are not useful to anybody and deny everyone an opportunity to learn.

Comment: I think this question is excellent example of the flow system. Question that has significant amount of views. Question that has affected enough people to do their effort to cast hundreds of votes. And yet the question is on the negative and the answer is like 100 more positive. I think this is ridicules.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Question downvotes indicate disagreement, which is valuable here. They're not to be taken personally.

Comment: @bjb568 dissagrement with what ? Dissagrement with the topic of the question , with the question itself ? A good question is a question that has a lot of views and that trigger a lot of good answers. How can a question with thousands of views get answers rated +tens and the same question get voting -tens. Sory I don't agree with this definition of up down voting.

Comment: @bjb568 I mean what is there inside a question that you can dissagree with. I understand to dissagree with a statement, but to dissagree with a question. Come on....

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The main problem I see here is that downvotes are taken so damn personal. A downvote does not mean *"you are a bad person and you should feel bad, go die in a corner"*. But that's how they're often understood. Try to see SE as a collaboratively edited knowledge base. New entries are created on an as-needed basis by actual users having actual problems, and they're collectively solved and answered and preserved for posterity. Upvotes and downvotes are used as an indicator for how useful overall a certain "article" is in the grand scheme of things in the context of a knowledge base.

See it from the perspective of a future visitor who has a specific problem and is using the search feature to look for articles that may help them (a feature which is sorely underused by "newbs" by the way). What that user wants is the most useful article which is both not too specific to somebody else's code but fits their problem perfectly. They do not want to sift through a ton of vague single-sentence questions with code walls to figure out whether that particular article fits their problem or not. But that's what most downvoted questions are: they're either too specific or too vague or too long to comprehend or have some other criterium which makes them unsuitable to be a highly visible knowledge base article.

*That's* what votes are for, to unclog the system from the regular stream of low-quality input that makes it less usable as a global reference. They are not there to insult anyone. If your question got downvoted, you should try to reevaluate it from the POV described above and improve it yourself. Don't expect others to jump in and do it for you, that's simply unrealistic and impractical.

The problem is that

1. new users who do not understand this perspective think SE is a "forum" for free speech
2. downvotes are taken much more personal than they ought to be and as a "veto" against their "right to free speech" or whatever other negative feelings they may invoke

That's why upvotes create "reputation" which builds "trust" in you by **the system**. Reputation first and foremost means that you know how the system is supposed to work. That means you understand what the purpose of the system is and act accordingly to keep it working that way. That is by design. Users with a low reputation simply aren't trusted to take good care of this *knowledge base*, users with a high reputation are. It doesn't say anything about you as a person.

Comment: I agree. Downvotes are great things. Maybe the problem is actually the reverse - maybe we need to educate new users on what downvotes are, instead of convincing old users to helping more.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think there is indeed a very ***primal, visceral, emotional*** reaction to being downvoted though. Being downvoted sucks. That's why I make sure that I cover my butt and make sure that I post ***really good*** questions.

Comment: @bjb568 all that is in help centre. do you expect a link to a help centre on each downvoted question? Whats the point? If someone does not do their research then a downvote reflects their laziness

Comment: @mehow I don't have a solution. I am just noticing a problem.

Comment: well I don't think it's a "problem". I think youre just being a bit too emotional about downvotes. In the election times this was discussed on meta and trust me the downvoters are moderating, keeping the quality of site good, saving it from the help vampires etc. It's not a problem, it's a good thing

Comment: @bjb568 sorry to have to repeat myself, but once again, there is a problem of scale. I suspect you are approaching this from the perspective of anecdote. How big is this "problem" that you notice? We have tools for you to investigate that and get actual stats and numbers if you want: [data.se] and [api.se].

Comment: @mehow **I** am? You can downvote everything I have. No, I'm talking about new users.

Comment: @Cupcake I don't know and I have no idea how to use those things.

Comment: @bjb568: To me, the problem is people who come to the site and can't be bothered to think for one minute "If I was reading this question, would it make sense?" Simply avoiding downvoting those questions doesn't solve the problem, does it?

Comment: it's like a dislike on facebook :)

Comment: @user That's the thing, **it's not**. It's *not* personal. It's *not* based on "like" or "dislike". It's more like an objective academic critique of a professional paper you wrote. As a peer-reviewed professional (or enthusiast) you need to be objectively open to objective critique of your work.

Comment: You can claim all you want that downvotes *should* be perceived a certain way but the fact is they aren't and no amount of FAQs or meta answers to meta questions is going to change that. You can't boil the ocean. Expecting users to follow these guidelines in the face off all evidence to the contrary is just ignoring reality. Design for reality not for some imaginary perfect user

Comment: @gman You're saying that we can't expect people to understand what a downvote they received really means? Or that downvotes should mean something else? Well, the entire system is based on the premise of voting based on perceived quality/usefulness. And so far that's worked pretty well, SO's success speaks for itself I'd say. Some users are misunderstanding and/or misappropriating votes for other meanings; which sometimes doesn't matter and sometimes is bad. Are we on the same page with this? What would you suggest to be done?

Comment: He's saying that, given the fact that people don't understand what a downvote really means, that yes, we can't expect people to understand what a downvote means. The system is working overall, but maybe if we found a way to clarify things, the system would work better. Maybe we wouldn't lose so many new people for instance.  The fact that WE understand it, doesn't meant the system is perfect and needs no improvements. As for suggestions... I have to think about it

Comment: @deceze, Actually the "critique" part only makes sense if there's a **comment** following the downvote. Downvoting without comment is like an academic critique that has only one sentence: *"the post is lousy"*. Such "critique" (if we could even call them so) has zero elaboration, zero justification, and zero clarification.

Comment: @Pacerier: the downvote button has a tooltip describing what it stands for. It most certainly does not say "This post sucks."

Comment: All well and good, but when your question gets downvoted, it would help people starting out if they had some accompanying reason why. Anonymous downvotes with no reason serve no purpose in shaping the community, other than unclogging the system as you say. But shouldn't the elites be trying to nurture and guide "noobs" so that they can someday grow into responsible users? Instead, newcomers are scared off because their questions get downvoted and nobody will bother to tell them why. The downvote feature needs a "reason" - even if it's just an anonymous selection.

Comment: @Typel That is a romantic idea which might work for communities of a few hundred users or so. But SO is way beyond the scale where everyone can be taken by the hand individually. Additionally there are tons of users who have zero interest in improving themselves and which only try to work around the system in whatever way they can. It would be an enormous waste of time trying to separate the wheat from the chaff. Also, often a downvote is accompanied by a close vote, which does carry a detailed reason.

Comment: @Typel Having said that, I do see your point about *honest* new users; but we’d need a bit more concrete suggestion how to care for those people. Mandatory reasons for downvotes has been proposed and shot down many times here already.

Comment: @deceze *"and which only try to work around the system in whatever way they can"* - indeed, like trying to smuggle in a request for tutoring under the guise of an open-ended question. It just won't work, but people keep trying.

Comment: Why is "forum" in quotation marks? The definition of a forum is: a meeting or medium where ideas and views on a particular issue can be exchanged. I've noticed a lot of people (often with a lot of internet points) try to feel special by calling it everything aside from what it is: A forum. What you wrote about the up- and downvote system is what it is in theory. In practice it's nothing but a ridiculous system which has gotten out of hand and in which people downvote for the slightest disagreements.

Comment: @Itry Because "forum" on the internet has a specific meaning, and SO *isn't that.* It's also not supposed to be a place to "exchange ideas", it's supposed to be a place for factual, correct solutions to specific problems. You'll need to have ideas to produce solutions to problems, but what we want to exchange here aren't the ideas, but the final solutions. You also need to have clearly posed problems so clear solutions can be proposed, and this is usually where the downvoting happens, because the posed problems aren't clear enough.

Answer (score 44):

> Only after considering commenting (so OP can learn)

No. Someone has spend a good amount of time to put a [help-centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) together. 99% of any Stack Overflow newbie (not newbie in programming) needs-to-know and guides are well described there. If question is downvoted all it takes its going into the help center and reading on downvotes -> once you there, you will probably see "how do I ask a good question" and "what topics are welcome here".

> Because downvotes discourage users. [...] It makes new users feel unwelcome, so they naturally (and partially correctly) assume that we want them to feel bad.

That is a completely wrong assumption.

Imagine you're British and going on a holiday to French Riviera for the first time. Say you're driving. As soon as you enter the French land you are expected to drive on the other side of the road. **You are the one who has to adjust**. It's not like everyone else will start driving on the left side of the road just because you're there. There are set of rules that you need to get familiar with before you actually place your foot in another country - even another community.

> Only after considering commenting (so OP can learn)

It's a bit similar here. You don't want to crash or get a ticket, create chaos on the road and cause harm and danger. You're welcome to come but you need to be respectful of the current rules and *laws*. If you don't you probably end up in jail - so a negative score on your question should **encourage** you to fix and adjust and not get pissed off and whine and complain.

Hope you see my point.

Comment: I'm not a terrible person (or maybe I am), but I didn't bother reading the FAQ until *long* after my bad n00b question days. I learned by example, but many others don't have time for that.

Comment: "You are the one who has to adjust." But there had better be a sign there saying something. No, by sign I don't mean chapter 37.a of the crap travel guide that nobody buys.

Comment: new users are taken through [the guide](http://stackoverflow.com/about) before asking. what else should we do? a YouTube tutorial on how to ask!? Come on this isn't kindergarten (*at least not yet*) so I am on the side who's voting against making this a [TALK TO ME](http://www.samaritans.org/how-we-can-help-you) lol

Comment: New users aren't taken thru the guide. They are pointed to it. By making it non-mandatory people skip it.

Comment: @bjb568 People who would skip it would skip it even if it was mandatory. :)

Comment: @deceze No, that's straw-man (like guns don't people, people do). Guns increase killing, making it mandatory would increase reading it. At least a little.

Comment: @bjb568 Meh, maybe I'm too jaded... ;) Is the tour really not mandatory anymore? I remember it used to be a while back.

Comment: I don't remember it being mandatory…

Comment: @bjb568 Even though, I think most users who produce questions which receive downvotes would not improve, no matter how many tours they're forced to sit through. Most of the time they can't even be bothered to read the duplicates which are offered while they type their post. :-/

Comment: @bjb568: You may have asked your first question before it was mandatory (although *something* has been mandatory for a long time). I believe it *is* mandatory now, and you have to check a box at the bottom to say you've read through it before you can ask a question, IIRC. Apparently, people are happy to check that box *without* reading it, which strikes me as disrespectful and lazy. How do you propose forcing someone to actually take in the guidelines that are already presented *very clearly* and often ignored?

Comment: Well, "most" doesn't include the 277686 users who obviously improved, as they have 100 rep.

Comment: where did those numbers come from now?

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh… I didn't know about that. Well, then ignore my entire argument. If they can't be bothered to read the thing in front of their face, they deserve downvotes.

Comment: @mehow Some data explorer query.

Comment: can you elaborate do you know 277686 users have improved? why does the 100 rep matter here? could be association bonus couldnt it?

Comment: @mehow God, it's an estimate! I assumed that if they got to 100 rep or association bonus, they learned from their noob mistakes.

Comment: can you share the query? I thought you've just said [you dont know how to use SEDE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253227/how-can-we-discourage-over-downvoting-on-questions/253230#comment12449_253230)?

Comment: I don't remember. I did a search for existing ones.

Comment: @mehow now now, no need to start getting accusatory `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake oh no pure curiosity

Comment: @bjb568 maybe you're right about the whole sign thing. I signed up for an account and asked my first question ***a long time ago,*** so I don't remember how any of that works or works now. Looking at the [about], you're right, it doesn't have enough warnings. How about suggesting that we add the [help/on-topic] rules to it? Along with the words "**Ignore at Your Own Peril**"? Something along those lines. I'm being serious too.

Comment: Yeah. I see a wall of text. Some tips. Etc. I need more "READ ME OR YOU WILL DIE!!!!!"s.

Comment: Good programmers read documentation. A good programmer will read SO's documentation, either before posting at all, or in the worst case when they post a bad question and start getting downvotes. They won't "die", because that single bad question will teach them the lesson they needed to learn. Bad programmers won't read the documentation without having it shoved in their face, sure, but we don't want them here anyway.

Comment: Well, you can't expect everyone joining to be "good programmer" - they're only here to learn.

Comment: This is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers. A person who doesn't read docs doesn't want to learn to be a good programmer, they just want someone to do their work for them.

Comment: Maybe when the OP visits a question with negative score, the site should add a banner with links to the guidelines and meta posts discussing how to improve bad questions?

Comment: A British friend of mine went to France and was driving on the wrong side of the road for about 15 minutes before he met a vehicle coming the other way and almost died. It was a road through the Alps with a sheer drop on one side of it.

Comment: the flaw of your 2nd and 3rd arguments is that in physical interactive actions we may not be able to avoid or fix the consequences w/o personal damages, while on the internet, we can edit and fix EVERYTHING, so why smash the brain and feelings of other ppl with a harshness hammer (causing them a personal damage!!!) if  that person could become an important contributor one day? just needs to help him/her adequate (not fix) their virtual behavior, as virtual interactions is all about that: self and everyone improvement.