# Why I get downvotes instead of answers when I ask a question maximum best I can?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I have a problem in expressing 100% clearly what I need to ask. Sometimes it is hard to type the exact question I have. Whe I try my best to put it clear and I really need an answer I get lot of downvotes. No single help to my question. Any competition over there? We are having problems and no answers from the pros here.

Comment: *Sometimes it is hard to type the exact question I have* - try harder. We have a quality standard here and we won't lower it.

Comment: I was going to ask for an example, but it looks like all your questions were deleted (if you did that, it's not a good idea, you should undelete them and improve them instead).

Comment: Well, I think the answer of your question is in your question :) You're asking "why are bad questions downvoted?" Why are bad homeworks graded bad? Why are bad exams graded bad?

Comment: purpose of this is to help people. downvoting will never help.

Comment: @user3580271: Of course downvotes help - they indicate you need to improve something.

Comment: @user3580271 Yes, but by people, we mean 100,000 Google Searchers. People as in plural, not only the OP himself and noone else. A difficult to understand question will be unlikely to be useful to googlers.

Comment: Okay, we are here to learn programming or to clear our problems. just we are not here in a english class to write things with grammer and not in this school to learn all their 1000 of rules before ask our simple question, sometimes come here to get an answer max within half and hour and leave with lot of disapontments. We don't come here if we have another person to ask them from.

Comment: @user3580271: *sometimes come here to get an answer max within half an hour* => if that's what you come to SO for, you come to the wrong place. When you come to my house you are obliged to follow my rules whether you like them or not. If you don't like the rules, don't come to my house. You can also talk to me about it (which is what you are doing here), but be aware that you are not entitled to demand anything. Same goes for SO.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. And guys overthere who has the same prob like me it is time we move to somewhere else than stacks. There will come better places to help people. when you restrict people.

Comment: I must agree with you, I already moved on for asking questions ^^

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL atleast one person understood me. I wish I can give you an upvote for that line :D

Comment: I would appreciate if people who downvote care to specify the reason. I know there is generic reason to downvote: "The question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Now, these are all relative terms used here. It would be helpful if downvoter also should specify reason specific to the question (For e.g. if they need clarification or more info about the question) Just downvoting would not help anyone. Further, downvoiting will demotivate other people from answering the question (As they might think its already downvoted question. Why to bother?)

Comment: @user3580271, correlation =/= causation. People are downvoting your questions, people aren't answering your questions. That doesn't mean that people aren't answering your questions because they are downvoted. One does not cause the other, the cause of both is a bad question.

Comment: I've removed a bunch of comments dangerously derailing towards name-calling. Please only use comments to discuss this question or use [chat] for more general discussion - in any case, keep it civil :-)

Comment: You "really need an answer" for "How much hack appropriate as a name for programming language"? Why is that urgent?

Comment: wonder I know you are not the person who gave that name later I thought I should ask the owner of hack language that question. :D

Comment: So I delete that q from SO. And they have replaced that useless question overhere now

Comment: Actually when I thought it was a bad question I deleted then they now think it really is a question by reposting it over here now. Now they must give an answer laugh-out-loud

Comment: @user3580271 Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/476

Comment: @deceze good answer

Comment: Am truly shocked you asked this in the right place.  I have hope for you.

Comment: @Andrew please see [Provide Optional Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814).

Comment: I realize I'm a bit late, but it looks to me like OP does not speak fluent English.  I know we want people to make an effort to articulate themselves clearly, but if somebody is truly "trying their best" (regardless of OP, in a hypothetical scenario) and just doesn't have a good command of the language, should they still be massively downvoted?  Or would it be better to suggest an edit?

Comment: @juergend Yes, "try harder" is great advice! No matter what people are doing, invariably just saying "try harder" always fixes all the problems: poor writers become great ones, poor programmers become great ones, and so on. I don't know why we even bother spending all that time training, e.g., airline pilots when we could just put them in an aircraft with a big "TRY HARDER" sign in front of them and eliminate aircraft crashes.

Answer (score 38):

The two questions you have asked are not very good questions for Stack Overflow.

> I went through reading about hack and I have a question!! How much hack appropriate as a name for programming language?

That doesn't make any sense - it is not answerable. Any answers would be completely subjective.

> Win 8.1 , 64 bit what is the android api level that I should select?. I have only api17 but emulator stucks in the middle

Not enough detail here. Nobody can answer it either.

---

In general, we expect people to **make an effort**. I suggest you hear our help center documentation on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - do read it, take notes and see if your next question follows those guidelines. Don't post it until it does.

The questions you have posted show no research, not effort and seem to expect an answer to materialize out of thin air (given that there is not enough information in either one to give any sort of answer).

Stack Overflow has quality requirements from questions - they need to be answerable, first and foremost. The ones you have posted so far fall short - this is why they have been downvoted and why no answers were given (who can answer something they both do not understand and that is not answerable?).

Comment: Additionally the second Q sounds like it is better off at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rockingskier - Not at all. An emulator would normally come into play when **developing** an app, not for casual android usage.

Comment: @user3580271 so how are we even supposed to edit them? I don't understand the first question, it just doesn't make any sense to me. And I can't read your mind to know what you wanted to ask so there's no way for me to edit it. For the second one, you didn't specify what you were trying to do when it got stuck, the code it got stuck on or any other relevant info. We can't see your computer, we can't see your code, so again how should we edit them? You need to make some minimum effort or we just can't do anything but downvote.

Comment: @user3580271 the problem here most definitely is not our lack of knowledge. Don't go down that avenue.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl "you didn't specify what you were trying to do when it got stuck" - Emulator stucks when you try to run the project. And it is my first project what more can I ask. At my very  first android lesson. I am not a pro like you are. If so why I question.

Comment: @user3580271 You are (wrongly) under the impression that this site exists to teach you programming. It does not. It is a Q+A site for high quality content _about_ programming and closely related subjects. If your goal and the goal of the site are inline when you ask a question, then great. If not, you need to do your basic learning elsewhere first, and then come to Stack Overflow when you understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes so do you think you are doing it perfect? Q+A? it is not. It is just. Q+downvotes and Pros+Answers(hiding knowledge)

Comment: @user3580271 the problem isn't that it's your first lesson and you don't know enough yet, everyone starts that way. The problem is that we can't help you if we don't have enough information. If we got the code we might see some problem that got the emulator stuck and that you didn't see or maybe something else. The more information we got the better we can answer. We have less trouble figuring out what the real problem is that you got and you get a better answer. A win win solution.

Comment: @user3580271 I don't think you really understand what the site is, or how it works. You've only been a member for 11 days, after all. Stick around for a bit and see how it works, then this will all make more sense to you.

Comment: @user3580271 just so I said something about downvotes too... they aren't meant in an aggressive way. They are **supposed** to be used to get questions/answers that are deemed to be most helpful to others to the top and to find easier. If your question gets downvoted that just means that the people that downvoted didn't see it as helpful to others, not that they don't like you. Sometimes people vote for other reasons than the supposed but that's not really significant in my expierience. Also usually people leave comments as to how you can improve your question or what information is missing.

Comment: @user3580271: Take a moment to see what's happening here: you are complaining about the treatment you get on SO; you put all the blame on the bad downvoters; and crucially, *you do not accept any responsibility for what's happening*. ("I am a newbie" doesn't count -- what counts is *visible effort to move beyond newbie level*). If that's the objective truth then you really should not come to SO because you can't change the bad downvoters and they will keep making you unhappy. What you *can* change is your own role, but it won't happen as long as it's someone else's fault.

Comment: I've removed a bunch of comments dangerously derailing towards name-calling. Please only use comments to discuss this answer or use [chat] for more general discussion - in any case, keep it civil :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz I appreciate your capability. And remove these too "People who downvote too many times than upvotes or give answers."

Comment: And remove "people who upvote like crazy to help each other". There are lot in SO like that. you do not notice them because of their ranks. I can just point out useless quetions with 1000 upvotes? where did they come from I wonder

Comment: There are already systems in place which detect and reverse inappropriate votes. Either up or down. Posts with many upvotes will have gathered those over a significant period of time or due to a very popular subject or great contribution. However, all this doesn't really have much to do with the topic of this post, does it? So let's keep it at this and keep focussed.

Comment: So should I open another question to ask? this two question? 1. Why SO people upvote for the interest for their friends . 2. Why simple questions get 1000 upvotes( I hope this connects with first q).

Comment: If you have two **different** questions, you should ask **two** separate questions. I do suggest, @user3580271 that you **search** the site for answers **before** you ask them. I will add that your question 1 reeks of assumption (how do you know this is happening?) - you will need to **prove** this is happening before you ask anything about it and provide your proof in your question. As for 2 - again, search before you ask. And perhaps link to your examples.

Comment: Arrogant as I am @user3580271, I think I have already given you the answers to your two questions in my comment. So perhaps there's no need to ask them any more. But if you do, do follow Oded's advice. Or just step away from the keyboard for a while. You seem somewhat upset, and that usually doesn't allow for great Meta contributions.

Comment: How do we make it more clear that **Stack Overflow does not exist to teach programming**? I mean really - does this need to be explicitly stated in the FAQ? On the top of every first-timer's "ask question" page?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart "Stack Overflow does not exist to teach programming?" I think that anyone who understands the philosophy of education would have a big argument about that. SO does not exist to do that, yet that is precisely what it does - because answering questions about programming cannot be detached from teaching in any meaningful way, without completely losing most common sense meaning that people associate with education. SO is a selective school - not all of students' questions will be answered. No shame in that, IMHO. That's what makes it good. Selectivity in this context is good.

Comment: @KubaOber Okay, then let me be more specific: *Stack Overflow is not a replacement for introductory-level programming classes or tutorials.*