# Where is my privacy?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, legal, creative-commons, privacy

I have deleted some questions which I asked and which got too many downvotes and I noticed they are irrelevant. So I removed them to make it clear but now I have asked a question which made people angry and all my deleted questions are visible.

When I delete a question SO shows me it is under deleted list but, It shows it the same way for everyone. What is the point of that delete? And it is like privacy is all out? what can SO suggest to protect users better than this?

Comment: Deleted questions are visible to users with 10K rep and greater, but not to *everyone*.

Comment: And why do they even want to see if I thought something is not relevent and deleted, It is my privacy to see it only by myself, and what they have to do with a deleted question, If i do not want it why they need?

Comment: Imagine stepping in front of a mid-sized auditorium every time you post something on SO. *Of course* there's no "privacy".

Comment: @user3580271: Note that even 10k users cannot easily *find* those questions, they are not listed in the usual places. A targeted Google search revealed just 1 deleted question, and only because it hasn't yet been cleared out of the Google search results (it will soon enough).

Comment: Why do you complain about no privacy if your user name is a system default and there are no personal details on your profile anyway? So a few thousand people can read your deleted posts. So What? They no nothing about you, so why do you even care?

Comment: Welcome to the internet? I mean you kind of have to expect things like this to happen. There is very little privacy on the internet.

Answer (score 22):

Once you post on Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange site) you are giving the site [the perpetual right to use that content](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

While you are welcome to delete your content there are some restrictions.

- You can delete any of your own unaccepted answers at any time.
- You can only delete a question if it has no answers or at most 1 answer (without a positive score).

However, if you try to deface your content or delete all of it, this will trigger automatic flags and people will notice. Their first reaction will be to restore the content.

If it's truly of no use to anyone you are OK in deleting it. However, if it is of use then don't expect to be able to delete it. You can ask for the content to be disassociated from your account, but that's not a right.

As to the specifics of your case. The post you have deleted are only easily visible to you and moderators/employees. Any user with more than 10K reputation can see your answers if they view the questions they are on. Any user with more than 10K reputation can only see your questions **if they have the url of that question**. These questions are effectively invisible.

Comment: I got it. And my questions were useless I know it and they knew it. I know how to delete but when I delete something some people can still see my deleted questions. You can't but some superusers can. and what is the point of deleteing them.

Comment: @user3580271: if you have the original URL of a question that's been deleted you should be able to see the question. If not, that's weird.

Comment: @user3580271 - people can only see deleted questions if they have the URL. People aren't likely to have kept the URL, so your questions are effectively invisible.

Comment: @user3580271: they are no longer listed in site searches. They are no longer listed on question pages. No one can vote on them, no one can answer them. Last but not least, if they were truly deleted, how could we ever recover accidental deletes?

Comment: @ChrisF Unless I'm very much mistaken, disassociating content absolutely **is** a right, as per the terms of the CC License in use, isn't it?

Comment: ya i know but i am saying some people just pasted my deleted questions saying they do not meet question standards. I deleted them because of that reason. And in my account I cant see them How did they paste them back for me.

Comment: @BillyMailman - yes it is a right, but there has to be a good reason for that request. Just because the question got a couple of down-votes is **not** a good reason.

Comment: @user3580271 where did they paste your deleted questions?

Comment: no need to talk about that I said what really happend. I delete becuase I do not want them to appear. Now it is back all over. putting it here is like opening again, isn't it?

Comment: @user3580271 - but unless I know where the content was posted I can't tell you how they might have got hold of it.

Comment: it doesn't really matter how now, what matters is however it happend. I will tell in private if you want than fooling myself posting it here.

Comment: @user3580271 once something is posted on the internet, regardless of where it is posted, you should no longer expect any privacy.  Sites like the [Internet Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/) and even Google cache data they come across and it can often be retrieved.  It isn't even something SO can control.

Comment: if that happened to you how you feel?

Comment: @ChrisF - I posted the content of the community deleted questions on my answer to the OPs question here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254000/why-i-get-downvotes-instead-of-answers-when-i-ask-a-question-maximum-best-i-can

Comment: @Oded - Ah. That makes sense.

Comment: @SList When someone comes to Meta asking why they got downvotes, or their question was closed, or they were banned, they should candidly provide the relevant evidence in their question, or be prepared for someone else to do it for them. Otherwise, the question cannot be answered with any specificity.

Comment: @SList: the user was asking why his questions were down voted, but if I recall correctly (his SO profile is now deleted) he had only two undeleted questions at the time, neither with down votes. Therefore, the only way to discuss why questions were downvoted was to show them.

Answer (score 14):

Your privacy is very real and protected by this family of sites. For example, the email you use to authenticate with is not displayed to other users. The site will not send you emails about recent questions that are similar to other questions you looked at, the way Amazon nags me about books I might like. You can read more in the site's [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) - there is a link to it at the bottom of every page.

Questions and answers that you post are not private. You give them to the site when you post them. (Details at [a 5-year old blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).) Other people may edit them, quote them, and read them whenever they want to. They are no longer yours to remove. (There are some exceptions for posts you decide to remove before anyone has interacted with them, but the general rule is that they stay.) As you've discovered, some cannot be deleted, and even those you can delete can still be seen by users with enough rep. This is by design.

If you think of your questions and answers as something private, do not post them in this public place. Also, if you delete downvoted posts, you may find yourself [blocked from posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) any more. Your best course of action with downvoted posts is to improve them - as you've seen removing them does not hide them, and can hurt your use of the site.

Answer (score -4):

Sir,
You read other people's questions without knowing who they are.

So you know they can do the same.

So you know what you post is not at all private, it's public.

So now you know that we aren't really talking about any private content here.

Ahh, may be we are talking about posting stupid questions.

So now your question really is why the stupid questions you posted earlier are visible to some of the users after deleting. I always put forward an intelligent thought/idea and get shattered when my friends laugh over it as they think it's stupid. So believe me, if you yourself are thinking your questions were stupid then everyone else is feeling the same. Please understand that SO has intelligent minds who have better things to do than reading stupid questions.

So, practically speaking, no one is reading what you posted and we have already proved mathematically(almost) that it's not private.

So, sir, again, what's your concern?