# Do you have to be good at programming to be allowed to ask at SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

For example, OP on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271176/my-is-connecting-with-an-if-statement/24271418 question asks a programming related question, with a clear problem in mind, every detail for the corresponding code provided and gets several down votes about (in my opinion) not having enough professional knowledge about programming and asking a questions that is for professionals obvious and easy to answer.

My question is what would be the correct reasoning: vote down because one does not know anything about programming yet and is asking a "silly" question of beginner, OR voting up or just answering by letting that anecdote of programming related issue to be of help to someone other as beginner as the first one?

Comment: Basic questions are fine, so long as they follow the guidelines. Everyone was a beginner once. The problem is that many of these questions have already been asked and have great answers - they are duplicates.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert at anything other than _using your own damn brain_. You have to have spent more time thinking about your problem, at an absolute minimum, than it took you to post the question. That is clearly not the case with the question you've linked.

Comment: "I want to do something impossible within the syntax of my chosen language" "I want to fly to mars on a unicorn that poops marzipan, but I'm not bothering you with my nonsense, am I?"

Comment: I would downvote that question without hesitation.  It shows a complete lack of understanding of the chosen programming language, indeed, of *any* programming language.  Any amount of research will show you that what is being attempted is incredibly bad design.  The answer isn't to help him work around it, but show him how to design it *properly*.

Comment: Well, you all had it right, the OP posted an update to question with the rest of the code and after that I removed my up vote when the situation was revealed at full detail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your confusion seems to be why a question gets downvoted, even though it appears to be useful to you as a beginner. For this I'll quote myself:

> A downvote does not mean *"you are a bad person and you should feel bad, go die in a corner"*. But that's how they're often understood. Try to see SE as a collaboratively edited knowledge base. New entires are created on an as-needed basis by actual users having actual problems, and they're collectively solved and answered and preserved for posterity. Upvotes and downvotes are used as an indicator for how useful overall a certain "article" is in the grand scheme of things in the context of a knowledge base.
>
> See it from the perspective of a future visitor who has a specific problem and is using the search feature to look for articles that may help him (a feature which is sorely underused by "newbs" by the way). What that user wants is the most useful article which is both not too specific to somebody else's code but fits his problem perfectly. He does not want to sift through a ton of vague single-sentence questions with code walls to figure out whether that particular article fits his problem or not. But that's what most downvoted questions are: they're either too specific or too vague or too long to comprehend or have some other criterium which makes them unsuitable to be a highly visible knowledge base article.
>
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/476

You can create questions at any skill level, but we expect that question to be **generally useful to anybody, including future visitors**. If the question got downvoted it's probably not useful to anyone except the OP right here right now or is otherwise misleading or does not add any generally useful knowledge to the pool, and we're trying to unclog the system from questions which are unlikely to provide any help in the future.

To be bluntly honest: we do not want super basic questions which can and should be answered by a tutorial, manual or programming introduction course, if at all avoidable. SO is the resource you go to when the manual and all of Google has failed you; we do not want to clog up the system with a copy of every manual for every programming language in existence in triple copy. *If* such a question makes it into the system, it should at least be of such high quality that it can stand the test of time and be helpful for thousands of future newbies.

In this particular case the question may be somewhat salvageable by rephrasing it and making it clearer what the OP wants to know right from the title on (which can admittedly be hard for a newbie who doesn't have the right lingo), but the question is about such a basic misconception that I'm not sure anyone in the future will encounter the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. "when the manual and all of Google has failed you" has the essentials what I was searching for.

Comment: "All of Google" is a bit of hyperbole, but a significant slice is certainly right.

Comment: Considering some of the older, very popular questions on this site, it may be more accurate to say "To be bluntly honest: we no longer want ..." instead.