# Should one advise on off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, scope

This may be one of the most common quandaries I have when looking through Stack Overflow questions, when the author has written an obviously off-topic but genuine question such as

> ### Windows Forms Application Classic Interface c#
>
> I want c# windows form applications but i don't want use classic
> butons, classic forms element etc. I want use more efficiently, more
> simple more elegant more impressive interface elements. Do you know
> any free library in this subject? Thanks a lot...

I often leave a comment on the question advising that Stack Overflow is not for opinions/advice...

Is it appropriate to try and help them out and advise them to ask in the chat rooms, or if you go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) you will find information, or should you simply not engage in helping, as that is potentially teaching the author that "yes I may be down-voted, but at least I will get my answer in some way".

Comment: I believe this is the controlling position from Meta Stack Exchange: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: Related (but not a dupe): [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)

Comment: @jww I should hope not. The attitude in that post is everything that's wrong with SO IMO. Too many holier-than-thou folks looking for ways to "ding 'em" and "cackle a little while they do it." That said, if you're just talking about what to do with off-topic questions, I agree. But "controlling position" implies agreement with the implied culture statement in the post, too.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

What you should do:

- cast a down vote
- vote to close (flag to close if you're under 3K rep)
- comment and explain why their question is bad and how to fix it, use the tour, the help, maybe even a chat session

Don't ever answer an off-topic question, not via chat, comments, or any other way. It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same and eventually get what they want.

Comment: @vba4all to me, summer of love wasn't an obstacle in doing as explained here; I _politely_ voted down, close and wrote comments explaining what's wrong with the question

Comment: @gnat: That is the point indeed. Downvoting isn't rude, but is often interpreted as such.

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601) :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for the answer, It does look from the votes that people are a bit on the fence on this but I will endeavour to vote/close/comment only in the future.

Comment: I do all that but still occasionally I give a hint how to solve the problem (not a full blown answer of course) because I see a spark of light somewhere in the rubbish which other SO users tend not to see or because I'm just a good man. And I'm immensely proud about it. Call it pity or whatever. Does this good or bad to SO? I don't know. Sometimes people improve and the second question is already better than the first one and a nice treatment might be good for something. It's not so clear as many people believe it is.

Comment: @Trilarion: I agree with you. But trowing a hint isn't an answer. If you comment 'Read up on feature X of Y', then you encourage OP to do his own work before coming here.

Comment: I feel like there are those who live their entire lives by finding others to answer questions for them.  Refusing to enable them to use this site might have noble intentions but it isn't going to stop them from going on that way.  In fact, they will in many cases simply be to ignorant to "properly" ask, and never find out.  I suppose competitiveness can be a good thing if it encourages people to go beyond the call of duty in making great answers, but it seems terrible if it perpetuates mass stupidity (even among those you deem as 'vampires' because they lack your problem-solving skills).

Comment: The interpretation of off topic is problematic because if someone makes an incorrect statement and you answer correcting their understanding, you are not making a recommendation, you are correcting their interpretation.

Comment: As long as it helps the question, no problem. If it is to get someone an answer who posted when knowing it is off-topic, not okay. @Jason

Comment: I would argue that the off topic police are too quick to shutdown the questions in many cases when valid technical assistance can be offered. It would be far better to come up with a clear description on how to compose questions the right way and have an automatic way to point people to this information when their question is asked in a way that promotes unhealthy debate.

Comment: @Jason agree with your last part, but what more can we do? People don't read the help, don't follow the tour, don't want to read proposed duplicates. This has come up many times on Meta and no one seems to have found the solution.

Comment: That is where I talk about an automatic way to point people to it. So instead of having a slew of downvoted questions on hold which have a minus one, two, three etc, look offensive to a new user and clutter the question list, the question shows up as being in a penalty box only viewable by the person asking the question until they rephrase the question if possible or withdraw it. If they never fix it, it eventually dies. If they do fix it, it goes live and can be answered. This also prevents the people who are trying to help from being dinged.

Comment: @Jason feel free to work it out in a proposal here on Meta. Don't forget to point me to it, would love to read it.

Comment: I would recommend against referring people to Meta for proposals as the social community here seems broken. I got many down votes long before getting any constructive feedback and was told how I simply did not understand. I was also called an idiot by a significant contributor in my attempts to outline the proposal. That is not somewhere you want to send people if you want their input.

Comment: @Jason: If you just cry "We should make things better", people on meta will say "sure, propose something", and that's to be expected because we know nothing is perfect. If you start an open question asking for proposals to make things better, that's obviously useless: Post a FR like anyone else who has a bright idea, we don't need a question for collecting all of them. Your [last / only visible post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304260) was justly shot down for a simple reason: You proposed implementing a system which exists, and had nothing new to offer nor would deign to acknowlege that.

Comment: @Deduplicator, it is actually comments like "nothing new to offer nor would deign to acknowlege that" that point out how unreceptive and condescending many in the audience are. I proposed something and the vast majority simply pointed to a one line comment as their justification for not liking it. That is hardly an environment where people will want to make suggestions.

Comment: Odd-ball question, what about **self-answers**?  I asked an off-topic question, to which I found and added the answer a month later.  Which is preferred, to leave the question in closed state or to delete it?

Comment: @user1361991: If it's off-topic, it's off-topic. It doesn't matter who posted it.

Comment: You should absolutely not cast down-votes on off-topic questions. Now I see part of the reason for this terrible (IMO) behavior.

Comment: Why not? It is one of the official downvote reasons.

Comment: @user1361991 - Flag the question for migration to an appropriate site in the Stack Exchange network. Then, answer the question at its new home. The strategy avoids off-topic questions on Stack Overflow, and provides the answer for future visitors on an appropriate site.

Comment: This answer is arguably in conflict with [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions). That one says to upvote good answers to bad questions. This one says never answer an off topic question which is one form of bad question. If you're never supposed to answer a bad question then those answers should arguably be downvoted since it's bad behavior according to this upvoted answer.

Comment: I didn't say to downvote the answer. I said to downvote the question. Not answering is something different that downvoting the answer. @gman

Comment: "It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same and eventually get what they want." Why is helping people resolve their problems considered dangerous? Does their device explode and cause serious injuries when you do that?

Comment: They hurt the community, since they will keep up this act to get their answer.

Comment: The conflict is in this answer saying "never answer an off topic question" and the other answer saying "upvote good answers to bad questions". "Upvoting a good answer to an off topic question encourages answering off topic questions which this answer says to not do"

Comment: @gman Such questions should not be placed. If done, vote on its quality. Usually they are low-quality too.

Comment: @gman the general rules at play here are 'don't answer off-topic questions', and also 'downvote wrong/unuseful answers' regardless of whether the question is off-topic or on-topic (likewise also regardless of whether the question is high quality or low quality). If a high quality, correct, or otherwise useful answer is posted to a bad question, it should be upvoted, because good answers can save bad (on-topic) questions. If such an answer is provided for an *off-topic* question, then it shouldn't be upvoted. The specific aspect of 'off-topic' overrules the general rule of 'bad' (like in D&D).

Comment: If only this was followed...

Comment: "It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same" needs evidence. I am sure you speak from your own experience with a large number of cases, but how would you know what people will always do ever after and that they will never change or improve? How is it "dangerous" to point them to Google? Dangerous for the users? Dangerous because any help might attract more low quality questions by similar people? You seem to have a point, but at least that aspect sounds more like a prejudice unless the point is made clear.

Comment: This is complete trash.