# My question was answered by someone, but I can't comment/thank/checkmark it?

Tags: discussion, support

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985930/50-000-rows-created-when-querying-small-table-in-google-sheets-working-as-desig) was just answered by [AdamL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373663/adaml), but I can't comment because I literally created my account yesterday and do not have 50 points yet.

I would like to thank/+ him, confirm that this answers my question, and ask if he knows of a documentation reference on Google Developer forum/anywhere else that confirms/describes this behaviour.

But as it stands I can do exactly nothing, which seems impolite to the person who took the time to answer my question. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts

Comment: It was answered in the comments, after closing ...

Comment: I checked your question to see if it was appropriate to be re-open it, so an answer could be submitted, but it really does seem off-topic. See also [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) -- that is, while your question *was* answered, it's still OT for SO.

Comment: By the way, commenting just to write +1 or "Thanks!" is not recommended ! Of course, it's pleasant to get thanks from OP (and polite) but it's against SE policy. => Just assume OP is polite enough to **upvote** and **accept the answer** in place of a "thanking" comment.

Comment: I understand that. However, because the question was put on hold as off-topic, I was unable to accept an answer bc the user who answered can only comment on, not answer the question. And I can't upvote a comment (is that correct?). And I feel it would be rude to no thank him. So catch-22. What does one do in these situations? In the end I commented on his answer in the comments with this (see next comment)...

Comment: ...which does start with a thanks, but which imo is more substantive than just a +1 or just a Thanks. Is the following still against policy?  "Thanks @AdamL! Do you know of an online reference to this behaviour in the documentation or some other "official" source? Just for completeness. Still seems strange this effect is not prevented, with a clear/unique error message. Is it possible for this question to be taken "off hold", so you can your comments as an answer, so it can be accepted and the question can be marked as resolved?

Comment: BTW my main concern is that is doesn't just get closed because I didn't post it on the correct site. On advice of another user on Meta-SO I flagged the question to moderator with request to re-classify it to SU as users seem to feel it belongs there. I still feel the question and answer in comments add value, and does not have a duplicate (that I have been able to find).

Comment: Update: the question was migrated to SO! See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/842208/50-000-rows-created-when-querying-small-table-in-google-sheets-working-as-desig). I quoted the comments from @AdamL (and attributed them to him of course), as comments do not seem to be migrated with a question.

Comment: So I wonder: if I would have put the question on SO in the form of; "I have this app script here (some apps script), that sets value ("(sql statement in original question)") in a cell, and then 50.000 rows are created, is this a bug in apps script?", would it then still have been considered OT for SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't accept because the user posted comments - not an answer. And since your question is on hold, they won't be able to post the information as an answer unless the question gets reopened.

Comment: He can still respond to the comment and notify with the @Name system

Comment: Update: just hit "Add Comment" button and was able to comment. Before I got a message to the effect off "You can't comment bc you need 50 points". Maybe I hit another option that first time? Is there anything I can do to have the question taken "off hold" so @AdamL can re-post his comments as an answer, which can then be accepted?