# Why is this answer deleted?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers, link-only-answers

In this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179352/library-implementation-of-a-map-backed-by-an-array

the user asks `"for a library implementation"` that meets some specific requirements.

I have an implementation that I published on github, so I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179352/library-implementation-of-a-map-backed-by-an-array/30179857#30179857) the question with a link to the implementation

> I'll just put my impl here in case someone finds it useful
>
> https://gist.github.com/zhong-j-yu/1580c495c6504375a7a5

The answer got deleted, probably because it contains only a link. However, for this specific question, the answer seems to be perfectly acceptable; there is really not much to say but to link to the implementation that the user asks. What more could I add to the answer?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731

Comment: @gnat that is really not fair in this particular case. it is a perfectly legitimate, complete, informational answer to the question. maybe the question should be flagged as "it is not a question as far as stackoverflow is concerned" :)

Comment: maybe. See [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: Don't worry, we're working on deleting everything else in that question.

Answer (score 17):

It is a link only answer. Remove your link. The answer becomes:

> I'll just put my impl here in case someone finds it useful

That is not helpful to future visitors.

---

> What more could I add to the answer?

It looks like someone tried to do that. They edited in the code. You informed that was inappropriate and mentioned that you published the code on Github, not Stack Overflow. Fair enough. At this point, it's still link only then. You even mentioned in the comments that "you can delete this post if you want, I'm ok with that."

I see no reason it shouldn't have been deleted. It's

- Only a link
- who's contents you don't wanted copied to Stack Overflow
- and you said it should be deleted

Comment: well I didn't say it *should* be deleted. I'm ok with deletion, but I'm curious why.

Comment: Because it's only a link.

Comment: the user did not ask for how to implement it; he/she just wants to be pointed to an existing implementation. I still have no idea of how to answer that, other than providing a link.

Comment: Close it. They are asking for a library/tutorial/recommendation. You don't answer those types of questions.

Comment: closing it would be a loss to stackoverflow. people would google the same question, but they won't find stackflow links.

Comment: @bayou.io Add context to links. (Re)Publish an excerpt or description about the link or how it solves the problem. Then it becomes a valid answer - although in this case the question is still asking for recommendations.

Comment: @bayou.io, It is off topic. There is a default [close reason](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AE2sa.png) for recommendation type questions.

Comment: @slugster thanks. but the question is very well defined, requiring very little context. also, this kind of questions seems to be perfectly legitimate *programming question*, it's in no danger of a flaming war like *which is better, C# or Java*. it would be a shame that we cannot ask this kind of question on stackoverflow

Comment: @bayou.io Unfortunately it doesn't matter how well the question is asked, it is still asking for recommendations or help to find an external resource - and these are considered off topic on SO because they become stale, they're not a good long term resource, and they're prone to subjective answers.

Comment: @slugster I don't think it's very different from *which C function I can use to convert string to date?*.

Comment: @bayou.io Do you see much spam on SO?  No?  Ever wonder why a gigantic website with as much traffic as it has isn't inundated with spammers dropping links all over the place for their crap products?  This is why.

Comment: @Will Well, it's one of the many reasons why.  There are a lot of other anti-spam mechanisms too.

Answer (score -7):

It was inappropriate for someone to delete that, but what you can do if you don't want to put all the code in, is to **put in an in-depth explanation of what that code is doing**. Some people don't like link-only answers, so it's important to bulk things up.