# Two NAA Flags Declined about Video Libraries/Tools

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags

I recently found two library/link only answer that I thought were low quality and did not answer their respective questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316524/read-dvd-metadata-e-g-chapters-duration-and-titles-using-c-sharp-or-other-langua/19325231#19325231

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169369/joining-h264-mp4-with-ffmpeg-concat-without-re-encoding/19171410#19171410

The first one recommends libdvdread with no additional information on how to use the library, and only provides a link to the project.

The second one suggests the asker to use a different piece of software.

Both are recommendations and neither really answer the question in my option.  While I agree that [poor questions should not be answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions), I am wondering why my flags were declined, and if I was wrong to flag these answers.

Comment: "very low quality" is not "Not an answer"

Comment: @Andy So what should be done?  Ignore?  Downvote and move on?  One could argue that the second answer is "not an answer."

Comment: @Andy That said, both flags do exactly the same thing and are almost indistinguishable to those handling them.

Comment: In the first place just nuke the whole question, rather than bothering with the answers.

Comment: @Servy I had originally flagged the first question as off-topic, and the flag was marked as helpful.

Comment: @JAL Well there you go.  If the question gets dealt with, it'll take the answers along with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While short, both of those answers did actually attempt to answer the question asked. Both of them would still be viable if you removed the links from them.

In the first case, the question was "Is there any simple way to analyze the IFO file within the DVD using C# or something like that?" to which an answer (without the link) of "libdvdread seems to be the most common library for this" could work. Is it a great answer? No, but it does address the question asked. I saw no reason to immediately delete that, so I declined the flag.

In the second, the question is an (off topic) one about how to stitch MP4 video files using FFmpeg. The answer suggests using mp4box instead to concatenate MP4s. That seems to address the question asked. Again, it's not a great answer, but I see no reason for it to be unilaterally deleted by a moderator. I didn't decline that flag, but I can see why it was.

For answers like these, I can see leaving comments asking for them to be expanded upon with examples (and maybe closing the second question as being off topic) and downvoting, but I don't think a flag requesting immediate deletion of these answers is warranted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Why would we want to leave these posts to encourage the original answerer (or other posters) that these kinds of answers are acceptable if they are not good answers?

Comment: @JAL - the comments and - most importantly - down-votes would show future visitors that these aren't good answers.

Comment: Fair point, thanks Brad and Chris.