# Is it OK to downvote answers given for off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555671/learn-efficient-basic-3d-simulations-to-advanced-ones) today, and marked it as off-topic as

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

The question clearly asked about such resources, and the close vote is appropriate.

Then [a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30555929/1413395) was given and I mentioned to their OP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555671/learn-efficient-basic-3d-simulations-to-advanced-ones/30555929?noredirect=1#comment49183641_30555929)

> Do not answer off-topic questions knowing so. Also what if your links decay? Would this answer still be useful for any future reader?

and downvoted for this reason.

That answer was actually accepted, and I receive claims now, that downvoting the answer was unjustified.

**What do you think? Is such an answer useful, especially as it only contains links to 3rd party resources primarily?**

Does such answer give **durable merit** for research on the question?

---

OK, I see that possible duplicate [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions), but I seriously decline this answer contains any ***durable merits***, because of it's mostly link only nature, which is naturally to expect for such kind of question.

---

I won't bother my question here will be closed as a duplicate, but if so with a **correct one** please, that reliefs the commenter's doubts if my down and close vote were valid or not (I'm pretty sure they were).

If you insist with the duplicate I'd rather refer to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255462/1413395) instead of the accepted one.

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to meta effect, it seems that this thread was deleted at all now. I'll take screen shots for users below 10k if requested.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå The duplicate actually doesn't hit my point, there wasn't any _merit_ with that answer.

Comment: Why does the question's quality matter if you think the answer itself was bad?

Comment: @apaul34208 The matter is about the answers quality, that seems to be inherently bad in turn of the OT close reason given for the question.

Comment: Not saying that I never downvote answers to blatantly off-topic questions, but there's two issues at play here and both are pretty heavily covered here and on Meta SE. You downvoted a bad answer, you downvoted an answer to a bad question, and/or both.

Comment: "and downvoted for this reason." does  "this reason" refer to you making a comment? Or for the content of the comment: "Do not answer off-topic questions knowing so....", because the answer was on a question that should be closed? Or is the reason that you have to ask what happens when the links decay? It is  unclear that you downvoted because you thought the answer was bad, at least from what you write here (except from the comment on Adnrew answer)

Comment: @user40524 You're completely mislead about my reasoning. I'm not downvoting the answer, simply because the question is off-topic. The answer just refers to links. Links may decay, the answer becomes useless. But asking for links makes this inherent, doesn't it?

Comment: see also: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: Your question and your comments do not seem to fit.  Your question talks about downvoting answers to "off-topic" questions.  But your comments seem to suggest you are only talking about downvoting bad answers to off-topic question.  Please clarify.  Otherwise your question is a duplicate despite the fact that you don't like the answers.

Comment: clearly, bad questions are different from off topic questions, and this question is asking about off topic question, why would it be a duplicate?

Comment: I believe this is the controlling position from Meta Stack Exchange: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: Hey, can we not mark a question as a duplicate of a question closed as a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate, but rather close it as a duplicate of the original?

Answer (score 9):

Votes are yours to use as you please (as long as you don't target a particular user). If you think answers to off-topic questions aren't productive (e.g. because they encourage off-topic questions), then down-voting is fine.

Comment: Thanks for backing up. I don't see any merit in the answer, and I'm just afraid it will attract such like questions being asked in future. That's why I downvoted the answer, and why I think this is justified.