# Asking question in multiple tags but only one MCVE

Tags: discussion

Earlier today, I answered this question:

- [Find last date of year in stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772102/find-last-date-of-year-in-stata)

The (new) user provided a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example in Stata's programming language, while asking a *clear* and very *specific* question.

Despite the fact that I provided an *exact* solution to the problem, some people voted to close the question as too broad and my answer was heavily downvoted.

The asker apparently also wanted to learn how to create a plugin to use other programming languages with Stata. As such, he asked if anyone could also provide a solution to his problem in four other languages.

My questions:

1. Is it really such a great sin for someone to ask if people are willing to help by providing solutions in other programming languages without a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example for *each* language?
2. Is it really valid for some people to down vote a legit and helpful answer because they obviously deem the question as too broad?

Comment: The problem is not a missing MVCE. The question asks multiple questions at once (aka requesting solutions in multiple languages) which makes it too broad. Also, +1/-2 is not heavy downvoting.

Comment: @BLD The question explicitly asks only one question. The rest is not mandatory, the OP does not _request_ any other solutions.

Comment: There is no optional part in SO questions. Either it asks for solutions in 5 languages or it doesn't. If this is just optional, then op should remove the sentence, then the question looks fine.

Comment: @BLD Even if we assume that what you are saying is correct, what is the solution? Ask five different questions? Provide five different MCVEs for the same question?

Comment: Basically, yes. Note, that there might already exist a duplicate for most languages.

Answer (score 11):

The OP stated in their question (emphasis mine)

> It would also be great if anyone could show me how to do this in **C, C++ C#, or Java** as I would like to try to create a plugin and interface this with Stata.

and also tagged the question with all these language tags when posting their question.

If that's not *too broad*, I don't know why we have that close reason at all.

Comment: So if the OP asked the same question five times in five different tags would be okay?

Comment: @PearlySpencer Most probably not without showing any efforts what they've been trying to do for any of these specific languages.

Comment: So both approaches are no good? Then why should someone bother coming to SO to ask a question at all? I would love to hear your views on my second question as well.

Comment: @PearlySpencer See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295689/is-it-ok-to-downvote-answers-given-for-off-topic-questions and dupes.

Comment: Let's edit out the to broad part then, the tags have already been removed

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This link  is not relevant here. The question is not off-topic and not a duplicate.

Comment: @PearlySpencer The question got put on hold. So clearly some people think it is off-topic.

Comment: @AndréKool I do not see anywhere saying off-topic as the reason.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: The distinction between "off-topic" and "too broad" with regard to downvoting answers is irrelevant. The reason for the downvote is the same: to discourage people from answering inappropriate questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Discouraging people to answer (less than stellar) questions is not a legit reason to down-vote answers, particularly when these are _not_ low quality and provide exact solutions. One  should vote on the content of the answer not the quality of the question.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: "*Discouraging people to answer (less than stellar) questions is not a legit reason to down-vote answers*" I agree. But if you want to know why they downvoted your answer, that's why. Whether it should be done or not, it *is being done* and it is being done *for that reason*. "*particularly when these are not low quality*" That is a matter of some debate for this specific case.

Comment: _That is a matter of some debate for this specific case._ The answer is spot on and not a matter of debate. What is subject to debate is the behaviour of certain users who choose to abuse their votes.

Comment: @PearlySpencer It's generally not a good idea to assume bad faith on the part of other people; you disagree with their actions, but that doesn't make it an abuse.  Bad questions that people think are close-worthy are going to attract downvotes on the answers; you can argue about how you think that's wrong all you like, but *none* of it means it's an abuse.  It's like saying your upvote on a crappy question that should be closed and deleted is an abuse.

Comment: @fbueckert It is not about what I think. Down-voting an answer which clearly produces the desired result and has been accepted by the OP because the perceived quality of the question is poor is a form of abuse. SO policy is to vote based on content quality. Disappointing I have to point this out all the time.

Comment: @PearlySpencer *You* think it is an abuse.  Those downvoting believe that *answering* or upvoting such a question is an abuse.  There are other perspectives beyond your own.  If you insist on downvotes on answers for poor questions is an abuse, you're only opening yourself up to others insisting you *answering* those same questions is also one.

Comment: @fbueckert _Those downvoting believe that answering or upvoting such a question is an abuse._ Not according to Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Can you provide us with a link to such policy you suspect? This ongoing discussion here starts to annoy me a lot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you are annoyed then do not participate in the discussion. As for the link, I think it is time for you to get another look [at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down): _... Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect..._

Answer (score 8):

> Is it really such a great sin for someone to ask if people are willing to help by providing solutions in other programming languages without a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example for each language?

Yes, it is. However, I want to talk about the hyperbole with regard to "such a great sin".

Closing a question is not a moral issue. It's a simple, practical one: does it fit the criteria for being on this site. Note that the criteria is *not* "can I answer it". We have set standards for what is allowed on this site, and questions which are outside of those standards should be closed.

Remember what the purpose of Stack Overflow is: to build and maintain a searchable database of problems and their solutions.

Let's say that you are a C++ programmer and you want have the same problem as the OP in this example. So you do a Google search for "C++ find last date of year". If you see a link to "Find last date of year in stata", are you going to click on it?

*No*. Because that question is about *Stata*, not C++. There is no reason to expect that link to contain an answer in C++, since that is not what the title says. So a C++ programmer will miss information that could have been useful to them because it was mis-categorized.

This is (part of) why Too Broad questions are not allowed. A broad question is so far removed from a specific problem that Google or other search engines are highly unlikely to ever find it if someone has a problem that would be solved by it. So any answers may help the OP, but are unlikely to help anybody else. Questions like these don't help build a searchable database of problems and solutions; they only help the OP.

We only want questions on this site that help us build a searchable database of problems and solutions.

> Is it really valid for some people to down vote a legit and helpful answer because they obviously deem the question as too broad?

"Valid"? Not really. I mean, some people will stretch the meaning of "not useful" to include "the placement of this answer on a poor question means that it will never be seen by people who need the answer and thus is a priori 'not useful' " or somesuch, but I've never found such arguments convincing.

*That being said*, such people still exist. They find the counter-arguments to their perspective as unconvincing as I find their arguments. And thus, they will still downvote such answers. And there's nothing you can do to stop them.

Ultimately, voting expresses an opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, the difference here is that the main question was not inappropriate. It was clear, specific and answerable. The users who so eagerly down-voted both the question and answer could had simply edited out the offending part and point out to the new user that additional questions should not be asked.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: What is your definition of "specific" that includes "provide an answer in *five separate programming languages*"? That's the *opposite* of "specific".

Comment: @PearlySpencer: Users are not required to edit content to make it appropriate for the site. They may do so if they wish, but they're not required to do so. The OP is the one who should make sure their content is appropriate.

Comment: The Stata question is specific and the user did not explicitly request answers to all the other four.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: "The question" does not get to stop where you arbitrarily decide it does. The OP does in fact request answers in multiple, disparate languages. As initially posted, it was Too Broad. Period.

Comment: The difference of Stack Overflow with other sites is that the content is curated. I think people here can easily over-react. Why bury an otherwise good question and a helpful answer if with a simple edit this can be preserved and improved? New users rarely edit their questions even after being told to do so.

Comment: Also, it is Stata and not Strata. And Stata was not originally in the question's title.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Gotta ask; why didn't *you* edit the question, since you're obviously at least interested enough in it to answer it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Because I did not deemed it to be too broad. And I still do not.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing would be if the OP tried implementing in those languages one by one and asked specific questions. Notice that a full answer for the question would contain an implementation in all the languages OP asked for, which is a bit of an overkill, hence the question was flagged as too broad (the OP didn't provide any implementation in any of these languages).