# This question should be undeleted

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330306/java-program-for-count-lines-of-code-of-a-c-source-file

Despite the VLQ 'gimme teh codez' nature of the question,  Hovercraft Full Of Eels and I both offered useful advice anyway.  I've had a lot of vodka, HFOE has his/her own motivation.

Maybe we were somehow swayed by the number of 'nazi moderators unkind to new users' posts, I'm not sure.

Naturally, on SO, no good deed goes unpunished, and the OP promptly deleted the question when it realized that its entire code was not going to get written, tested and debugged for it.  Another waste of time for two SO contributors who, in a moment of madness, decided to help someone who was unworthy of it.

The question should be undeleted so that the advice given is not lost.  Undelete votes, anyone?

Either way, this is positively the last time I give new users any special consideration whatsoever.

Comment: "I've had a lot of vodka" man, you aren't sober still?

Comment: related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: So it should be undeleted, closed with one more vote, then the vacuum will get it eventually?  What's the point?  The advice wasn't remarkable enough to be worth saving, and the op can still see the deleted post.

Comment: I would understand your sentiment if you had written an answer, but undeleting for a couple of comments seems like a stretch.

Comment: Also friends don't let friends drink and post...

Comment: I see no purpose or point in undeleting a horrible question because two relatively high-rep users posted comments. This hopefully will be the last time you fail to do what's proper with this type of question (regardless who posts it) and VTC/downvote. New users don't automatically get a pass for posting poor questions - they have to meet minimum quality standards just like everyone else. We're not begging for users, and having standards is meaningless if they're not upheld by (and for) everyone.

Comment: I did it again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356376/winapi-c-program-causes-access-violation-error-for-no-reason

Answer (score 5):

In your moment of vodka induced kindness, you should also have edited the question into something worthwhile keeping. As it stands it is simply a statement, it could be added to the OP's list of things for Santa to bring him.

Offering "helpful" advice via the comments is okay, but you must remember that comments are second class citizens with zero rights. Under no circumstances should a question (or attempt at a question) ever be kept simply because there was a good comment. If your input was worth keeping then you should have tendered an answer.

Comment: Did you actually read the question that was linked? There was no *editing the question into something worth keeping*, because there was no meaningful content that could be edited. You can't polish a turd no matter how hard you try. The proper behavior would have been to VTC immediately and DV to try to speed the process of getting it deleted. (It's really telling that the question was edited to add "Ignore the comments" when the post was criticized, apparently before it collected enough votes to cause the poster to delete it. "I know this this is crap. Ignore those who say so and gimme codez."

Comment: @Grant: You're right (I mistook that for the poster's edit, which it wasn't - my error), but that doesn't improve the quality of the question enough to keep it open or change my point even if you remove the last two sentences of my comment. It's a turd of a question, there's no way to apply enough polish to change that, and the comments made by those two users aren't enough reason to salvage the question from deletion.

Comment: @Ken Of course I read the question, and yes this particular question is an absolute turd. However my answer is for questions in general, and in your comment you've validated what I said - that comments are not a reason to keep a question.

Comment: Sorry, but your *you should also have edited the question into something worthwhile keeping* is inappropriate. That question could never be edited into something *worthwhile keeping*. The proper response to this sort of question *in general* is DV and vote to close, without exception, and that includes advice for *questions in general* that are of this nature. (And while I disagree with your advice in general, I appreciate that we're in agreement that comments aren't a reason to undelete a bad question.)