# Are book recommendations low quality answers?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

Today I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479557/lazy-sequence-in-clojure/31480121#31480121) as very low quality, since it's nothing more than a recommendation of a couple of books. Apart from the recommendation, the answer doesn't provide any information.

However, the flag was declined with

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

Was this an oversight, or should I have flagged differently/not-at-all?

Comment: The question is asking for a book, so the answer is an attempt to answer the question. The question should be closed, but the answer is not low quality.

Comment: @gunr2171 Doesn't that just mean that it's impossible for there to be a good answer to the question? Why does a low quality question make a low quality answer okay?

Comment: @resueman it doesn't.  Which is why the question should be closed.

Comment: People answer on off-topic/low quality post to earn reputation which should not be.IMO they should be punished like answer ban.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam While I feel the same way about it, such a mechanism would be *very* hard to implement since the quality of a question evolves in many cases (and in both directions).

Comment: This is like an avalanche! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff , http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic, http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7498/add-finding-a-good-book-for-to-off-topic-section/7502?noredirect=1#comment22536_7502, now this!

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Four somewhat related questions in five years is hardly an "avalanche."

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Ideally the system would be "question gets downvoted and closed, then later it gets deleted, so people who wrote answers lose their points because the question was deleted". Sometimes it does work that way, sometimes they just stay closed, so feel free to downvote them yourselves meanwhile.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As the commenters point out; the answer is a symptom of the problem, not the actual problem you should flag.

In this case, downvoting and voting to close the question, or if you don't have reputation, flagging it for closure is appropriate.

Downvotes are a really good idea in these situations (for the question; for the answer it's a personal call).  The downvote would put it into a review queue as a low quality post.

I've closed and deleted the question, since it's not really helpful or useful.

Comment: I think the answer is part of the problem, because by answering off-topic questions OP gets the illusion, that he can ask such questions here and gets his answer. So I think we should also inform the users, that they shouldn't answer off-topic questions. So that OP doesn't get the feeling, that his question is on-topic on SO and gets answered. Which I think helps, that we maybe get a few less off-topic questions.

Comment: @Rizier123 my favorite reference for cases like that is [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601) "...Don't ever answer a question, not via chat, comments, or any other way. It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same and eventually get what they want."

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the answer attempts to answer the question. It's not NAA. And because the question asks for book resources, I wouldn't consider it VLQ.

The question on the other hand, should be closed for asking for a book.

> Doesn't that just mean that it's impossible for there to be a good answer to the question? Why does a low quality question make a low quality answer okay?

The question should not have existed on the site to begin with; it's off-topic. The unfortunate part is that the post wasn't closed in time. An opinionated answer got though. So let's close it before more make it in.

As for what to do with the answer once the post is closed: you can either leave it alone if it's not doing a lot of harm, or you can downvote. In more extreme cases a moderator might lock the post or clean up the answers.

...or George can nuke it...