# Off-topic: "My email isn't spam"

Tags: discussion, scope

I am attempting to clarify the scope of the posting guidelines related to evading spam filters. My interpretation of the site policies is that ***these questions should be closed as off-topic,*** and that there isn't usually another site in the SE network to refer them to. Is my interpretation correct?

In the [email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) tag, I routinely flag the following for closing as off-topic.

- My email is blocked by Gmail as spam, what can I do?
- My email is blocked as spam, how do I configure PTR / SPF / DKIM / what not?
- My email is blocked as spam, how can I reformat it so it goes through?

Tangentially, there is also

- Help, my system was hacked and is transmitting spam
- Help, my system is blacklisted by a DNSBL or similar reputation provider

Obviously, none of these topics are programming-related.

- There is no way to programmatically influence (say) Gmail's company-internal decisions for what to block -- and if you find a way to bypass one particular filter of theirs, it's only a matter of time before the spammers notice, too; and so any useful answer will be extremely volatile, and likely to be obsolete by the time a reader visits the question.  Furthermore, answers detailing how to bypass a spam filter are likely to be picked up by spammers, and thus are ethically borderline at the very least.
- Configuring DNS and related infrastructure obviously belongs on https://serverfault.com/ (though will likely be closed as a duplicate there, I guess).
- The third topic really goes by the same reasoning as the first -- even if changing which headers are transmitted might coincidentally involve some programming, email deliverability as such is not a programming topic (and in fact, I don't believe there is a place in the Stack Exchange network for this particular topic currently).  What to put in your message in order to bypass one or more spam filters is fundamentally a content question, not a logic question.

Now, my close votes have generally been accepted, though not always so; and now, [one correspondent is challenging my close vote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066187/emails-flagged-as-spam#comment52030038_32066187).  Thus I am posting here in the hope that my reasoning could be either refuted, or accepted as a consensus interpretation of the [Stack Overflow posting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

For background, here are some samples of previous close votes of mine.

- Not closed, but arguably members of one of the above sets *(and now, by massive meta effect, closed and deleted by Community♦)*:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373456/spam-mail-and-hostname-settings-on-ubuntu
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255750/my-ip-adress-is-not-blacklisted-but-emails-are-going-to-spam
- Deleted (requires 10k reputation to view):

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693029/dedicated-server-emails-goes-in-spam-on-many-email-providers -- deleted by Community♦
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455657/gmail-puts-emails-from-my-fresh-server-into-spam-folder-due-to-its-similar-to -- deleted by OP
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443400/symfony1-4-mail-send-to-spam -- deleted by Community♦
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051293/how-do-i-get-emails-into-inboxes-and-not-spamboxes -- deleted by Community♦
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688735/postfix-mail-server-spam-allboutspam-spamassassin-batv -- deleted by Community♦
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555218/lot-of-spam-mails-are-being-sent-from-vpscentos-postfix -- deleted by Community♦
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415059/email-going-in-spam-folder-using-php -- deleted by Community♦
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222259/postfix-smtp-mail-is-sent-to-spam -- deleted by Community♦
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567841/mail-sent-throught-email-client-refused-as-spam

<sub>Duplicate note: this is **not** a question about [how to react to off-topic questions in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions); it is a question about Stack Overflow scope.</sub>

Comment: It's tricky. It could go both ways. At first glance it has nothing to do with programming, but if you look deeper it would appear the emails are created programmatically and sent to multiple users (I'm supposing clients). The OP either needs to re-write his post or it should be closed.

Comment: @Grimbode if the problem is what you put in the body of your email, or who you send it to, how does it relate to programming? Unless your question is "I don't know how to change the body on an email I already created programatically", I don't think it's relevant to post here.

Comment: [He could try here](http://spam.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Is it worth adding a section to the tag except saying these questions aren't valid. Is there even a precedent for doing that?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan There is indeed. The evidence suggests that nobody reads tag descriptions when posting, but it's a good place to document this practice for reference.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan It can also be handy for reviewers. If I see a question in for example triage where I doubt the tag usage I will check the wiki for such guidance.

Comment: @Patrice *"Unless your question is "I don't know how to change the body on an email I already created programatically""* be careful because that's a slippery slope, ie. what's the difference between emails and any structured piece of text?

Comment: @cosbor11: I expect any regularly active user with rights to vote-to-close and experience in a tag to be routinely closing questions that are off-topic. It is the responsibility of the whole community to do so. Questions can easily be re-opened once they have been edited, but to wait for the user to edit first does not scale.

Comment: "My email is blocked as spam, how can I reformat it so it goes through?" might be a valid question for superuser? After all, spam filters rely not only on the source, but also on the contents of the email.

Comment: @A.Donda no, is not on topic *anywhere* on SE. Is something that is not answerable since is "state secret" of each company.

Comment: It seems to me the topic is off-topic because it does not concern itself with programming or development. Two sites that may be helpful are [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) and [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). If you ask on those site, you probably want to avoid framing it as "email evasion techniques". Instead, use something like "delivery and/or confirmation strategies" including "when a domain may be blacklisted"*.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The question being questioned is definitely off topic and the poster of the question seems to know this, but attempts to justify with the idea that he cannot find a better fit on the Stack Exchange network. That is a horrible excuse and not at all reasonable.

There isn't even a slight mention of anything programming related in the question. The thought that it is somehow Stack Overflow related is absurd.

Since he created a bounty to prevent a close vote, I flagged for moderator attention. You should too.

Comment: Every time someone says "I can't find another site for this" or "What about this question from 2008?" I politely respond something like, "If you want to defend your post as on-topic, please cite one or more **site rules** justifying your position." These other arguments are simply tangential and not germane.

Comment: "That is a horrible excuse and not at all reasonable." Though I agree, it may also a bad position from SE, as a Q&A site, to not provide a catch-all sub-site for questions like this. Not doing so will just mean these questions will constantly be posted. Because as we all know, just because a question is against the rules, doesn't mean it won't get an answer. And an answer is what most people use SE for, and don't really care about the rules. The people who frequent meta/care about the rules are in the vast minority.

Comment: "it may also a bad position from SE" - Nope. Not our problem.

Comment: @Rob Well, you can always direct them to yahoo answer's or something like that... Moreover even if such a sub-site exists it doesn't mean SO wont be flooded by crappy off-topic questions. A lot of people reason in this way: SO has millions of users so posting there you are sure to obtain some response and in a few minutes. Posting on a small site, even where on topic, may result in slower responses, hence fuck the rules... the correct response is to close/delete crap *fast* so that people don't obtain what they want and stop doing this.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I agree. Just because it has to deal with computers, people flock to SO for help. This is not the only site/network. I think people today are just afraid to use traditional forums, to contact support of the service/product provider, or to ask on Reddit.

Comment: @Rob I sympathize with the idea that the site will always be flooded with the traffic of questioners who won't read the rules (or the fine manual), but the idea of a "catch-all" site seems to imply that we (as SE citizens) are somehow responsible for every type of question on the internet. Surely we have to draw the line somewhere?

Comment: @Rob anyway if people can't read the rules to post on-topic question, how would they be made aware of your"catch all"... people won't get answers on that since it'll be a hellhole of junk, so they'll end up posting on SO anyway

Comment: @WayneWerner: Answers.com?

Answer (score 13):

Not to cast asparagus on the validity of your reasoning, but it's just not a big deal that some OP disagreed with you about a close vote. If you are a responsible citizen and cast many close votes, you are going to run into people who don't like it. After all, they posted the <del>crap</del> inappropriate content, so they presumably thought that it should be here. Except for the special dupe-hammer, you're just one voice, and nothing happens unless four people agree with you. *If* four people agree with you, that's *prima facie* evidence that your judgement was good in the first place. So I'd counsel you not to stress about situations like this. Don't feel that you have to respond to complaints at all. If the question does eventually get closed, and the OP really wants to grieve (in the labor law sense), the OP can post here. Oh, and like GEOCHET says, if you see <del>crap</del> inappropriate content protected by a bounty, use a custom flag.

Comment: I'm not stressing, I just wanted a reasonable page to link to in the future, as this was not the first time the topic came up

Comment: Asparagus?!?​​​

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit old joke for 'cast aspersions'.

Comment: To be fair the turn of phrase I know is "casting nasturtiums".

Answer (score 6):

Even if the particular disputed question had been related to programming, the poster still need to narrow it down to a specific technical problem, provide information of the what attempts have been made to solve it *programmatically*, and if possible also provide the problematic source code.

Otherwise the post should be closed for a number of other reasons, other than it being off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Because the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066187/emails-flagged-as-spam) is now deleted (requires 10k rep to view), I'll point out here that @Shog9 posted a comment there directing to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ for this type of question, with a specific link to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59813/reduce-likelihood-of-mailchimp-email-campaign-going-to-spam

Comment: For general server administration topics, try [sf]. For general computing, try [su]. For Unix-specific questions, there's also [unix.se]