# Request for [comments] on burnination

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments)[commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting)

## Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tag excerpt says it's for comments in programming languages, but most of the questions under it are questions about commenting systems. Both of these things are more/less keywords.

## Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not for questions that are done next to programming like documenting or commenting. Therefore, we should remove this tag.

## Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, it's usually quickly to see if a questions is about comments without this tag.

## Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, because commenting is a common thing used in almost any language, outside the fact that it is a comment, there is no other similarity in comments

**Tags to burninate:**
[comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments)[commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting)

**Highly related tags:**
[block-comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block-comments)[multiline-comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiline-comments)[comment-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comment-conventions)[code-comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-comments)

Comment: What about [block-comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block-comments), [multiline-comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiline-comments), [comment-conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comment-conventions) and [code-comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-comments)?

Comment: Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: Questions about parsing comments, or extracting comments, or stripping comments, or otherwise interacting with comments are undoubtedly on-topic for this site. So this is just another case of someone coming across a "generic"-sounding tag and wanting to burninate it. That's counter-productive. Tags can work in combination. If I tag a question [c++] and [comments], it becomes quite clear what my question is about, adding meaningful information to the post. This usage is supported by the fact that tag filters support filtering by multiple tags.

Comment: I would certainly support *cleaning up* the [comments] tag, closing and deleting any questions that are not programming related. I'll grant that there are a fair number of them. But that is a far cry from *tag burnination*, which I think is completely inappropriate. That rule #4 ("does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?") trips people up a lot, you are not the first. It doesn't mean simply "can this possibly be ambiguous?"

Comment: @CodyGray why don't you post that as an answer? I would love to give my upvote with some more weight ;-)

Comment: Having tags for [tag:comments] is about as useful as having tags for [tag:loops] which is entirely useless.

Comment: @CodyGray "Questions about parsing comments, or extracting comments, or stripping comments, or otherwise interacting with comments are undoubtedly on-topic for this site." And precisely that was the argument we used several times to remove other tags too, as I recall. SO member barely cares from where the data comes from (txt, doc, mp3, etc.) as long as the tool you are using is meant to consume that kind of data (regex?, vba, libav, etc.).

Comment: Suppose the tool I'm using is a C preprocessor, @braiam. I tag my question [c] and [preprocessor] and [comments]. With your argument, the only tag I should have on that question is [c] because there are multiple different types of preprocessors (aha! an ambiguous tag!) and same thing for comments. My disagreement with this line of reasoning is quite well-established.

Comment: @CodyGray what has to do the fact that you are using a C preprocessor with comments? I'm not following. Instead lets look at a better example: because you are sending a [email](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302903/792066) you believe that you should use the email tag? Or, to use [comments] instead, because I'm using SEDE to figure out the average length of all comments in the site, should I use the comments tag?

Comment: @Braiam Your examples are incorrect usages of the tag, but do not prove the tags themselves are bad. Writing a query to determine the average length of comments doesn't actually have anything to do with comments. On the other hand, using a C preprocessor to strip out comments from a source file *does* have to do with comments, so the tag is appropriate. You are not following because you have this preconceived notion that tags with broad definitions can only be used as meta tags. That's not correct. If they're being used that way, the question is mistagged. Not an inherent problem with the tag.