# Should I be answering 'code requests'?

Tags: discussion, answers

In the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, there seems to be an extremely common practice which I'm guilty of too. A user asks for something along the lines of "I want to get from some data A and transform it into B, how do I do it?" with no effort. A lot of these questions are pretty easy to answer if you're well-versed in ES6 and functional programming and garner lots of fast upvotes.

This makes it extremely tempting to just answer these 'code requests' for easy reputation. I was under the impression that the OP had to actually show effort instead of just asking for code to be written for them. Is this practice wrong or am I interpreting the policy wrong?

Comment: No, they should be downvoted and closed. Such questions should then be removed either through roomba or delete votes. If people don't answer then roomba will do just fine.

Comment: There's a gigantic "it depends" here. Is the question formulated in such a way that someone else might be able to find it and apply it to their own problem? That's really the important thing to consider: reusability. ["Shows effort" is just a proxy for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor).

Comment: @AndrewLi some get closed.  It's a race between the closevoters and the rep-personalServicesWorkers.  Sometimes the close votes win:)

Comment: Very closely related: [Is the How to Answer article's section on only answering well-asked questions advice or site policy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad)

Comment: Note that a lot of these questions, especially in the `javascript` tag, are duplicates. We have so many questions in `javascript` that are immediately answered (by some high-rep people too) which have been asked and answered many, many times. [Recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44789790/215552).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Those two users should be answer-banned for encouraging this behaviour on such a regular basis. It's horrifying!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yeah. While they are good answerers, they encourage low quality and gimme-teh-code questions. This question was raised when one of those answerers answered a code request and instantly got 5 upvotes, with the question also garnering a few. It's really bad and it degrades the site.

Comment: At the moment, there is no incentives to flag duplicate. If an accepted dupe flag would count as an accepted answer, maybe users would take the time to find the obvious duplicate.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I agree that it would probably be an improvement if there were a rep reward for dupe hunting (and maybe also points towards badges), but I don't think earning an accept is appropriate. OTOH, the reward does need to be comparable to what you'd expect to earn from writing an answer. For further discussion on this topic, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322096/should-we-try-to-train-users-to-close-as-duplicate-vs-answer and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes

Comment: Wehn im elekted prezidnt i wil giv evry1 kodez... /s

Comment: see also [Should we add a “Do my work for me” close reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630/839601)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Looks like it just happened again with the same answerer. Should I alert them of this meta post and tell them it's wrong?

Comment: @AndrewLi I've tried before, and it didn't seem to take. Maybe having more people saying it (and people with higher rep than I) would help.

Comment: @AndrewLi I fundamentally disagree. ES6 can be pretty confusing and tough to find answers if you're coming from something else like Ruby. This type of policing doesn't happen in the Ruby community. I've only found it here in the JS community, and honestly it's pretty lame.

Comment: Shouldn't StackOverflow be about helping people? I understand the intention here, but I think sometimes people make the wrong call that the op didn't take any time to try to figure it out.

Comment: _"Shouldn't StackOverflow be about helping people?"_ [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179009/159251).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe.  It depends on the identities of A and B.

If A and B are both reasonably standard things (like, say, JSON and YAML), and the request doesn't seem too specific to one particular set of requirements, go ahead and answer it.  There may not be much to elaborate on.  If the problem really is trivial (as is the case for JSON and YAML), the OP "showing effort" is just going to change the subject of a question into "How does [language feature X that I'm misusing] work?" which is a substantially less useful question for future Google traffic (Because in most cases, it's a dupe of an existing question, but with a title about JSON and YAML!  Yes, you can edit the title, but at that point, why bother having a dupe in the first place?).

If A and B are both highly problem-specific formats, or the problem is clearly very involved, downvote and/or close-vote, and write comments encouraging the OP to show the code they have so far and explain the specific issue they are stuck on.

Finally, a reminder: The questioner often does not care about rep.  They care about answers.  When you answer somebody's question, you are encouraging the questioner, and others like the questioner, to ask questions similar to the one you just answered.  This is like upvoting, but with a much larger weight.  Answer judiciously.