# Should I just spoon feed answers if I'm a point junkie?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I don't want to criticize a 50k+ user.  But I see it over and over - what is basically a "have you ever freaking used google" question followed by an answer that really is just a Google regurgitation.  Someone who has the ability to close the question but instead answers what is likely a dup.  Should I not try to provide answers for new questions?  I get dinged when I downvote an answer that is trivial.

If my only Pavlovian Conditioning is points, why strive for quality answers?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly it is you're asking about with this question. Are you asking why some people answer questions that are probably duplicates? Also, since nobody knows who voted for what, how exactly do you get "dinged when I downvote an answer that is trivial"?

Comment: Related reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370539/repeated-behavior-of-user-harvesting-reputation-from-known-duplicates-next-step, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322096/should-we-try-to-train-users-to-close-as-duplicate-vs-answer

Comment: 50k+ users are in no less need of criticism than anyone else.

Comment: Stack Overflow users are not robots, everyone has their own motives for doing what they do. Some people have a need to collect points and will do so at all costs. The why can be as simple as "I'm bored" or "I'm on this planet to help *everyone at all times unconditionally*". Two groups of people you will not persuade to start dupe closing.

Comment: @Gimby I'm bored and I like to help people, and for me dupe closing works just as well as answering for both of those things. I don't know if that applies to everyone else in those groups, though