# How is this regex question too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

In regards to the below question, I want to understand why it was closed as "too broad".

As far as regex questions go, this is the most focused, verifiable, and clear question I have ever seen. No room for interpretation. If there is any room for interpretation, or providing any other answer that is more than a stylistic change, what is it?

Technically, it had issues before it was edited (just less clear, it said the exact same thing the whole time); But it was closed almost 2 hours after the final edit, which means that the question, in its current form, was deemed 'too broad', by multiple people.

Also, if this really isn't too broad, I doubt anyone would flag it if it came up in audit, so should it be reopened or left as is? (Does the audit system have anything to protect itself from bad audit questions?) I can't vote to open, so does that mean I should flag it for moderator review?

Here is a copy of the question.

> So I have a regex pattern that works well. I wanted to see if I could
>   make it better.
>
> Here it is:
>
> "(SEGMENTA)(.*?)(SEGMENTB)(SEGMENTB)(SEGMENTB)"
>
> So this looks for any pattern with (SEGMENTA) (anything)
>   (SEGMENTB)(SEGMENTB)(SEGMENTB).
>
> But is there also a way to say that I want it to bring back if it only
>   has this"
>
> "(SEGMENTA)(.*?)(SEGMENTB)"
>
> Essentially the last 2 ending SegmentB can be optional.

Comment: doesn't look like the first 3 bullets as mentoned in the [tagwiki under How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) are fulfilled. Too broad it is.

Comment: I have no idea what this means: *"But is there also a way to say that I want it to bring back if it only has this""* If you know what it means, you should edit the question.

Comment: "_I can't vote to open, so does that mean I should flag it for moderator review?_" No.  Do not use custom moderator flags for things the community can handle.  Your meta post is sufficient.

Comment: @rene I don't get what you mean. He said what he tried, he said what he wants, there are no duplicates (that I can tell); What wasn't fulfilled?

Comment: @CodyGray The edit queue was saturated at the time and then I kinda forgot about it. Edited it now, but the question title really says all you need to know.

Comment: I don't see what his tried input is, I don't see what his current output and expected output is, I don't see which dialect they are requesting the regex for. Okay, I'll give you that between the couple of current regex questions on the site it is possible no dupe exists. my bad.

Comment: @rene It opens with the regex he has now... true it doesn't include sample input and output, but the question is so simple, do you really need it to understand the question? (Would it help if I edited that in for future readers?)

Comment: My main problem is that, to me, if this question is unclear, almost all regex questions should be closed as 'too broad' because almost all the answers start with 'if you allow me to make these assumptions...'

Comment: Concerning assumptions: Your answer is missing the assumption, that OP used the capturing groups just for fun.

Comment: @Tezra If almost all regex questions can't actually be answered given the information provided in the question, then yes, they should be closed. That there's lots of bad questions doesn't make them any less bad.

Comment: @SebastianProske The OP also didn't say what OS/program he is running. I think it's safe to say that that doesn't affect the answer. It is also a trivial adjustment to switch from non capturing to capturing groups. The OP said he only cared about matching 1 or 3 times, so that is all the answer needs to address. I kinda feel if you are going to nitpick about what the OP DIDN'T say, than half of SE should be closed as too broad. In which case, why are people being 100X more strict about the rules for this question as apposed to all other regex questions? What stands out with this one?

Comment: Well, there is a deleted answer on that question with a single comment from a mod. That is what stands out.

Comment: So let me try asking something else, aside from adding input and expected output examples, how can this question be improved to make a good question? (As any information that isn't explicitly stated, can easily be added by anyone, pretty much just from reading the question title)

Comment: That is good question ...now if you would have only asked that from the start ...

Comment: What would be the purpose to have it re-opened by the way? Do you expect it to have much more and better answers? Also worth mentioning now that due to the meta attention it also gathered 2 delete votes, needs one more to be deleted completely

Comment: @CodyGray Apparently, the review queue decided "But is there also a way to make it also match this" isn't clearer than "But is there also a way to say that I want it to bring back if it only has this"". How can I make that any clearer?

Comment: First of all, I don't know what review queue you're talking about. [The question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660755/match-1-or-3-of-pattern-at-end-of-match) hasn't been edited in over a week, and that edit occurred *before* it was closed. Second, I can't advise you on how to make this any clearer, because I don't understand it myself. Maybe the problem is that I'm not a regular expressions wizard (far from it), but the question makes very little sense to me, so I'm kind of on the "unclear what you're asking" side as it stands now.

Comment: @rene I don't think it is a bad question, at the very least, it deserves the top 5% for a regex question. My only concern with reopening it is the review queue has an audit system, and I would expect most people to fail this in an audit. (I don't know how the audit system picks audits though, so is that a null issue?)

Comment: If this is "top 5% for a regex question", then that tag needs some serious attention… Good thing we have new moderators coming down the pike, eh?

Comment: @Tezra it has mixed votes (up and down) so yes, audits is a null issue as only posts with only upvotes or only down votes are considered for audits

Comment: Too bad tag burnination isn't something a mod can do @CodyGray otherwise I would have a backlog for you to handle after [tag:regex] ...

Comment: @CodyGray first, if you browse Meta about regex, you should find that this has been a known problem for a long while. (That regex questions are almost always bad when first posted) I'm usually in the triage queue, and I've failed audits for question I was too lenient on (because I thought they where clear enough), so I just assume it picks posts at random.

Comment: *"My main problem is that, to me, if this question is unclear, almost all regex questions should be closed as 'too broad'"* yes, they do. But people still keep answering them....

Comment: So it seems to me that my answer to "why is this bad" is more that regex questions are bad for SO, and should probably have its own SE, as only a master of Regex can read anything remotely regex.

Comment: @CodyGray This question really is as simple and clear as a regex question can possibly be (at least that can get past the edit review queue). I'm great at regex, so I read it just fine, but if it really is gibberish to anyone who can't read regex, that might be the entirety of the problem? (At least, until someone can show me that this question can possibly be made any better)

Comment: What I'd really like to know is why you think it *isn't* too broad.  Suppose for a second that this were a question about C, C++ or JavaScript that covered similar grounds.  Would it be too broad then, or would it still fit on-topic?

Comment: @Makoto A programming equivalent would be "I know how to do `if(1 <= x <= 3)`, but how do I do `if( x equals 1 or 3)`?". That is not broad in the slightest. I will accept an argument that it's stupid because it is rather basic, but that sadly describes 80% of regex questions just because it is so much harder to read for those not already an expert.

Comment: You really  should have included the question you mentioned as a quote into this question of yours.

Comment: @Jan I underestimated the meta-effect. replaced link with question text (should probably have done that from the start)

Answer (score 14):

It's too broad, and here are two reasons why:

1. **He didn't read the excerpt**

   We don't write tag excerpts just for fun. My top peeve on SO? People who don't read and then get shocked when their posts get downvoted/closed/deleted. Here's the [regex excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (emphasis mine):

   > Regular expressions provide a declarative language to match patterns within strings. They are commonly used for string validation, parsing, and transformation. **Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.** NOTE: Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead.

   The only tag on that question is [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex). So now you know. Pity it took a question getting [red and blue lasered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU8zJ.jpg) for that.
2. **The answer isn't useful**

   So, there's POSIX and PCRE. But the question and answer are in…pseudo-code:

   ```
   SEGMENT((?:SEGMENT){2})?
   ```

   This takes regex, which is already hard enough to understand, and makes it even more arcane. If I want to use this…there's nothing to use. Yes, we sometimes have academic discussions, but keeping the content usable for other people is fairly important. The only good thing about this is he's not trying to [parse HTML with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483).

Comment: I like that this is grounded in something to prove objectively that the question does have an issue. There are a lot of regex questions that fail to specify a flavor. I kinda feel it should be ok for a basic question like this, where a solution that works in all flavors exists... but I can't flag every regex question that fails to list a flavor, can I? (The flag queue is saturated enough) I guess that's a question of how aggressive do you want to be with flagging.

Comment: @Tezra If a question has a problem, flag it. Don't worry about the size of the queue. And just because other bad questions remain open (6000+ questions asked per day overall) isn't a license to leave this one open.

Comment: Is 'too broad' the appropriate flag here though? It seems like it is only a low quality question. I don't feel any of the flag accurately describe the issue (lack of OP effort mostly)

Comment: I take you back to my answer, tho. He's talking about a general regex principle. Had he posted a specific example, the question would have been  acceptable. Specific is the antonym of too broad.

Comment: Do note that the initial revision of said question did try to parse html ...

Comment: @rene It was edited before the pony could come, so it's all good

Comment: @Machavity The original question text had specific text instead of filler text. (switched to the filler because comments got derailed by sight of html and had to be purged with holy fire). To be clear by specific example, are you saying that using specific text over filler would have made it a good question, or that a more specific question, that required a more complicated answer should have been asked?

Comment: @Tezra The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44660755/1) wasn't that much more specific (it was still pseudo-code). Yes, he was parsing HTML, but *what was he using to parse it*? Java? PHP? PERL? It would have helped to have the question tagged, say, [java] and then give a full example in Java.

Comment: What's pseudocode about that fragment?

Comment: @JoshCaswell What's he running it in? And, as I noted earlier, what type of regex are we talking? So it's pseudo-code without context

Comment: I agree, the flavor needs to be specified, but "pseudocode" seems a little strong.

Comment: @Machavity In what regex engine does `(x)(xx)?` not work to match "1 or 3" in where x is any string constant? What regex flavor could change this behavior? What other non-stylistic changes could you possibly do to that? That is main reason I don't think that rule applies **in this one case**. I can understand this as bad as being too basic a question, but what information can you possibly add to the question to change that answer?

Comment: Also, the question never said anything about parsing. All the OP wanted, was "Match 1 or 3. not 2, not more, not less, just 1 or 3". He was matching a string pattern in a blob of text that just happened to resemble html. The match he wanted made no sense for any html parser either. So, this is really just an extremely specific, very basic regex question, where flavor happens to not affect the answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Funny you should mention this...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354)

Here's why I feel like it's too broad:

- The question is asking us to essentially write their regex with these specified constraints.  That is, they have some working regex that satisfies their needs, but then they say that they need a *different* regex.
- The question doesn't tell us what they've attempted, or where they're having trouble.  All we get are the requirements, which aren't really...enough.  Yes, we know that they want the last two fragments to be optional, but...okay, where are you having trouble with doing that in your regex?