# Good answer, bad for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There is [this question asking for a description and comparison of various Python tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981444/what-is-difference-between-anaconda-python-python-idle-ipython-jupyter-noote) ([<10k screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb9QU.png)). This does not seem like an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. But the answer is probably one of the best on the Internet (AKA: Google search) that I've found.

What is the appropriate site for this question? In the comments someone linked to the [Python Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) where it has been discussed before. The answer is too good to lose in my opinion. It is short, concise and well-written. It "instantly" answers the question to those who ask this question, and I hear this question a lot from new Python users.

Also, what is the appropriate action to take in this case?

Comment: @AndrasDeak everyone can see you downvoted the answer...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, I know, but I presume we're all sort of grown-ups here. If the answerer would've left a comment asking about the downvote I would've explained it anyway; it's not a secret what I think about answers like this. Anyway, if you feel it biases the picture, feel free to replace the screenshot.

Comment: I'm kind of wondering if Documentation might have been a place this kind of info could have lived. Like a, "Common Tools for the Language" topic or something.

Answer (score 13):

The question is *egregiously* off-topic for Stack Overflow, it is too broad by any reasonable measure, and it entirely lacks research; any amount of googling would've answered OP's questions.

Now, the question is what we want to do with honest answers to blatantly off-topic questions. On the one hand the official guidance is "to vote on the post" and that the true pearls of Stack Overflow sometimes come from sand (which typically consists of fish poop). On the other hand, answering blatantly off-topic questions is indeed unhealthy for the website, because it gives off the false impression that such questions are welcome here.

I don't think there's community consensus in the subject. Some users will upvote these answers because they are "good" or because "they try to help poor asker"; others will downvote it because they are not useful for the site in the long run, and they believe that [ruthless peer-pressure is the main method of maintaining high signal-to-noise ratio on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353993/5067311).

Note that in the specific instance in question, the answerer themselves [noted that the post is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46981765/5067311):

> P.S. As described in the comments between John Y. and myself, this question would typically be off topic for this Stackexchange in general, but I'm afraid there aren't very many good options to get this question answered which is why I decided to answer.

This suggests that the answerer is OK with gathering a handful of downvotes.

Also note the fallacy that the answerer might be hinting at: just because there's *no* Stack Exchange site for this question doesn't mean that we should tolerate it on Stack Overflow. With that reasoning any sort of mad question could be asked anywhere, for want of a topical Stack Exchange site.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=is+sand+fish+poop

Comment: I am fine with a few downvotes, but as MattR mentions it's a common enough question that might benefit having an archive here. It won't stop being asked until someone answers it...

Comment: @Aaron people probably also search a lot for how to cook crystal meth. That doesn't imply that we should keep a recipe on Stack Overflow. Even if you remove the hyperbole/strawman/slippery slope, my point is that we can't decrease the quality of Stack Overflow to keep up with the declining ability of users to find basic information on the internet.

Comment: @Aaron:  So you're suggesting that we answer *all* kinds of questions like this.  Because questions on how to interop with languages and what all these technologies actually *are* will exist until the end of time, and in no way are we meant to actively maintain a list of those differences.

Comment: @MattR That seems on topic for [EarthScience.SE].;)

Comment: I wish you hadn't conflated "off topic" with "too broad" in your first sentence, but the fallacy pointing at the end is well done.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I was going to say that this question is as off-topic as tool requests are (but instead of looking for a specific tool or manual or tutorial, the asker is looking for generic information that's all over the web), but I double-checked [help/on-topic] and you're right, it's technically on topic here. Still, I believe questions like "*how does a while loop work?*" are not on topic (since this is not a tutorial service), but then the question we're discussing is pretty much along the same lines: "how are these jumble of concepts related?". So your on-topicness mileage may indeed vary.

Comment: Fair enough. It _is_ sort of on the tool request borderline, but I do agree [with Ilmari Karonen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358572/603977) that a question about tools should not be _ipso facto_ off-topic.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I just found that answer and I've only skimmed it yet, but I think we need to distinguish between tool requests and questions about tools. Asking what IDE to use for your dev work is off-topic. Asking how to set breakpoints with your specific chosen IDE is on-topic. I'll read that answer in more detail later, so sorry if this comment missed the point.

Comment: Yes; absolutely agreed with your distinction.

Answer (score 6):

I'm normally a sympathetic ear for "this question is off-topic, but has a really good answer, so we shouldn't delete it" complaints. Probably a far too sympathetic ear for some of the hard-liners on Meta.

And I strongly disagree with the vigilante "downvote people who dare to answer off-topic questions into submission" strategy pursued by Andras and others. Not because I disagree with the aim of improving Stack Overflow's quality, but because [I don't think this is a reasonable or effective way of going about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions/255861#255861).

But, in this case, I honestly don't see the argument. [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46981765) is *okay at best*. Yes, it adequately answers the question that was asked, but the question is off-topic and completely unsuitable for Stack Overflow. No one is contesting that fact, so the only issue is whether the answer is awesome enough that it should save an off-topic, inappropriate question. It just isn't. Not anywhere close.

The question was appropriately deleted. Note that a question's deletion takes the answer(s) with it, which removes any reputation gained and thus any lasting incentive to answer. This is the sane method for quality-control, and the time-tested one.

If the aim is to preserve value, and you find Aaron's short descriptions to be useful, then consider editing them into the corresponding tag wiki pages.

Comment: For what it's worth I usually reserve my downvotes to spoon-feeding answers to tutorial-type or code request questions (in an attempt at discouraging rep farming), and answers where the answerer is clearly aware that the question shouldn't have been answered in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

It feels like a technically-oriented disambiguation question.  The OP is looking to define these terms based on what they've seen, given that they've seen people talk about these technologies before.

The *problem* is that there is absolutely ***no*** effort to research this for themselves.  A quick Google search would turn up answers here for everything that they're looking for.  In terms of an on-topic question, it doesn't quite have the right feel about it; I feel like I'm on the fence about it, which is why I'd default to it being off-topic.

Chat would be a good place to discuss it, since it's more informal than a question, and you're more likely to get the kinds of answers that would fit a question like this there anyway.

It's fairly broad in scope, so I'd vote to close it as "too broad", given that they're looking for a giant list of information.  If they want to get info on this kind of stuff, they can ask in chat or do some research.

(I get the above sounds harsh, but when faced with the alternative, we're basically subject to someone's lack of research.)

Comment: I can agree with this. The lack of research is evident. But the answer there does more explaining in less reading than anywhere else. The answer, from a Python user's perspective, is just spot-on (besides the opinion about personal favorite)

Comment: @MattR:  Yes, but it ends with more recommendations for tools, which are the kinds of answers we want to *avoid*.  Irrespective of the answerer's intent, off-topic still means off-topic.

Comment: @sara:  You're going to want to take your time and look at things piece by piece.  Start small and then expand your search.  A big part of software development in any language, technology stack or framework is problem solving and searching for answers online.  Take the time to practice and hone this vital skill.

Comment: @Makoto Research effort is surely important in any question, in that it makes it easier to answer. But after it is answered nobody cares about the content of the question. A good answer is sufficient for most people landing on the question though Google, they don't really care how much effort the OP but into it. In my opinion a good answer can salvage the lack of effort in the question.

Comment: @user000001:  I get it, I get it, optimizing for pearls instead of sand, but that doesn't shield the question from extra moderation or scrutiny.  It also doesn't make it "suddenly okay" to post a really bad question if it gets a really good answer.

Comment: @sara also, one thing you need to consider... look at your post. How does it show ANY effort? You said you looked in Google in the comments.... but nowhere does it show in your post. Doing research is good... showing it is better :) for instance, WHAT did you find that got you more confused? Why doesnt it aligned with your current understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, I took a look at [the official description of what's on-topic at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and... funnily, I can't seem to find anything there that would make this question off-topic.

Let's take a look at what that page actually says is on-topic at Stack Overflow:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Anaconda, Python, IDLE, etc. are clearly "software tools commonly used by programmers", and figuring out how they differ from and relate to each other is clearly "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

So, great, it looks like SO *is* the right place for questions like this!  Admittedly, there's no source code in this question, but that's not actually mandatory, just recommended.  Nor does this paragraph say anything about "showing effort" being required, either.

But wait!  There's a bunch of exceptions further down the page.  Surely there's something there that says you have to show your research effort?

Well, the closest thing there is, is this (*emphasis* original):

> 3. Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

But this clearly isn't a homework question!  It's also not "seeking debugging help", it's not "about a problem that can no longer be reproduced", nor is it about "professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration".  It *is* asking about off-site software tools, but it's *not* asking for recommendations for them, and the tools it asks about are clearly "used primarily for programming".  So it looks like none of the six numbered exceptions apply, either.

It's of course possible that this question has already been asked before, but if so, it should've been closed as a duplicate, not as off-topic.  And so far nobody's suggested any duplicate for it.  It's also pretty evidently not eligible for closing as "unclear", "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based", since it's asking a clearly scoped factual question that can be answered in a few sentences.

---

So, at this point, I can see only two possible conclusions:

1. this question is, in fact, on-topic at SO according to official policy, and should be reopened; or
2. the official policy [documented in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is outdated, and needs to be updated to match the actual current scope of SO, whatever that may be.

Personally, I'm hoping that the answer *isn't* #2.  I'm aware that there seems to be a sizable and growing contingent of SO users who seem to view this site as "Debugging Stack Exchange", and who will vote to close as off-topic any question that is *not* a homework or debugging question (with source code and a list of the OP's prior solving efforts included, of course).  But personally, I'd like to hope that there's still room on SO for questions about things like algorithms and development tools.  And, yes, for simple clearly asked questions about common newbie problems that are *not* bloated down by a gratuitous code dump or a list of attempted dead ends.

That's because I still believe that the goal of SO is to "make the Internet a better place" by creating a searchable repository of comprehensive, correct and clearly written answers to common programming problems.  And while "show your effort" may be a useful barrier to keep the volume of redundant questions down (not that it seems to be working very well), the people who find the question and its answers on Google don't care how much or how little effort the person who originally asked it had spent on it.  All they care about is actually finding a good *answer* to the question.

So, yes, I think the question should be undeleted.  Not because there's anything particularly good or bad about the question itself, but because it has a useful and well written answer, and because there's no way to undelete the answer without undeleting the question, too.

Or, if the new consensus on SO really is so dead set against "rewarding a low-effort question" by leaving it open and eligible for upvotes (which such a simple and common question surely would collect over time from people with the same problem stumbling across it), perhaps we should encourage the author of the answer to repost it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on a new question of their own.  Unless, of course, the community would just close that one too because the question still "showed no effort".

Or perhaps we should just stop fighting the trend and create yet another new SE site for questions about programming tools, just like [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) was created because people asking algorithm questions no longer felt welcome on SO.  Maybe call it "Software Development Stack Exchange" or something.  Then we could finally dedicate SO to nothing but debugging and homework questions and let it slowly sink to the bottom of the Google rankings where it belongs.

Comment: The question is closed as "too broad", not for being off topic. While I agree with some of your editorializing, I also agree with "too broad" here. I don't find the answer satisfactory _at all_ for the question -- it raises more questions, if anything -- and I can't imagine anything less than a _very_ long article doing so. The topic itself is not the problem with the question, it's that [the asker has just dumped all the pieces on the table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220), requiring any answerer to [start from square one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: While the answer is surely not perfect, it seems to me it answers the OP's basic question -- "what are all these things, and which of them do I need for a reasonable python development setup?" -- pretty well. And I say this as a relative newcomer to python myself, as someone who knows the language itself relatively well but had never even heard of (ana)conda, jupyter or pycharm before this question. Perhaps *you* would prefer a much more in-depth explanation, but I suspect that for the OP, and others like them, the current answer is quite sufficient.

Comment: This might be a bit vague formulation of my opinion, but I believe Stack Overflow should be a knowledge base, so we should _know_ instead of the asker rather than _think_ instead of the asker. The largest problem with the post in question is that the asker handed us 7 words related to python and left us to tell them what they mean (i.e. basically what @Josh already said). It would've taken 7 google searches to figure out what those 7 things are. I know RTFM answers get the most upvotes, but we really shouldn't strive to become a search engine replacement. Every question should follow research!