# Why is my chatroom access still not available although I have the rep?

Tags: support, bug, chat

I wanted to go to the Python chatroom but the site told me this:

[image: Not enough reputation error message]

I was a bit confused, because I have more than 20 rep...

[image: I have 29 reputation]

I have waited some time and reloaded all pages various times... Is it normal that the site does not recognize my reputation? How can I get access?

Comment: you have 29, but need 20. I can give you a few downvotes, if you want :) but really, i think it takes time for reputation to "adjust in all places". but I can be complete wrong. I am sure more experienced stackoverflowers will have an answer.

Comment: With chat, you'll have a separate chat user that is linked to your parent account. It likely just wasn't synced yet, but appears to be fixed now. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/8908318/monamona

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ has the answer

Comment: We look forward to seeing you in the Python room. Don't forget to read our [room rules](https://sopython.com/chatroom) ;)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is a slight lag in the refresh of chat accounts from main accounts. I manually refreshed your chat account from the main site, so you now should have the capabilities required to chat.

Use them wisely.

Comment: Great power comes with great responsibility.

Comment: Only a King knows the true weight of a Crown.

Comment: “Nearly all men can stand adversity, but if you want to test a man's character, give him power.” -- Abraham Lincoln

Comment: Rank does not confer privilege or give power. It imposes responsibility.

Comment: "The greatest gifts you can give your children are the roots of responsibility and the wings of independence."

Comment: "Something in quotes in a list of quotations can be equivalent to another famous quote"

Comment: Well done. This is not a quote.

Comment: "Freedom is the right of all sentient beings". There, this desperately needed a nerd-quote.

Comment: "Now witness the firepower of these armed and fully operational... Python chat previligies"

Comment: "monamona, we are your fathers" -Lord Overflow

Comment: "Power tends to corrupt and absolute power corrupts absolutely" - Lord Acton

Comment: "Build a man a fire, and he'll be warm for a day. Set a man on fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of his life."

Comment: "Luke, I am your father!"

Comment: Am I the only person who doesn't understand why this answer's comments filled with quotes (looks like)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dJolYw8tnk

Comment: “Power is power.” - cersei lannister

Comment: @SankarRaj "Use them wisely" was a dramatic/poetic way of wrapping up that answer. Quotes are meant to continue that dramatization. Now, obligatory quote: "The measure of a man is what he does with power" - Plato.

Comment: "Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat." – [Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359531/if-a-1k-rep-user-told-a-6k-rep-user-that-answering-no-research-effort-question/359534#comment534001_359534)

Comment: @SankarRaj Yes. "This knowledge is the king of education, the most secret of all secrets. It is the purest knowledge, and because it gives direct perception of the self by realization, it is the perfection of dharma. It is everlasting, and it is joyfully performed."

Comment: "Power resides only where men believe it resides. [...] A shadow on the wall, yet shadows can kill. And ofttimes a very small man can cast a very large shadow." ― George R.R. Martin, A Clash of Kings