# Should I avoid making suggestions/recommendations to someone who has a higher reputation than I do?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, writing-style

Long time ago, when I first joined Stack Overflow, while trying to help someone (who had >10k rep), I said something among the following lines: *"Do this, don't do that"*.

I admit that I'm not good at English, so someone may get me wrong. But I just wanted to help! They replied:

*"I've been here around years and I know what I could do. Don't tell me what to do, what not to do..."*

Today I saw the following answer:

[image: 2]

My question is: Although they have much more rep than me, could I comment to suggest them that they shouldn't just write a code-only answer?

Comment: Highly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359531/if-a-1k-rep-user-told-a-6k-rep-user-that-answering-no-research-effort-question/359532#359532

Comment: Why can't it be a good answer? You haven't told us the question. Does it work...if not, why not. Its nothing more than a suggestion.

Comment: And you don't **tell** other users what or what not to do...you guide them.

Comment: Yes that's arguably a bad answer, and a poor way to respond to criticism. What was your comment though that lead to that response?

Comment: @Paulie_D I've learned that: all of the answers which contains code block should have explanation about the changes and how it works (at least 1 thing related).

Comment: @Paulie_D If I ask the question, I copy the code in that answer and I try to run. It works fine. I still need to know how it work. I think many other *askers* have same idea.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the link. I will notice.

Comment: A fresh example of a high-rep user who should know better than to [not inline images of code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53251693/revisions). If only as it appears to suggest that that is okay and actually *expected*.

Comment: @usr2564301 I don't think that was a bad thing to do necessarily, after all it may encourage others to downvote when they see that image.

Comment: @DavidG: such a question *without* the image inlined should already be downvoted. (I cannot but despair seeing that question has a +1.)

Comment: @usr2564301 What makes you think the user that made the edit didn't also downvote? The upvote on it is another problem completely.

Comment: *it may encourage others to downvote when they see that image.* @DavidG In my experience it encourages people to answer the question as is, which means the OP never fixes the question because they already got a solution. Images of text should not be edited into posts at all.

Comment: @BSMP Those people are almost certainly going to answer the question anyway. Posts with embedded images of code are objectively better than links to images of code.

Comment: @DavidG There's no difference between a link to an image and an inline image if you can't actually see it. Images of code are particularly bad because you can't even write useful alt text for them.

Comment: @BSMP That's a pretty small number of users though.

Comment: In response to your statement "I'm scared", what of? What do you think they're going to do in retaliation? Most of the time a bad reaction is just going to result in an angry comment. And if that's the worst they do, then you're probably scared for no reason.

Comment: Just FWIW, I have a gold badge in a tag, but I know several users with less reputation in that tag who know more than me regarding that tag language. In other words, reputation means a lot of people have upvoted your stuff as helpful/useful. It doesn't mean you're an expert or that you're infallible.

Comment: I periodically get asked whether what I've said is right, in some shape or form. Usually, it means I've screwed up and I'm grateful to whoever had the guts to let me know. Occasionally, I disagree with the suggestion — I will either give a cogent explanation of why I disagree, or will ignore it altogether (or will seek clarification of what is being suggested and why if I'm not sure I've understood). Appealing to 'reputation' isn't worth it. The person could be new to SO but still have vastly more real-world experience than me, so their reputation doesn't reflect the value of their opinion.

Comment: programming is about learning.  Someone who tells you they know it all because they have been around for years most likely knows a lot less than they think (regardless of what they think the numbers next to their icon means.).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, it's better not to say "Do this, don't do that" to anyone even if they have lower reputation than you.

If you see an answer like that you can just say:

"Can you please explain the answer further so me and other people checking this question can understand why this works?"

Or if you know why it works, and you want to add explanation to the answer then just edit the answer with your explanation or ask the user in the comments if you (OP of this question) can edit it and write some explanation.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you mean _lower reputation_ or _higher reputation_ in your first sentence,  so me and other people checking this answer can understand it better?

Comment: I meant lower reputation because OP thought he should only talk in a good way to someone who has a higher reputation that him, but really should just be polite to anyone regardless of the reputation.

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 31):

I agree this is in part a matter of language. "Do this, don't do that" is rather abrupt and, under the wrong circumstances, could be taken as an order, or as condescension (see also [Paulie_D's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376511/should-i-avoid-to-suggest-recommend-someone-who-has-reputation-higher-than-me-to#comment645924_376511): "you don't **tell** other users what or what not to do...you guide them."). It is generally better to phrase such things as "I suggest you do X instead of Y", or "Wouldn't doing X instead of Y be better?".

That doesn't mean that >10k user was in the right, either. Not only have they, to my eyes, overreacted to what was, at worst, a minor language slip-up, but they are also wrong about it being a matter of reputation or seniority. The suggestion about language applies to dealing with anyone here. The flip side of the coin is that you should not be scared to suggest things to users with more reputation than you -- if an honest on-topic suggestion offends them, that is on them.

As for the answer you posted a screenshot of, it can indeed be improved by adding a written explanation to accompany the code. You can address that by suggesting its author add such an explanation, or doing it yourself (if you choose the latter option, it is courteous to leave a comment explaining to the author what you have attempted to do). See also [Peter Haddad's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376512/2751851).

Comment: And what does the `cf.` stand for? I saw you wrote that: `cf. Paulie_D's comment`

Comment: @TânNguyễn I used it to mean "see also". However, according to the [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.), my usage of it wasn't entirely correct :)

Comment: There's always qv.

Answer (score 14):

Think carefully before doing it, but if you're confident that you're right, then do it.

You run the risk of making a fool of yourself and you have to consider whether you're prepared to take that risk. You can protect yourself against that risk by using language that is tentative rather than assertive: "I may be wrong, but I would have thought...".

Remember though that however experienced and knowledgeable someone is, (a) there are things they don't know, and (b) they are capable of making mistakes. Also, in my experience, people who are highly competent are also open to criticism and correction, provided it is well founded. However, they are likely to have little patience with someone whose criticisms are ill-informed.

There's a difference between criticising a post in terms of its technical content, and criticising it because it doesn't follow SO guidelines. In the same way that the best composers break all the rules taught to novices at music college, the best engineers probably have little respect for rules and are unlikely to take kindly to attempts to pull them into line.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, in my opinion, reputation points are not directly proportional to your expertise in specific subject or topic. Because there are a hell of a lot number of tags out there and may be more than *80%* of the tags are not known to you. May be a user has huge reputation, but just started learning the technology and answering as per his/her knowledge. So, even if I have 30k reputation I don't know what [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf), [xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin), etc. is.

Secondly, we're not here to teach. We are here to collaborate to make this site a platform where you can get answers of questions you're looking for and answer those questions for which you think you know the answer.

Even if you said, and I quote, "Do this, don't do that", I don't find it abrupt or rude, but some people may, so even if you think the answer is not as per the expectation, you can write the reason why you think anyone *should not do that and should do that*.

Code-only answers are not really good answers, but those do or may answer the question. Always ask to explain about the code in a comment, and downvote if it doesn't add any value.

Comment: Thank you! I will provide an example which relates to this post: If someone just posts *code-only* as answer, but he/she explains how to use it inside the code as comment(s). Can it be a good answer? Same to that *answer*, if someone appends *Try this* or *You can try this* (but they have a comment inside code block), can I ignore it? I saw many posts like that in the queue `Low Quality Posts`

Comment: It's very easy to check user profile and evaluate from where high reputation comes as well as user experience with current topic.

Comment: @Sinatr So, I think you disagree with [TylerH's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376511/should-i-avoid-making-suggestions-recommendations-to-someone-who-has-a-higher-re#comment646390_376511)

Comment: @TânNguyễn, yes sort of. Even if gold badger don't think he is good, he **is** good enough to be called an expert. Simply because he has answered so many questions already that he become an expert in problem-solving. You unlikely to ask a question which can only be answered by the best expert.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Explanation in comments are not acceptable because that explanation should ultimately be a part of that code only answer, I would better suggest him to update his/her answer with that explanation. Also, comments inside code are fine but I find it less readable compared to text written outside code block. Just read the input text of comment section of SO, _Avoid answering questions in comments_.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Stack Overflow was meant as a technical resource, not a social network. But some people use it as a social network, not as a source of information.

The high reputation points mean they are constantly on this site, and working to have a higher reputation.

I think Bill Gates has zero reputation here, but it does not mean he is less trustworthy than somebody with a very high reputation here.

So it is perfectly fine to make suggestions here if you feel that you know better. For another person it would be good to make a comment on your advice than to downvote your answer without reason.

And look after posting this question you have a higher reputation now. Does it mean you are more trustworthy now, than 2 days ago? Nope.

So the reputation is more like a social status here. It gives you more privileges - for example to downvote your answer. But if you use the site as a value resource it should not worry you.

Comment: `And look after posting this question you have a higher reputation now`. Sorry,  but all of the upvotes and downvotes in this post don't make changes to my reputation (same to you). *Off topic*: If Bill Gates is here, it should be a difference story. Because the way to say to an expert is *absolutely* different from the way to say to a billionaire (*in the world*).

Comment: @TânNguyễn But in any way in the technical resource correctness must be first and then politeness, and reputation. In the social network this works in the other way.  P.S. this is  my first answer in this section, so i did not know about how these votes influence the reputation. But all the other things are correct.

Comment: I got it. You have same idea with [@Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376511/should-i-avoid-making-suggestions-recommendations-to-someone-who-has-a-higher-re/376629?noredirect=1#comment645932_376511). An answer which *Looks OK* may not solve the problem, and otherwise. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Once I received an answer like this, "**I did just suggest something, did I not? Have you tried that yet? Here’s a similar question with some more suggestions in the answer, stackoverflow.com/q/4313494/10283047**". I got this because I was a little straightforward. It happens, Then I turned the table around and appreciated his efforts and requested more suggestions. I got more than expected. it's all about humbleness, try to fit in "*I request*", "*please can you*", etc. It works like *a miracle*.

Answer (score -1):

I think reputation points doesn't mean that one knows everything. It may be a coincidence that the way they perceive the issue is too complicated yet a simple script could have sorted it.

What I'd say is give the advice, and try to be as detailed and brief as possible explaining why you are seeing that the suggestion you are making is correct if it's accepted fine if not... you made the effort.

PS: One thing I have learned is we learn best from noobs rather than nerds. :D

Comment: Yes, we're all human (I think), and tone does matter even if we like to pretend it doesn't. I'm not saying we don't need technical accuracy, of course.