# Are adding image for new users edits allowed?

Tags: support, editing-help

So new users can only post links to images. But if you make an edit and you fix some grammar or spelling or add a tag, would it be allowed to save the image, re-upload it and paste a new link.

An example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21508165

Comment: Note that you don’t need to upload a new image! Just add the missing `![](...)` syntax.

Comment: Related: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) and [Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is allowed. And many times a good thing.

But the suggested edit [you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21508165) is **not a good example** of how to go around suggesting edits.

Your suggested edit should attempt to fix all the problems that you can find in a post (remember that you [should be removing salutations and greetings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)).

And it is best if you do not suggest edits for posts that are otherwise closable, unless your edits bring them past that threshold. Which in this case you are failing to accomplish.

Comment: Where were the salutations and greetings?

Comment: In this case, I'm referring to the _"please blah, blah, blah"_ phrase. Not exactly a salutation, but still noise. But even if you edited that part out, this post would still be closable. Save your suggested edits for **better** posts.

Answer (score 5):

The other problem with your edit is that [the question should be clear even if the image isn't visible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376751/raise-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-stop-seeing-the-warning-on-the-image-up). There's no way for a user that can't view the image to know that the OP was getting "Permission denied" in the terminal and even if you can see the image you have to click on it to make it bigger before it's readable.

If the image is just a screenshot of text it's better to just ask the OP to provide the actual text.