# What's with downvoting perfectly understandable questions and viable answers?

Tags: discussion

I posted two answers today (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043111/65863 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043058/65863) within minutes of each other and they were both downvoted very quickly.  I'm not known for posting bad answers.  The questions themselves were also downvoted quite severely, which I think was overkill as they were maybe not the highest quality but still quite understandable and answerable.

A user commented on one of my answers:

> I've noticed a phenomena lately when answers to what are perceived as bad questions get downvoted. I guess someone has taken it upon themselves to police this site in that way.

I hope that is not the case.

I really wish there was a report, maybe behind a high privilege level, to see exactly who is issuing downvotes on questions and answers, to see if there is a pattern to it, perhaps an overzealous user who needs a slap on the wrist or a ban?  Can moderators see this info?

Comment: I mean... because it was an image of code for one of them... that you were willing to transpose it isn't an excuse

Comment: *"which I think was overkill as they were maybe not the highest quality but still quite understandable and answerable."* quality is literally one of the key reasons voting exists. simply being answerable isn't enough.

Comment: As for the image, not every new user is aware of the policy of not posting images of code. So yes, I sometimes translate them into text when feasible, and sometimes I point out the policy if I don't want to take the time to translate. That's not the issue here.

Comment: Regarding why this question was downvoted: I didn't downvote this question or your answers, but perhaps the voters don't think a meta question about two answers with one downvote each is especially useful (especially given that you have over 17k answers; inevitably, someone won't like something about some of them).

Comment: As for your feature request in the last paragraph, it already exists: mods can see voting patterns (we don't discuss the exact details of what we can see in order to help prevent people from evading detection).  I took a look at the voting toward your posts and I see no evidence that any person is targeting you with downvotes.

Comment: FWIW, I don’t get how answering "how about [using] the size function" with three variations of "use the size function/method" is *useful*. This does not need some nefarious explanation for attracting one measly downvote.

Comment: Relevant reading: [Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415040/2029983) TL;DR: No.

Comment: @ThomA That's about whether to do it in the first place. It's also advice, not a rule. And furthermore, to _undo_ such an edit when it's already been done is harmful, because it's removing text and replacing it with an image, and spiteful, because it's intentionally attempting to waste an editor's time and effort. It should be discouraged, but _undoing_ it when someone has already done it should _also_ be discouraged.

Comment: It's reverted a *bad* change, @TylerH . Undoing bad changes is encouraged. There is no way to know that a transcribed image is accurate; the OP needs to copy and paste that text, not have someone make a best attempt that could easily be wrong.

Comment: @ThomA That's incorrect, it was not a bad change, it was a good one; it improved the post. That's objective. That you don't _like_ that Remy did it instead of OP is a you problem, not an edit problem. And of course there is a way to know if a transcribed image is accurate. Have you never heard of diffs or comparing two things side by side?

Comment: It's incorrect to undo bad edits, @TylerH . I can only disagree.

Comment: We don't disagree on "undoing bad edits", please don't try and use a strawman argument. What we disagree on is "replacing code with text" being a bad edit. You seem to think it's a bad edit if anyone other than OP does it. I think it's less than ideal, but still overall a good edit. The important lesson here is, **once the edit has already been made, reverting it is *objectively* reducing the quality of the post**. Please, don't reduce the quality of the site out of spite or let the perfect be the enemy of the good.

Comment: "Wow, even THIS QUESTION gets downvoted? Why?" Because a) you propose punishing people who according to well established consensus **did nothing wrong**; b) the question demonstrates a lack of awareness of said consensus, implying a lack of research; c) your interactions here suggest a lack of awareness that [voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), further confirming a lack of research; d) your question is predicated on the idea that "perfectly understandable" is all that's required of a question, implying a general misunderstanding of the entire site.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - “Wow, even THIS QUESTION gets downvoted? Why?” - Because you’re asking the reason an answer to a question, that was deliberately deleted by the author of the question (because it was downvoted), was downvoted. Don’t answer questions that should not be answered. At 567K reputation, don’t expect an explanation, for every downvote. You answered low quality questions. Answers to low quality questions are rarely helpful in my experience. Low quality contributions to low quality question are not helpful. Yes; Your answers are low quality

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The primary reason for casting a downvote on SO is quality. If the question isn't well written, asks for something unreasonable, lacks information, contains images of code, or links elsewhere for code, it will attract downvotes.

Your first example which is now deleted is somewhat unclear. They did provide code, but they also in passing mentioned ChatGPT and didn't indicate whether any of what they are providing is ChatGPT generated code or code they've written themselves. It can be perceived as being code ChatGPT wrote, and as such it'd be quite rude to come to SO and ask us to debug ChatGPT output for them.

[image]

[For the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043058/65863), The original version of the question included an image of code, which is guaranteed to be downvoted and is often quickly closed. Editors shouldn't be expected to transpose that into text.

> I've noticed a phenomena lately when answers to what are perceived as bad questions get downvoted. I guess someone has taken it upon themselves to police this site in that way.

This does occur, I think it is wrong, but there's certainly an argument to be made for downvoting answers to not useful questions for the purpose of the roomba being able to clean up later. I'd prefer the roomba be altered to not require this practice myself.

Comment: " I think it is wrong" - why? Answers to bad questions lower the overall quality of the site, by acting counter to the stated goal of building a library, and by impeding cleanup efforts.

Comment: But we don't vote on the quality of the site, we vote on the quality of the content itself. Voting down perfectly fine answers just because the question shouldn't have been answered to begin with remains voting abuse.

Comment: @Gimby Your opinion on whether that kind of voting constitutes abuse is an opinion. Please let's not pose it as if it were a fact. For that matter, it makes no sense to evaluate an answer as if it existed in a vacuum, because external circumstances do influence its overall usefulness.

Answer (score 6):

At the risk of repeating several points I've previously made on Meta yet again:

> which I think was overkill as they were maybe not the highest quality but still quite understandable and answerable.

This is **not even close** to sufficient.

**The purpose of the site**, as described in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), is to **build a library** of high-quality answers. This requires high quality questions that prompt answers that belong in a library. To be useful as part of a library, these questions need to:

- Not be closable, as described in [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/). **Every question that should be closed also merits downvoting.** If it's being closed as "needs details or clarity" then it's also almost certainly "unclear"; if it "needs more focus" or "needs more debugging details" then it very likely also "does not show research effort"; and in any event it is certainly "not useful" - since voting to close means signalling that the question should not be answered, and a question can only contribute to a Q&A library insofar as it prompts answers.
- describe problems **that other people can have** - not just serve as requests or support tickets to fix a problem the OP is experiencing. What good is a library that is full of books that are only of interest to their authors? In particular, "questions" that boil down to expecting someone else to find the bug in some code sample are not suitable for Stack Overflow - and they will normally be closable as either "needs more focus" or "needs debugging details". It [is the OP's responsibility before posting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [isolate](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the bug first and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and I have a copy-paste feedback comment template in my profile for this case (because it is so common).

**The fact that such a large fraction of Stack Overflow users want to use the site software a certain way, does not justify them in doing so.** The site is designed with a specific purpose in mind; that purpose potentially allows for the creation of something truly valuable; the actions of such users directly go against that purpose and diminish the value of the site; and there are *countless existing other places* where people who want to "help" each other in that way may do so. (For example, Python users can try https://reddit.com/r/learnpython, https://reddit.com/r/python or https://discuss.python.org/.)

In the specific cases you describe:

For the first question, even after editing to include properly formatted code, it is not a MRE. Most of the error message is in a foreign language, which is unhelpful; there are dozens of lines of code for a common sort of error; there are multiple lines of [noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/) in a question that seems to boil down to just "what is wrong here?" but without a clearly identified "here".

While most of this could be fixed by other editors, even given a MRE, the underlying Q&A ("Q. Why can't I use `std::exception`? A. You need to `#include <exception>` first") is a common problem that demands a [proper beginner-oriented canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426205/) - assuming that the [existing general one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030) is considered insufficient.

Aside from all of that, your answer demonstrates that there are many other things wrong with the code besides the issue that actually prompted the question. The purpose of Stack Overflow **is not** to fix code posted by the OP and solve the problem for one user. The purpose is to build the searchable library so that **everyone** can get answers. Pointing out other problems in the code is not answering the question. The existence of those problems in the code in the question is distracting from the actual question. **The question needs to be about one thing**.

The second [tried to use an image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551); other users [should not attempt to transcribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) these (although once you've put in the effort, it's better off left that way; the rollback war there was silly IMO). But the image wasn't even inlined (as this is [blocked for new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377038)), and the question text blatantly misused formatting (initially setting most of the question text in `<h1>` header text; the edit to include an image only *accidentally* avoided this).

Aside from that, the question is not clear. Does OP has a specific function in mind? Which one? Or is the question instead asking whether there is, indeed, such a function built in? Or is it asking about how to implement one? It also isn't clear *why* using `sizeof` in the normal way doesn't meet OP's needs. The grammar used in the question is a complete mess, and your edit doesn't attempt to fix this - so, quite frankly, I don't even agree with you assessment of the question as "quite understandable".

---

> I hope that is not the case.

I hope it is.

Answering bad questions makes it harder to keep the site clean. Even when there is a potentially good "underlying" question and someone properly answers it (and nothing else), that question **is usually a duplicate** of something somewhere else. Standard debugging techniques normally lead to isolating a commonly-encountered issue with a standard explanation. Writing an answer in these cases is *at best* putting the answer in the wrong place; most commonly it is duplicating effort (and many of the most popular dupe targets already have *way too many* answers).

A lot of this answering is done by people who write tons of answers, almost all of them to bad questions, apparently in search of a quick upvote and/or accept vote from the OP for up to 25 reputation at a time. (What a shame that I can only offset 2 of that when I see a familiar username attached to yet another such answer.)

I have certain old answers from 2010 or so with hundreds of upvotes that I would gladly delete if I didn't fear further repercussions for deleting such supposedly "valuable" content. The last [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) is awarded at a mere 25k reputation and I have more than double that. But some users seem to value these points in and of themselves, and have an insatiable appetite for them. (Or perhaps they take the "leaderboard" seriously.) That [is not a recipe for quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not/387550#387550).

Comment: *"Every question that should be closed also merits downvoting"* is a _bit_ of a stretch IMO (although is very nearly the case). Duplicates, in particular those that are legitimately hard to identify when searching unless you know the exact right terms, can very much be useful to serve as sign posts, allowing more users to find an answer from a broader search space. I don't believe those kinds of posts necessarily deserve a downvote. That said, blatant duplicates with clearly no attempt to find the dozens of identical posts out there? Downvote away, the answers too, they're totally unhelpful.

Comment: I don't know about downvoting answers to bad questions. The point of voting on questions and answers are slightly different. We upvote a question that has *potential* to attract good answers. We upvote an answer by its face value. You're suggesting we consider second order effects to all our voting, and in particular, consider the user behind the post. That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @PasserBy Considering the user behind the post is definitely not right. But there is evidently the case for the platform favoring the bad practice of answering questions with a weak threshold, which _"makes it harder to keep the site clean"_. To add some insult to injury, any attempts from curators at reverting these cases by deleting the duplicate questions are perceived as downright malicious. Looks like we can't have nice things either way.