# The "How to Answer" section should include a "DO NOT post images of code" warning just like the "How to Ask" section does

Tags: discussion, answers, help-center

In the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), there is the warning "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.". Shouldn't this warning also be included in the [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section?

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't post images *of code*. Data and error messages should (ideally) not be needed in an answer but will be in a question. However, there are a couple of aspects here: 1. Do *that* many people really post images of code in their answers? Or data/error messages. It seems like something that doesn't really happen as often as with questions. 2. Even if it happens with enough regularity, I don't think changing the How to Answer page will make posters *stop* doing that. Ultimately, they'd be providing making bad posts and more text in the help articles hardly helps with that.

Comment: @VLAZ Frequency should not be a reason to not make a rule.

Comment: I think that page should remain as concise as possible, and that images in answers are too rare to be worth a sentence there. Personally, I've *never* seen an image of code in an answer. If the guide can be lengthened, there are probably more actionable tips that should be added first.

Comment: @Rob if something happens only once *ever* does it need to have a rule? If so, we'd need a VERY long list of rules, most of which are not applicable. So, it's going to be daunting to read, understand and apply them.

Comment: Also, on a slightly separate note I don't think the "How to Answer" page is for *rules*. It's a help text with *guidance*.

Comment: Relatively few people rob banks, too.

Comment: @Rob strawman argument.

Comment: I don't think there's any *harm* in putting this in [answer]... we could also add a bullet under "Answer well-asked questions" that includes "...include code only as images or links to external sites" (the ellipsis picking up on the ending of "avoid trying to answer questions which...")

Comment: I still think [making the existing warning on the upload dialog visible longer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376751/raise-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-stop-seeing-the-warning-on-the-image-up) is a good idea, though I agree there’s no harm in adding something to the Help Center.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that pictures aren't bad in themselves. It's when they are used incorrectly that they are a problem.

That said, I agree with the idea with adding this. Although, I think it might be better if we try, "[something a little more nuanced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334713/10957435)."  I think that type of warning might be more effective.

Comment: Agreed with the "nuanced" bit. The help centre is all nice and proper to have, but not many people will go read through the thing and conform to all rules. An on-your-face pop-up might be more effective. I'd let it appear only when there's no code though, otherwise it becomes annoying fast when you answer lots of [tag:image] or [tag:image-processing] questions.

Comment: *If* they are used, they are usually used incorrectly (more than 90% of the time in questions and more than 70% of the time in answers (estimated)).