# Why was posting the question with basically no content possible?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, specific-question, low-quality-posts, question-quality

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382727/illegal-start-of-expression-with-combo-box) is a mess of ill-formated image and ... basically nothing else.

Wasn't there some kind of "quality filter" and/or guideline that stopped users from posting it like this?

This is both an incredibly bad experience for the new user (as they will almost certainly collect many down votes and some mean comments) and pointless for others to answer. I for one have grown unwilling to spend several back-and-forth interactions just to get the question to a state where we can start guessing at the problem.

Comment: The "quality filter" was never a good one. IIRC, it prevents new users from embedding images into the post but they can include links to images. I think it also prevents posting code-only or links-only posts. My guess is that the user tried to just post the image/link, it didn't work so they did some random trial and error until it was accepted. The post contains some "text" along with the image link and the filter probably isn't smart enough to see that something is wrong.

Comment: If the "quality filter" lacks quality itself, then it should probably just be called "filter".

Comment: @VLAZ: but since it does not *filter* either, it does nothing (useful) at all. It's probably implemented as `def quality_filter(text): return True`

Comment: The filter ought to reject posts containing "enter image description here".

Comment: @JohnKugelman *Inlined* images which have that description are fine (the description appears automatically when embedding an image, but it's only seen if one looks at the alt text). Eg `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/913e6362-6c70-44c8-90c6-b94f4e26e161/view-source https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61179831/revisions But when someone without the rep to inline images doesn't even bother to edit the placeholder text, that's often an indication of a poor question

Comment: @JohnKugelman Too many users never see a warning message about filling in the image description because [the warning goes away after 20 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376751/raise-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-stop-seeing-the-warning-on-the-image-up).

Comment: These examples just keep coming. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482782/i-have-3-errors-and-1-warning-need-help-to-fix-them The site could definitely do better at stopping users from asking this.

Comment: Heads up this is on our list to revisit. We'll want to do some additional research as to why similar posts like this keep coming up before we decide on a solution.