# When the "Best Answer" is not always the "Right Answer"

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I have recently joined SO, interested in Python, pandas, and NumPy, and have noticed a tendency for questioners to favour, and often explicitly request the following:

1. "One-line" answer
2. "Most efficent" answer, when the piece of code is not a bottleneck
3. Get from A [input] to B [output], when no existing code shared

With particular reference to questions tagged [python], where a *good* solution is a *readable* solution, this is problematic.

**Exhibit 1**: [python: write column backwards with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731502/python-write-column-backwards-with-condition)

This is an example of issues 1 & 3. Possibly the most efficient, shortest and smartest answer is given as:

```
df['x'] = df.groupby((df['number'].bfill()[::-1]//10).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['number'].transform(min)
```

There are at least 6 functions involved here. But it works, and I envy the poster for being able to come up with this. In this case, it wasn't the accepted answer, but in many cases it will be. The answer is accepted because it solves the problem tersely and efficiently.

Let's say tomorrow the question changes to "10% change condition *but only if  number is increasing*, otherwise 5%". In my mediocrity, I will be clueless to adapt the above answer. Most people wanting to adapt it will need specialist knowledge, but this is available, because there are dozens of pandas-specialists on call at SO.

**Exhibit 2**: [Expand pandas DataFrame column into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203352/expand-pandas-dataframe-column-into-multiple-rows/38203702#38203702)

These are 2 valid solutions to the stated problem:

```
def using_repeat(df):
    lens = [len(item) for item in df['days']]
    return pd.DataFrame( {"name" : np.repeat(df['name'].values,lens), 
                          "days" : np.concatenate(df['days'].values)})

def using_apply(df):
    return (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.days), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=1).to_frame('day').join(df['name']))
```

The second answer requires a good understanding of pandas, using at least 6 functions. Such a response is usually "first to market" and often the one that is accepted. But the chances are if this is the one the user accepts, as soon as some minor change is required, they will return with another question / answer. Which suits both questioners and responders well if the respective goals are to fix something quickly and maximise reputation.

A case in point is that I see these questions which ask to split pandas columns of lists on a very regular basis: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203352/expand-pandas-dataframe-column-into-multiple-rows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows/17116976#17116976), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651008/splitting-multiple-columns-into-rows-in-pandas-dataframe), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022899/converting-tuples-into-rows-from-numerous-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe/46023057), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255181/questions-about-pandas-expanding-multivalued-column-inverting-and-grouping). Given a few more minutes, I could find dozens of these.

**My Question**

What is the point of SO? Is it to provide smart, optimal one-line solutions to problems that need to be maintained by SO responders should requirements change? Or should it be to provide the tools and knowledge so that questioners can incorporate, understand and easily adapt solutions? If the latter, how can we encourage this behaviour, when incentives appear to be aligned towards quick-solutions/max-rep?

Comment: Related:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354

Comment: A few fundamental points otherwise:  1)  Questions should *never* suddenly change from one requirement to another.  If you find any that do, roll those questions back.  2) Python has had a tendency to produce small, Pythonic solutions with code instead of explanation more than most languages.  That seems to be the nature of the beast, but it's not entirely for the best.  3) Answerers are not obligated to water down their approach.  They have a right to assume that the asker is fairly knowledgeable about the domain they're asking about.

Comment: @Makoto, (1) Agreed, though I have often seen this violated in practice, even within the question. We answer a question "smartly", then the requirement changes subtly requiring a whole new approach. (2) Agreed. (3) Excellent point. I don't want to restrict answers, but when no code is given it is usually a good sign the questioner has limited knowledge - and if often shows with follow-up questions.

Comment: Isn't this just a case of where we rather (spoon)feed the fish instead of teaching how to operate a fish rod, line, hooks and bait?

Comment: @rene. Yes, indeed. But is this not a joint responsibility for questioners and responders? If we choose to give the esoteric, convoluted, library-specific answer, are we are not propagating  spoon-feeding? I gave a couple of examples, but see them all the time.

Comment: The boring truth is *it depends*. If googling the functions is enough to figure out what they are doing I can see a responder to take the easy route. If the answer tries to out-smart everyone then extra context is welcome. The former answer could be much easier subject to upvotes than the latter.

Comment: Another solid indicator, in my opinion, is the number of duplicate questions. Many duplicate  questions (many not marked as such) are asked because the user was not able to adapt esoteric answers to similar other questions, cf. the 5 questions I found for splitting columns.

Comment: @rene's comment also touches upon a very common problem: some posters don't come here to *learn*, they come here for an *answer*. So they will prefer a code-only answer over a lengthy explanation. And indeed, as soon as they need a variation of such code, they will HAVE to ask again.

Comment: I'm tempted to post "You're right." as an answer. You have astutely identified some problems with this site which are very hard to correct, technically or socially. On the one hand, we have ethics, principles, and rules; on the other, we have users who are unaware, or have their own agenda.

Comment: As an aside, editing your post just to bump it is **precisely** an example of the latter.

Comment: @tripleee, SO is, by nature, a democracy. If you have a problem with my "agenda", or the fact I have one, downvote!

Comment: I was hoping you were merely unaware that bumping posts is not kosher.

Comment: @tripleee, On SO I never bump a post. Ever. Instead I offer a Bounty. Unfortunately, I can't offer a Bounty on SO Meta.

Comment: I'm afraid the only reply you can hope for here is "yeah, we know" and/or the crowd marking yours as one of many possible duplicates for "Fastest Gun in the West" and related general questions on the same topic. You are certainly not the first to notice this problem, though you have articulated it really well.

Comment: @triple, yeh I was hoping so, except several people seem to have downvoted the post, which seems to suggest either they disagree, or it's a point not worth making (or already made?). I'm new to SO (~1month) and couldn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: I'm guessing "up to our eyebrows in point already made".

Comment: Give a man fire, and he will be warm for a day. Set him on fire and he will be warm for the rest of his life.