# Should question with describing a problem but without any effort be flagged as Too broad?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

This question:  [Transform NA values based on first registration and nearest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130682/transform-na-values-based-on-first-registration-and-nearest-values) was in "Review Close Votes" queue.

I selected **Close - Too broad** option, because question has only description of problem to be solved and without any effort, just asking to write a code solution.

But I got "**STOP! Look and Listen.**" message form SO, and now I see that this question has 14 upvotes and seems legit for other SO users.

Am I missing something? Why my close vote is not correct?

Comment: @yivi:  Do you *really* need expertise in a specific domain to see that this question is dumping data in front of us and asking, "How do I make this do the thing I want to?"   Context:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354

Comment: **The audit is _irredeemably_ broken, then.** If the audit slaps us on the hand telling us that this is question is *fine* when it really isn't, then the audit has failed us and is encouraging us to look at otherwise poor questions as somehow good.  You do ***not*** need to be an expert to identify "work dump"-type questions.

Comment: @yivi then I guess I should blame SO for giving me to review "tricky" questions

Comment: @Kos No, you should blame the people indicating that the question is a quality question, if you think it's really not.  The system can only use the information given to it by users to determine what posts are good/bad.

Comment: @yivi:  The angst comes in the fact that **two gold tag holders** and **one silver tag holder** chose to blatantly disregard the policies of the site and answer a question which, had it been painted any *other* color, would be considered "Too Broad".

Comment: I don't disagree there @yivi.  I just believe it's incredibly _myopic_ to suggest that a lack of tag expertise translates to not being able to make a judgment call on the non-technical aspect of the question.

Comment: Okay, I think we've found the problem - there absolutely should not be a difference in culture in how we evaluate questions on the site.  We don't treat PHP questions any differently than Python questions any differently than R questions, and the fact that we are means that reviews will forever be broken because of the inherent lack of tribal knowledge required to navigate those minefields.  That's worth a Meta post in and of itself...

Comment: How-to questions do not require an attempt to solve the problem. That would make it a debugging question. How-to questions must be reasonably scoped (asking how to solve one problem, not four problems in one) and well-defined (not ambiguous or open to interpretation).

Comment: @yivi:  You're right - no prose exists to convey to people how to filter out questions like this.  But that doesn't mean we can't start *somewhere*.  Reviewers are kind of the last line of defense in this context.  Punishing them for doing what should be done is counterproductive.

Answer (score 7):

I'm willing to go out on a limb here and suggest that you did The Right Thing™.  The question has a set of data, and the OP wants it in a different form.

The problem is that the OP hasn't actually done any of the work to establish what it is they're having trouble with - they just want it done.  This - in theory - puts strain on us as we don't really know what effort the OP has done, or if it'll dovetail in with what we answer.  We're just giving them free labor, which makes the scope of the question itself "Too Broad".

If the OP *had* shown what they were working through, we could meet them halfway in a peaceable fashion, and addressed the core issue that they were facing.

However, there are always going to be people which take that low-hanging fruit and just solve someone else's problem in this fashion, which led to it being upvoted and presented as an audit post.

Hopefully a moderator won't let this one count against you.  It *really* shouldn't.

Comment: Seems to be the "too localized" species of "too broad"; agreed.