# Answers with large amounts of code (whole scripts)

Tags: discussion, answers, code

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69846174/17242583) [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69829372/17242583) (since closed: "This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers," and deleted) a little while ago, and it really is a good answer, because it solves the OP's problem, but it has almost 100 lines of code, an entire Python script, and I feel a slight bit silly posting it.

Is it ok to do this? Are there better ways of handling the problem? The thing is, I'm often inclined to write such an answer, but I don't see answers like that very often, if ever.

Comment: eh, it depends on the question. but honestly... if it requires 100 lines of code to answer... is the question too broad? or did you just include more code than you needed to.

Comment: I included the minimum amount of code; and the question doesn't _really_ seem that broad.

Comment: Some very long-winded answers result from questions that don't look too broad. Just about any question about multithreading seems short and simple and ... probably isn't. Broad's not necessarily the problem, note how the wording changed a while back. Needs focus is for questions asking too many things. If the asker's asking one thing but it takes an understanding of many things and a complete program spanning a hundred lines of code... Well then. Probably needs focus. Getting someone through step one of that 100 line program, That should be enough.

Comment: And remember: showing no effort in finding a solution is a valid downvote reason. Vote early and vote often. If an asker learns and improves, remove the downvote. Maybe give an upvote.

Comment: 100 lines of code? Why not, if it solves the problem and teaches people (and in my case, the question is interesting enough). But I may not be the best person to ask, having written an answer that's few characters shy of the post size limit :D | However, in general I try to provide whole scripts as a solution if at all possible, including sample input and outputs.

Comment: ... (Although in your case I would have probably written more of an explanation of what I've done there and why I did it.

Comment: Re *"it really is a good answer"*: But you just dumped an *implementation* (admittedly with a few comments), without any explanation (besides some performance characteristics). What is the gist/idea of the solution? What is the thinking behind it? What makes it fast? - what techniques were used to achieve it? Could it be made even faster with some other technique that wasn't tried (but is more complex)? Why weren't some other technique used (e.g., some technique that may come mind to first). At the very least you could have refactored it into (well named) methods to give a hint.

Comment: 100 lines of code is not that much FWIW. Not everything can be done with one line like in jQuery @KevinB :-)

Comment: Yea, what i was trying to say was what Makoto put into an answer so eloquently, ;) it's not that 100 lines is a lot, it's that if it takes 100 lines from nothing... it's probably a bit more than someone answering a question for free should be expected to do for you.

Comment: Often wondered why stackoverflow even shows the 'reasons' section.  The reasons seem to be selected at random and are often unrelated to the question itself.  Just get rid of the reason part altogether and treat closing the same as downvotes:  I did it because I felt like it.

Comment: May I please ask: why does every time I get an upvote on that answer, I get a downvote? It's currently +6/-6 !?!

Comment: I guess half of the people who voted on it thought it was useful, and the other half throught it wasn't useful. BTW, regarding "it solves the OP's problem", I'm curious how you know. Did OP accept your answer or respond with a comment to this effect?

Comment: I'm guessing it does, because the OP provided a dataframe containing the output they expected. I modeled the script closely after that, and called it done when the df it produced was identical to the model. But no, the OP seems to have dropped from the face of the earth...

Comment: Or in other words, it is essentially [a *"Try this:"* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656677/using-output-of-a-function-that-is-a-command-in-tkinter-button/69656856#comment123123765_69656856). There [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826405/how-to-get-data-from-tkinter-object-entry/69826499#69826499) [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826405/how-to-get-data-from-tkinter-object-entry/69826499#69826499).

Comment: [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) Sometimes folks who see your post here will follow you back to the Q&A and vote. Often the referenced post gets an absolute shellacking, but sometimes the majority figures the post got a raw deal and upvote it. There seems to have been a bit of a disagreement on how to handle your case.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I'mma squint *real hard* and try to see what this question is.

> im trying to get my data from a .txt separated into a dataframe. the text file looks like this
>
> this is a shortend version of what im looking for. i tried to read the txt line by line but the text file is long and it took too long! im stumped!
>
> the job and program number are hidden in the line that contains "Start Job"
>
> thank you

I don't see any code, or any prior attempt at the problem.  There's also no definition of what "too long" is - is it a minute?  An hour?  A day?  A *second*?  This seems emblematic [of the problem I noticed with Python questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354) quite some time ago.

Basically, to put it extremely, you just did this person's job for them.

To put it *less* extreme, this question should've been closed.  Stack Overflow works best as a two-way street; the OP giving you no lines of code and you giving them 100+ seems incredibly unbalanced to me.

Comment: As long as there are free internet points up for grabs, people will grab them.

Comment: @user4581301 you speak the truth. I want the points. To put it more honestly, I _need_ them so that I can do more in terms of _non-diamond moderation_ on the site...

Comment: One thing to remember is real life: If you help a [cargo cultist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) cut-n-paste their way through school, they'll wind up trying to pull the same <expletive deleted> as somebody's co-worker. Trust me you don't want to have to clean up after one of these disasters.

Comment: It's not like I felt like I had to - I enjoy solving CS problems like that with Python.  But you're right, of course.

Comment: "Stack Overflow works best as a two-way street; the OP giving you no lines of code and you giving them 100+ seems incredibly unbalanced to me." Should it generally be balanced though?

Comment: @user17242583 If you need the points, there are plenty of questions out there that show some effort and are on-topic. ...At least I think they're out there. Anyway, I believe you'll find that it's usually a waste of time to answer questions like this because 97% of the time some combination of the following happens: OP disappears from the thread/site forever, the post is closed (and subsequently deleted) while you're writing your high-effort answer, OP responds to say their requirements were something they didn't tell you about in the question, etc.

Comment: @ggorlen i think "plenty" is a bit of an overstatement for the amount of good questions.

Comment: @user17242583 -- "_I enjoy solving CS problems like that_": if you find an off-topic or gimme-teh-codez question that really shouldn't be answered on the site, but that you want to answer for yourself, you can always do the work to write the answer, and _not_ post it. I have folders filled with answers that I wrote in response to bad questions because there was something for me to learn from writing the answer; I did not post those answers because we have enough problems with low-quality questions that I don't want to encourage more of those.

Comment: @adabsurdum Mind sharing those? perhaps for a blog.

Comment: you're _bang on_ @ggorlen after a while I think we will eventually learn not to put what would have been billable hours into something that OP will neither understand or appreciate. Its especially frustrating when they get their answer and delete the post! Sometimes you're giving away your time for free and no one else ever gets to see it.

Comment: Downvoted because the question was about posting long code answers, not about answering a specific bad question.

Comment: @xdhmoore The problem with your position is that while the OP claimed _"I'm **often** inclined to write such an answer"_, they freely chose to provide just a solitary example, where the linked question was poor, deserved to be closed, and should not have been answered. The OP could have provided additional examples of their long code answers to merit a more nuanced response, but they didn't. Perhaps your concern should directed to the quality of the question rather than how it was answered?

Comment: @ggorlen: I have come to find out that the worse the question is worded (or the less effort that was put into it) the more likely you are to get downvoted for trying to answer it, even if your answer is completely fine.  That's in addition to your other points, which are accurate, as the kids say, af.

Comment: @xdhmoore: It's still a red flag to post hundreds of lines of code in response to a simple and well scoped question. Long form answers are the exception, not the rule, so it's easier to deal with questions about it in that way.

Answer (score 18):

Answering a question with 100 lines of code is OK in some cases, but not this one.

From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in SO's help documentation: *"**if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some**"*. That obviously applies in the case of the linked question. The OP made vague claims about their code, and they may or may not have written some, but there is no evidence in the question that it actually exists.

So what you should have done instead of answering is ask the OP to update the question with their code. That is a win-win approach:

- If they don't provide the code then vote to close the question with *"Needs details or clarity"*.
- But if they do provide their code then you can show them where they are going wrong, which is much more helpful than simply throwing working code at them with little explanation.

Don't reward bad behavior, because your answer can only encourage others to post poor questions that ask for working code. More generally, answering a bad/deficient question is probably not a good idea.