# Was my question correctly not reopened after editing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777693/modifying-list-in-determined-indexes-steps) was closed because I needed to provide "details and clarify the problem I was solving". So I edited with more details, addressing some of the comments. I submitted for review, but the system says the "original close reason(s) were not resolved".

I could not understand what is still unclear. How could I further improve my question?

Comment: Some things at a glance: It starts with "replace some of those [repeated] values", which likely should mean *all* of those but it's not really clear. Until close to the end, I was certain the challenge was to identify repeating values; then we learn "It always appears at the same indices" and it looks like all you need is the equivalent of "every 4 and 5 steps". But since "The list repeats itself lots of times" it might actually be enough to do the replacement once manually, then repeat that part as often as the original. Which of these you actually need... is unclear to me.

Comment: I agree with you that it seems pretty clear now; what I glean from your question is that you need to modify each of the "profit" elements in your array. They occur at regular intervals, which means we can travel by index rather than searching, but that still makes for a pretty clear question overall. I'd be really, really surprised if there wasn't a duplicate for looping in Python around somewhere though. That would be a much better closure reason.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the question to reduce some redundancy and get straight to the point. That should remove some unclarity from building up the requirements. I think the example could be further condensed by using numbers instead of strings, but that would be more for making it better suited as a duplicate target.

Answer (score 7):

The question [in its current state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72777693/6) I think is clear enough to reopen (and have voted accordingly).

For me, the primary piece of information that was missing to clarify and define this problem was:

> The word is always the same. I just need to add "3 months" or "12 months" in front of it. And yes, always appear at the same indices. The list repeats itself lots of times.

(Added in [Revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72777693/4) and in response to [this question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/128548645))

This information helps to outline the assumptions the solution is allowed to make. Limiting the problem input space to a small known set of values to concatenate and a set of regular cyclic data makes the solution space much smaller and more clearly defined.

---

My general advice would be to rely a bit less on input and output alone.

Input

```
2 2
```

Output

```
4
```

There are quite a few options for solutions here: 2 + 2,  2 * 2, 2 ^ 2. An *explanation* of the input and output is almost always necessary to fully understand the problem and, in my opinion, that was the core that was missing in [Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72777693/1).

---

- Are there other things that could improve this question? Certainly.
- Are there other threads on Stack Overflow that could answer this question? Maybe.

But these issues are *different* issues than not being a clearly defined problem and can be handled with other mechanisms.

Answer (score -5):

I really don't think any kind of editing was going to "save" your question, and I don't think that it's quite fair to have misled you into believing that.

Let's put it like this.  The ultimate thrust of your question indicates that [you're looking to us to write this code for you](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72777693/7).

> So I want to update my list every 4 and 5 steps to add "12 months" and "3 months". But I don't know how.

The only kind of thing that could *save* that would be for you to show an attempt at solving this *and* what errors you were getting, but if you literally don't know how to do it...then you probably can't meet that standard.

So...all I can really say is that we're sorry.  I wouldn't be moved to reopen this question since [it fits with the pattern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354) of questions that really *shouldn't* be posed on the site.

Comment: I don't see how that is a work request. The gist of the question is "how do I work on evenly spaced indices"; about one to three lines of code are the solution, and it offers ample opportunity for generic explanation. While the question is not particularly generically worded, it's very, very far away from the use-case specific blobs of data that people throw around the tag usually.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi:  [I showed my work on this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354). In spite of the fact that it is *clearer*, this still follows the same pattern, and should be closed.  Maybe you can show a way that it doesn't?

Comment: "*The only kind of thing that could save that would be for you to show an attempt at solving this and what errors you were getting ...*". But that would convert it into a debugging question, with answers focusing solely on fixing the issues in the OP's code, rather than solutions showing how to solve the actual problem. Speaking strictly for myself, I find debugging style questions to be substantially less useful when I'm trying to solve a problem myself. That's because I don't really care what specific bugs the OP has in their code, I just want to solve the problem I'm facing myself.

Comment: The question is not just focused on "input, output, gimme answer". Even the original title "Change element in a list each 5 steps" already extracted the generic component; FWIW, this is almost exactly the wording I was using to search a duplicate for it just now.

Comment: Lack of demonstrated effort is not a close reason... Downvotes are for that. I'm not really sure why OP decided to feature post with zero effort to solve it on meta. On other hand this is Python question - based on answer (which is quite crazy-looking to me without any Python knowledge) Python may not even have basic `for` loop (also I'm sure I've seen some) suitable for the question... maybe indeed it is a good question and can't be easily answered without special knowledge...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  Let me be explicit.  I never stated that would be a reason to close the question.  I'm stating it's a reason for me to not want to reopen the question.  Why would I want to reopen a question that I'm just going to downvote anyway?