# Can I refer "Do my work" questions to my profile, which contains a link to my Careers or rent-a-coder profile

Tags: discussion, answers

I've read various Meta questions about how to handle "Do my work" and "Rent-a-coder" questions, with the general consensus being to not answer them, to (vote to) close them, and/or refer them to the Careers section.

I'm looking at the following question which seems to be specs for a mini-project and I think it deserves all down-voting and flagging that's possible:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215246/copy-data-based-on-multiple-requirements-highlight-changes

My understanding is that I can't provide a link in an answer/comment that would direct someone to anywhere I perform freelance rent-a-coder work, as it would be classified as spam/advertising.

I was wondering if instead I could include such a link in my profile (as I've seen many other do), and then when a question like this comes up, perform the recommended actions for an off-topic question (vote to close, leave a comment about why the question is in appropriate) and also include in the comment that they could consider renting-a-coder and to check my profile.

I expect this to be a gray area, if not entirely disallowed. Of course we don't want this place filled with advertising and the intention is to provide free help that everyone can benefit from. We also want to discourage these types of questions. I think my possible response still adequately discourages these types of questions, follows the recommended actions for handling off-topic questions and doesn't overtly break any rules.

Comment: I mean, good on you for asking, but why would one level of indirection make a difference? "But your honor, I _didn't_ give the mayor any money! I gave it to my brother; _he_ gave it to the mayor."

Comment: Gray area entered! I don't disagree, but I see some distinction because we _are_ allowed to put links in our profile. My counterexample is: I'm not allowed to put a billboard on the sidewalk, but I _am_ allowed to put a billboard on my front lawn, stand on the sidewalk and point towards my billboard. It should also have the effect that I'm not spamming the area that everyone looks at. I expect most people to look at the question and possibly my answer and then move on. They're not exposed to my URL. They're just seeing a comment that refers to my profile rather than to the Careers section.

Comment: Gray area, or slippery slope? In this case, the obvious "do-my-work" Q, it all seems reasonable to allow it. Then, others do the same thing, and more people get the work done that they can't, won't, do themselves. Next we see posters offering there services in comments to random questions that are not "do-my-work" type. (I've seen them a few times already!) Opening a door is easy, closing it again, not so much. @Michael kudos for asking before doing. Still, IMHO, not a good idea. OTOH, these Qs are likely from new/anon posters, so they see ads on site. Maybe purchase your own ads from SE?

Comment: People who want they work done for free not going to pay you... They are the once who get payed minimal amount to write that code already :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### No.

This is not allowed. **If the question is off-topic or out-of-scope for Stack Overflow, then you should not be answering it.** Period. That includes answers that point them to an off-site resource, such as a way to hire a programmer.

I guess you could probably get away with it if you left this as a *comment*, as long as you were also performing the necessary moderation tasks, including downvoting the question and flagging it as needing to be closed. Such questions are not valuable to anyone else, and would quickly be deleted once closed, so your comment probably wouldn't ruffle very many people's feathers. But it may ruffle some, since it is technically a violation of our guidelines—specifically, the ones you mentioned about excessive self-promotion. It isn't really a gray area, but you probably won't run into any serious problems. At worst, your comments will just get flagged and deleted. I've left snarkier comments without getting banned yet.

Please reconsider how much time you waste on these types of questions, though. The time you spend posting comments there is time you *aren't* giving to people who took the time to ask a good, on-topic question. Those people deserve your attention much more. It is very unlikely the people who ask for others to do their work for them are actually going to hire you, and even if they do, you probably don't want to take a chance on working for them.