# Off-topic questions asking for offsite resources and links posted in comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

As we know, many questions get posted asking for various off-site resources and usually these questions slowly get closed as off-topic.

However, in many cases, long before the question is closed and eventually deleted, comments are posted to the question with links to the requested resources.

So the end result is that people happily "answer" these off-topic questions with their helpful comments. The OP gets what they need and there is little incentive to avoid posting such questions due to the helpful comments.

Should these comments be flagged? If so, which flag?

Is there way to discourage people from posting such comments?

Perhaps there should be a check that prevents anyone from posting a comment with a link if the question has one or more votes to be closed due to asking for off-site resources.

Comment: I don't mind posting a comment with a link to an off site resource if I think it can help the OP, even if their terrible question was massively downvoted and closed (But I will never post it as an answer though), what is the real purpose of this suggestion?

Comment: @AlonEitan You are contributing to the problem of bad posts. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions

Comment: @AlonEitan well I would guess that the logic there is "Even if OP gets their question closed, they got their answer, so they don't truly care. Other people seeing this question and the answer in the comments will go "hey, I can ask here too!"". Basically the broken window theory.

Comment: Oh yeah, haven't thought  about that... I'm encouraging mediocrity by doing this. Point taken

Comment: @AlonEitan I feel you though..... it's VERY easy to go "but I know the answer.... here it is". Considering most of us come to SO to help others, we see this as innocent (and the intention definitely is good)... but yeah :/

Answer (score 3):

> Should these comments be flagged? If so, which flag?

The only flag reason I could see possibly working is not constructive, as in the behavior they are promoting is not constructive to the quality of the site but that is a stretch.

> Is there way to discourage people from posting such comments?

Not really.  About the best you can do is try and get it closed and deleted before the comments can be posted.

One thing that could help would be to give gold tag badge holder a resource request hammer.  A resource request is pretty easy to spot and we should be able to close them faster.  Doing that limits the whole mess as the faster it is closed the faster it can be deleted.

Comment: I had the same basic thoughts on the comment flags. I like the "resource request hammer" idea. Goes well with the "dupe hammer" privilege.

Comment: Like it too, has it ever been feature-requested?