# Bounty annulled shortly after answering

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty, closed-questions, moderation

Here's a short description of the events:

1. [Off-topic/TB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47296663/3372061) question is asked.
2. [Question is given a +500 bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47296663/timeline#history_cd4a0af1-4044-4556-a7e2-4a2cf632df68).
3. Several days later I see the question in the bounty list, decide it's an interesting problem although the question is objectively lacking, and since the bounty shouldn't go to waste I post [a CW answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47296663/timeline#answer_47391138).
4. Mod [rolls back bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47296663/timeline#history_e77102cb-e21a-46af-a273-73b24bea9553), closure protection is removed and question is closed.

The result: asker got "free publicity" for his question along with an ok-ish answer that addresses their request, for the discounted price of a few downvotes instead of the -500 he got refunded for the bounty; answerer invested quite some time compiling an answer **mostly due to the possibility of earning a sizable bounty**, only to find the "contract" annulled after the fact.

Clearly, there's no guarantee that I would get the bounty. However, I think this turn of events was unfair to me as an answerer, and the mod shouldn't have intervened.

Is this a new way to discourage answering bad questions?

Comment: You know when the question inevitably gets deleted, all the bounty stuff would get reversed. So it's not really unfair in the sense that even if you received the bounty, you'd just lose it in the future, and they'd still have a refund.

Comment: @animuson Huh, I did not know that awarded bounties could get reversed. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @animuson I always thought bounties were linked to an account, not to a question/answer, just like badges and hence not get removed or refunded when it gets deleted after the bounty has been awarded.

Comment: Bounties are recorded as votes, just as an upvote or downvote, and the usual rules of reputation apply to them when deleting. If the post wasn't 60 days old with 2+ score, the reputation is reversed.

Comment: In that case, do they count towards a tag-badge score? Sounds like an easy way to get 50 votes in one go towards that gold badge @animuson.

Comment: @Adriaan A single bounty is still only *one* vote, but no, only upvotes and downvotes are considered for tag badges. There are many types of votes. Up, down, accept, bounty set, bounty award, suggest edit approved, etc. They are all recorded as "votes" but they don't all count for everything, and all get reversed at deletion.

Comment: @animuson this particular Q already had two close votes and was in the cv queue prior to the bounty being added bumping it out from the queue. Seems odd that's not criteria for the bounty eligibility check... Don't happen to know if this has been discussed before somewhere do you?

Comment: @JonClements this is a good idea! I have seen this so often, a Q with 1-3 CVs, usually as either TB or tool rec, and then snowed under in the queue only to be bountied. Tangentially related: close votes *stay* present on the question until the bounty is removed. Thus even if there are 2 CVs on it, they remain visible until the bounty is removed, instead of until the bounty is added.

Comment: see also: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Off-topic questions should not be answered, regardless of whether a bounty is present or not. If none is present, the correct course of action is to close vote it, if one is present, either flag it with a custom reason explaining why it should be closed, and thus not have the bounty, or leave it be until the bounty is removed and then close it. This mechanism has been in place for years; personally I have flagged multiple questions with a bounty for closure (results may vary, previous results are no guarantee for the future).

If anything, this shows that in some cases the bounty privilege is given too soon and people bounty questions which should not be given a bounty before completely knowing what the site's rules on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are.

Edit: I see the user in question has >9k reputation, so it just shows you that you can be around a long time and have a distorted view of what goes and what doesn't go as a question.