# How to deal with a well-meaning Answerer who answers off-topic questions

Tags: discussion

I'm in a bit of a quandry. There's a person relatively new to the site whom I've known in on-line support capacity in MS forums for many years - we're colleagues, but also to a certain extent rivals.

From remarks this person has made recently outside of SO I know s/he does not really understand or respect the guidelines that SO has put in place about what is on-topic, what should be answered, etc. But this person is suddenly putting in more time here - I haven't asked why.

Now this person has answered a SuperUser type of question, correctly and competently - it just doesn't belong here. Were it someone I didn't have this kind of relationship with, I'd post a comment. The only type of flag I could raise would be to the moderator's attention - but I'm not sure that would be appropriate?

How to best handle this kind of situation? I don't feel I should ignore it...

Comment: downvote the low quality/not useful content, upvote the high quality/useful content. the rest will fall in place

Comment: Why wouldn't you post the same comment you would to anyone else, informing them of why their action is inappropriate?

Comment: I have a canned comment which reads *"We appreciate that you are only trying to help but this question does not meet our quality/topic standards. Providing answers to such low quality or off-topic questions only encourages equally low quality or off-topic questions. You might wish to consider removing this answer in the interests of the site."* I use for these occasions

Comment: ...plus a DV...

Comment: related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: You might consider leaving a comment on one of this user's posts, linking to this meta question and inviting him to answer it.

Comment: Kevin, Servy, Paulie_D - thank you. @Servy: Some things are better done by "neutral parties" when there's already a bit of friction. I'd already admonished this person for public berating of SO philosophy, aimed at a "messenger" (forum moderator) who advised an OP to ask here, rather than in that other forum. Even though SO is the official support channel of the software in question. Correction coming from me wouldn't help this person comply to SO guidelines, I don't believe, so wouldn't be productive for anyone involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm of two minds here.

If the question is off-topic *here*, but is **otherwise a good question** and **is concisely on-topic elsewhere**, then it's fine in my mind for them to answer the question and for you to flag for migration to the other location.  **You should only do this if you're *certain* the other question is a good fit for the target site.**  I would personally avoid any chatter about where the question belongs, since that can confuse the OP into thinking that they should delete their question here and repost *there*, when we could just migrate it instead.

If the question is off-topic *here*, and is **otherwise off-topic anywhere else**, or **you're not sure** if it's on-topic anywhere else, then it's not the *best* thing for them to answer the question.  I would encourage close votes and downvotes.  You have the option to leave a clarifying message when you do this, explaining your stance on the matter, but nothing further.

Comment: Absolutely a perfect Q&A pair for SuperUser. I had already advised the OP of this fact before the Answer was posted and the OP assures s/he will ask such questions there in the future. I also immediately voted to Close as off-topic and belonging on another site. I don't know of any way to request migration other than my close vote? But it can take quite some time for things in the ms-word tag queue to get processed...

Comment: @CindyMeister:  There are close-migrate votes, but depending on the site it may not be in the target list.  In those cases I'm absolutely willing to stake my reputation on it, I flag a moderator and request that the question gets migrated.

Comment: Thank you. In the end, it's probably best at this point for things to take their course. But this gives me a solid basis for the future, because I suspect this won't have been the last time...

Comment: @CindyMeister If (as you did ;) ) you vote to close using *"close > off-topic because… > Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."*, the question will not* be migrated. If you instead vote to close with *"close > off-topic because… >  This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network > belongs on [superuser.com](//superuser.com/help/on-topic)"*, the question will* automatically be migrated when it is closed…

Comment: … * The question will be migrated iff the majority of voters choose the "migrate" close reason, of course. PS Currently, meta.so, su, tex, dba, and stats are the five target sites available for question migrations.

Comment: @robinCTS Yes, the problem with the migration option is that it's so far away from the "doesn't belong here" option that it's not noticeable...

Comment: @CindyMeister In a way, that's a good thing ;) If it was easily discoverable, every Jack and Jill would attempt to migrate questions to other sites, even if they are were off-topic/unsuitable there. You really need to have carefully read the help for the target sites, and possibly even spent some time there, before migrating questions to them.

Comment: @CindyMeister Just noticed that Martijn Pieters basically said the same thing a comment to your meat post.