# Did specifically what help center told to do when wanting "on hold" repealed however I was told moderator intervention was unneeded

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderation, reopen-closed

I had a question, put on hold for what I believe to be a false premise, claiming it is too broad.  Okay, I have seen tons of similar questions, if it is too broad I would like a bit more of an explanation for how it is too broad.  I edit it asking how it is too broad and giving an example of another similar question.  I get no response and it stays on hold.

I believe that this is a scenario where moderator intervention would apply so I flag it, however "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" is the response.

Just checked an apparently the site agrees with me: "If a moderator (user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the question, then you may flag it for moderator attention. Again, do this only after editing and include a detailed explanation of why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions." in https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

I would like to say the duplicate message explicitly said to edit this post for reasoning on how this isn't a duplicate so I will.  My point in posting it here was not relevant to the "too broad" tag even though that is what people discussed.  My post was about how the help center explicitly tells people to request moderator intervention for posts mods put "on hold" when you disagree with a decision.  I did that and it was declined for being not relevant to mods, hence this post.  It has nothing to do with the circumstance for why my post was put on hold or if it was "too broad" or not.

Comment: If you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064944/what-is-the-point-of-a-testing-framework), you can't just compare a question to a 10-year old one. If that 10-year old question got asked now, I'm 100% sure it'd been closed as too broad as well. In fact, the timeline reveals it's been tried to close that question you refer to 3 times already, it probably only exists because by chance it didn't get closed initially and got good answers

Comment: @ErikA am not specifically disputing that, though I am disputing the fact that I was it not applicable to flag

Comment: @gnat also not applicable

Comment: Oh, _declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention_ is a standard decline reason. Pretty much all flags asking to reopen a question get declined for that reason, since any >3K user can vote to reopen a question and a substantial edit puts it in the reopen queue, so community members are free to disagree with it being closed, even though a mod closed it initially. Mod flags are really only if you want an action only a mod can perform.

Comment: It was a mod that put it on hold and Help Center specifically says if a moderator put it on hold to flag for moderator intervention, as I quoted @ErikA

Comment: Yeah, that clearly seems outdated to me, though I doubt it ever was common practice. But I certainly understand you didn't know that, and even might not take my word over the help center. Seems like that should be removed there.

Comment: I agree with the closure. Also, the question  you linked to was just closed by another moderator.

Comment: @Zoe That is fine, I am more disputing the seeming to be error in the help center.  Although, I have yet to find an answer to the question, and am open to suggestions on how to rephrase it to be more clear.

Comment: @Zoe Ha, so I guess I set a precedent

Comment: I would say that your explanation is not exactly detailed... I added a comment on your question @ mentioning the mod that closed it and that it's being discussed on meta.

Comment: @AidanWelch Your question wasn't unclear. It was too broad. Often, you can't do anything about that, except narrowing the question down (doesn't seem applicable to yours), or asking it elsewhere. That elsewhere might be [softwareengineering.se], they are more open to questions about the advantage/disadvantage of a specific approach, but I'm not sure it would be received well there too.

Comment: Also, it might be considered a duplicate of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/137302) on software engineering, though they're a little different, but be sure to research before asking for other possible duplicates

Comment: @ErikA I read that a few days ago, I thought the answer might be different for specifically node.js because it is the single language I have seen with the most adoption of test frameworks

Comment: I'm not active on software engineering, so take everything I say with a grain of salt, but if your question is distinct because it relates to node.js, I'd state that in the question. If you find related recent questions on Software Engineering that are well-received, that's a good indicator you're better off asking it there.

Comment: So would it be fair to say(and maybe advertise when a new user asks a question) that Software Engineering should be used for higher level theory while the main site should be used for specific questions on specific components?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fine.  I'll bite.

Your question is too broad because it questions the very utility of testing frameworks.  This is likely due to a misunderstanding of how testing frameworks are meant to behave at all.

You say

> I did notice Chai has assert stuff, but that seems to be purely for readability and not any functionality.

...but if you look into what asserts *actually* do, they provide quite a lot of useful stuff:

- They indicate that a test has failed from within the test framework
- They provide useful information (e.g. stack trace) to determine where the test failed, and sometimes why
- This information can be leveraged into a CI utility like CircleCI or Jenkins to give feedback on the health of your code through tests

...and all of *this* information is, regrettably, a bit too much [to simply teach you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368278/1079354).

Comment: I do appreciate the answer, I do now see how it was too broad, but that does not relate to this question.  Maybe this would be better suited to a comment of that post.

Comment: It relates to the question you asked.  You wanted an explanation as to why it was too broad.

Comment: Not here, I wanted a discussion on what seems to me like going back on the sites own recommendations

Comment: There's nothing to discuss.  Your question was too broad, and it was closed.  I can respect that you're *dissatisfied* with the fact that your question was closed, but that's not something my prose can rectify.

Comment: No, the discussion is not about the question, it is how the moderators actions when a review was flagged...

Comment: The flag was declined because the decision to *reopen* a question lies with the community (in 99% of the cases).  You've done your part by coming here to Meta and making a plea for it, but honestly I see nothing else to do as far as reopening the question.

Comment: I agree that the question could not be reopened, I can also see your point in that is lies with the community.  But I think you should recognize that the help center specifically says you should seek moderator intervention instead of going to the community

Comment: @AidanWelch No, it does not.  The help center says that you should have flagged your post *to explain why it should be reopened*, but you *asked for an explanation of why it's closed*.  The former is okay, the latter is not.

Comment: I realize I said that once, that is poor phrasing as that is not what I did

Answer (score 15):

You should *not* be editing your question to ask why the question is closed.  You should be editing your question to *narrow the scope of the question so it is not too broad*, or to clarify what the question was asking, if it was misinterpreted as asking for something broader than you intended.

Likewise, mods are not there to explain to you why your posts are problematic and how you can improve them, so you should not be flagging posts to ask moderators how you should fix your question.  You should be making every effort you can to improve your questions on your own, reading through the help center sections on the topic(s) at hand, and the other more general information and FAQs on meta on how to ask quality questions in order to figure out how to improve your question.

If you've done everything you can to try to address the problems with the question and it's still insufficient, you could ask on meta to explain what feedback you've gotten on your question, how you've tried to address that feedback, and why it was deemed insufficient, in an attempt to get some help in fixing your question.

Also note the existence of a single close-worthy question not being closed is not justification for your question to be reopened.  There are lots of questions that merit closure that haven't been closed.  The content curators are constantly falling behind the constant barrage of problematic questions, so there are always plenty that slip through the cracks.

Comment: Addendum: There are several thousand questions that get asked every day, and not nearly enough people to put eyes on each and every single one to curate them.  Using any question as a defense will usually lead to it being closed as well.  Much better to focus on your specific question than pointing to another question and saying, "But THAT one didn't get closed!"

Comment: As I said in the comments and as has been pointed out, my post on here does not relate specifically to that question so 2/3 of this answer is irrelevant.  And, addressing your second paragraph, as I said, you are specifically told to contact moderators when a moderator puts a question on hold if you dispute it.

Comment: Although, I would agree that I should have left that as a comment instead of an edit.  The sole reason I did that was because I was not sure if it would get re-reviewed if I commented, vs if I edit-ed

Comment: @AidanWelch You asked why your flag was declined, and you've gotten an answer.  Had you flagged your question to explain why your question was not in fact too broad, they would (probably) have evaluated the merits of your case and either reopened the question or declined it saying they disagreed with your argument, rather than the issue not meriting a mod flag.  But you instead *asked the moderator how to fix  your question*.  That is *not* what mods are there for, so your flag was declined accordingly.

Comment: @AidanWelch Intentionally doing things that you know you shouldn't be doing is generally not a good idea in general, but especially so when you're trying to get help correcting already problematic behavior.  It just makes people all the less likely to want to help you when you go around knowingly doing things that you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: No, I asked them what is wrong with my question not how to fix it.  I also did not ask why my flag was declined here, that was not a question ever brought up

Comment: @Servy That is not what I said again, I did not know it was bad practice, I hadn't considered that it was...

Comment: @AidanWelch Asking moderators what's wrong with your question is *also* not something you should be flagging them for.  You could have flagged your question *if you had fixed it already* to explain *why the question is not Too Broad*, but you didn't do that, so your flag was declined.  Sure, technically your "question" contains no question mark, but the implied question is why your flag was declined.

Comment: @AidanWelch You can't say that you knowingly did something you shouldn't have, and then in response to me saying that's a bad thing, walk it back and say you didn't know it was a bad idea.

Comment: @Servy How can I fix something if I have no idea what the issue is?  Say I were a moderator and I closed a question you asked for being primarily opinion based, say you did not consider it opinion based and you asked how it was and I did not respond.  Would that not be an appropriate time to ask for another moderator to intervene, especially if the help center indicates you should?

Comment: @Servy I said I agree that I made a poor decision, I never indicated I agreed then...

Comment: @AidanWelch No, it's *not* appropriate for you to be flagging posts to ask people questions about why it's problematic.  I was rather explicit about that in my answer.  Additionally the help center is *not* telling you to flag posts to ask moderators why your post is problematic, it's telling you to flag posts closed by a moderator *if you have fixed them to address the problems* so it can be reopened.  It is *your* responsibility to fix your own posts, not other people's responsibility to fix them for you, or tell you how to fix them.

Comment: @Servy As I said, I did not believe my post had a problem...  Hence why I flagged for intervention.

Comment: @AidanWelch Had you flagged your post to explain why it is not Too Broad, instead of to ask why your question is Too Broad, then as I said, it would have been either marked helpful or declined due to a moderator disagreeing with your argument (almost certainly the latter, because the question is very clearly Too Broad), not because it's something that shouldn't be flagged.  But you didn't do that, you flagged to ask something that's *not appropriate to do in a flag*, and it was declined accordingly.

Comment: I said specifically "I don't see how my question is too broad but stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing is not" I did not ask for a specific answer, but I can not rebuke an argument when I have no idea what it is.  I asked a moderator to review if it really is too broad

Comment: It seems like a lot of your disagreement with me comes from you assuming stuff I never said

Comment: @AidanWelch For like the fifth time, explaining that you don't understand why your question is closed *is not an appropriate reason to flag a question*.  You could have flagged your question to explain why it's *not* Too Broad.  You didn't.  You chose to flag it to say you don't understand why it's Too Broad.  That's not an appropriate flag, it was declined accordingly.  If you can explain why your question is sufficiently narrow, you can flag it.  That you don't even understand why your question is problematic is not something a moderator is there to solve.

Comment: @AidanWelch What have I assumed you said that you did not in fact say?

Comment: @Servy For the fifth time, I did not ask for an explanation I asked for a review...  And, I feel I did explain how it was not too broad the best I could when I don't know the counter-argument.  So I ask you, how could I have narrowed down my question?

Comment: @Servy That I "Intentionally did things I knew I should not be doing."

Comment: @AidanWelch *No, you did not*.  You did not explain why your question wasn't Too Broad, and ask for it to be reopened.  You said that you didn't understand why your question is problematic, which is asking the moderator to explain to you why your question is problematic and how to fix it.  That is not an appropriate flag, and so it was declined.  Saying, "I don't understand why my question is Too Broad" is not explaining why your question is not too broad.  It's not the same question in the slightest.  I don't see how that question can be narrowed sufficiently myself.

Comment: @AidanWelch Considering there's still a comment on my answer of you saying you did something that you knew you shouldn't have, that doesn't seem like a false assumption.  Anything else?

Comment: @Servy How do you disagree with something when you don't know what its argument is?  That is what you don't seem to grasp, I disagreed with the closing, I did not know how to argue against it though as I did not know the reason for it...

Comment: @Servy I said "Although, I would agree that I should have left that as a comment instead of an edit." I did not say "Although, I would like to say I knew at the time I should have left a comment instead of an edit."

Comment: @AidanWelch Saying that you can't explain why the question isn't too broad because you don't understand why it's too broad doesn't make the flag any more appropriate.  That you can't do something doesn't make it okay to do something else that's prohibited instead.  You can't explain why your question isn't Too Broad until you understand why it's too broad.  That's certainly true, but it doesn't change the fact that *it's not appropriate to flag posts to ask why they're problematic*.  It's not the moderator's job to tutor you on what a good question is and why yours is problematic.

Comment: It is not prohibited, it is recommended, the help center specifically says if you disagree with a from a moderator closure to flag...  I disagreed and presented the best argument possible in the scenario for why

Comment: @AidanWelch No, it's *not* recommended that you ask moderators to explain why your question is problematic.  It's recommended that you explain *why your question merits being reopened*.  You didn't do that.  That you can't doesn't change the fact that you didn't do it.  You did not explain why your question isn't Too Broad, you *asked why your question is Too Broad*.  The former is recommended, the latter is not.

Comment: The merits of the question were that it wasn't too broad.(My argument at the time) There is nothing to add to that, how can one specifically argue more than that for how something isn't a subjective adjective without first hearing how it is?

Comment: @AidanWelch You *didn't* say that your question was not Too Broad.  You said you didn't understand why it's too broad.  If you just said, "it's not too broad" your flag would have instead been declined with the moderator saying they didn't agree, rather than because it's not something you should flag.  Again, that you can't explain why your question isn't Too Broad because you don't understand why it's Too Broad doesn't make it okay to ask a moderator why it's Too Broad.  Do your own research, read through the help center, look at the FAQs, *figure it out*, if you want the question reopened.

Comment: English is a language full of inquisitive negatives, if you said the Earth was flat and I said I don't see how you could think that, that is me disagreeing with you by nature of the statement but also leaving the opportunity for you to explain.  Also, I did read the help center and it specifically backed my actions...

Comment: @AidanWelch No, the help center *does not* back your actions.  The help center tells you that you can flag the question *to explain why it's not close worthy*, not to ask someone else to explain why it's close worthy.  That you were trying to be passively aggressively disagreeing with someone instead of stating your disagreement doesn't change the fact that you *were not following the directions of the help center*, and does not make your actions any more appropriate.  If you want to know why your question is Too Broad, I've given you lots of advice, but flagging is not the appropriate action.

Comment: I did explain, I did not ask a question. I left the opportunity to explain, as I explained to you.  Leaving the opportunity is not the same as asking a question

Comment: @AidanWelch No, you did *not* explain why your question is not Too Broad.  You said that you don't understand why it's too broad.  That's not an explanation of why it's not Too Broad.  While you may not have used a question mark, you stated that you did not understand something and expected someone else to explain it to you.  While it wasn't *grammatically* a question, it was conceptually you asking for an explanation, which is equivalent.

Comment: @AidanWelch But anyway, if you want to quibble, not only is asking a moderator why your question is problematic not acceptable in a flag, but "leaving the opportunity" for a moderator to explain why your question is problematic is *also* not acceptable in a flag, for exactly the same reasons, because you're asking them to do exactly the same thing, namely explain to you why your question is problematic.  That's not what they're there for.

Comment: So if you said "I wouldn't mind you giving me something" is that the same as you asking for it?  No, and like I said I did explain in that I gave an example of a similar question knowing there were many more like it.  That is an explanation, granted not a very good one, but as I have stated before, the best one possible in the scenario

Comment: @AidanWelch Yes, yes it *is* the same.  It's grammatically different, but it's a different phrasing of the same fundamental behavior.  But more importantly, both "asking a moderator a question" and "giving the moderator the opportunity to answer a question that is implied but not asked" are both not, "explaining to the moderator why a question should be reopened".  As for linking to another open question, my answer explains why that is in no way an explanation of why a given question is not Too Broad.

Comment: A single sentence can check two boxes...  I said I disagreed with the closure because there were examples of similar questions that weren't closed and gave an example.  While doing that I left the opportunity open for a discussion.  Can you with intellectual honesty say that is not a fair explanation of "I don't see how my question is too broad but stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing is not"?

Comment: @AidanWelch Saying, "there is another question that is too broad that isn't closed" is not explaining why your question isn't Too Broad.  You did not explain *why your question should not be closed*, you just pointed out another question that needed to be closed.

Comment: It seems we just a fundamental disagreement in our understanding of English making this discussion pointless, also it has become very cyclic