# Is it allowed to invite a new user to a private online collaborative editor if their question was rightfully closed?

Tags: discussion, rules

I've stumbled upon a small issue today. A new user asked a question that clearly didn't fit SO's guidelines. Even though the question was clear, it was simply Too Broad.

I wanted to take some time to teach the user how to solve his issue. But as the user only has 1 rep and cannot join SO chat, there's no way to contact him.

So I've made an online collaborative editor on my server where I can invite a user to teach. The editor requires no registration or anything and cannot be used again after I closed it. There's no advertisement of any kind either.

Is it allowed to post a link towards this editor in the comments?

I'm asking because some other user joined it and called it advertising and stealing users from SO. While that's clearly not the intention and, since the room is destroyed after use and no registration is possible, technically not even possible.

Edit:

Suggested duplicate: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

I agree the duplicate anwers most of my question. However, my *specific* question is if it's allowed to do this or not. Not whether it's advised to or not.

Comment: Note: the "advise" in [the linked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) isn't "is it advised", but rather "should I advise". (And acceptable behaviour on the site is often determined by community consensus.)

Comment: @Dukeling Right. That makes sense. Unfortunetely I can no longer accept the dupe at this point, I think?

Comment: I don't know who voted to reopen this question, but you might want to add a comment as to _why_ it should be reopened. It seems to me the question is clearly answered, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My opinion is that you should at most point a user to a place where their off-topic question, along with any new similar question they may have, would be accepted (at any time).

If the user can post any future questions to the collaborative editor at any time, and quickly receive an answer, I wouldn't really have a problem with it (but I'm guessing this isn't the case, since you presumably have to sleep at some point).

But simply helping them with *this* question encourages them to ask questions here again in hopes of having the same happen (maybe they're hoping you'll help them again, maybe they'll hope anyone does, but the bottom line is asking their bad question here "worked", so why wouldn't they do it again?).

Comment: Good point. I didn't think that last part through. I know of such a place (Free Code Camp). But to me a link to it would clearly be advertisement (even though it's free and open source). That's why I didn't do that.

Comment: @icecub  The accusations of "advertising and stealing users from SO" are, in this context, absurd, so don't worry about this specific issue. The flip side of Stack Overflow insisting on a very specific Q&A format is that Stack Overflow is not and should not be a monopoly.

Answer (score 7):

I think the user who accused you of stealing traffic from Stack Overflow was a little over the top.  Taking the OP who asked a bad question away from the site certain isn't going to cause problems with SO's traffic.

As for whether the concept is appropriate, I would say this ***could*** be ok depending on what your goal is when working with the user.

- Do you want to help them with their specific question and give them an answer?  I'd strongly advise against that for the [same reason Dukeling mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374313/250725) - it only encourages them to come back and ask more off topic questions in the hope that an experienced user stops by and walks them through their problem and gives them the answer
- Do you want to help the user understand why their question was closed and help teach them how to rework their question into something suitable for SO (how to reformulate the question, how to debug the problem, how to construct an MCVE)?  If so, then go for it.  Stack Overflow tried that with a mentoring experiment a few months ago.  But if you do it too much, you are likely to burn yourself out and give up quickly.

Comment: My intention was somewhere in the middle. I didn't just want to answer the question. I could've done that with a link to a JSFiddle. I wanted to teach the user how to search and understand the code itself. I agree expending upon that by teaching how SO works would even be better.