# Should I downvote/flag an answer to an unreproducible question?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, minimal-reproducible-example

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71704860/7884305) was asked.

Now, this question is not reproducible. When I paste the code in the playground, [it works perfectly fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c06dbe4816c71820a07be8bb30b035c) (the compiler can infer the type). Of course, I need to flag the question for closure (and perhaps also downvote it), which I did.

But this question [has got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706099/7884305). This answer is not blatantly wrong: I'd answer the same if I hadn't bothered to actually check the question is reproducible. Moreover, this answer *can* be true in other cases (for example, if the type was specified at return type position. Maybe this was the original problem, and the OP effectively erased it without knowing while minimizing the question). I guess that's what the other people that upvoted it thought (in fact, I was about to upvote it too, then noticed the compiler should not behave this way and went to check).

What should I do in this case? Should I "punish" the answerer for not checking the question really applies by downvoting the answer? I don't think we should always check that (I, for one, don't). Should I flag it for moderator intervention? Or just leave a comment, like I did?

While relevant, this question is *not* a duplicate of [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions). I agree we shouldn't downvote good questions for bad answers, but in this case it's not just that the answer is not high-quality, but that it's just there is no question at all. Pedantically, the answer is incorrect because it doesn't "solve" the problem, as no such problem exists. In addition, even if we should not downvote it, we may want to flag it.

Comment: Downvotes are not punishment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)

Comment: @pppery Nope. Edited to clarify.

Comment: if *you*  cannot reproduce the problem, maybe you should have asked for clarification (question): which version, how OP is testing, ....

Comment: @user16320675 I didn't mean to discuss the correct thing to do with the question, only the answer.

Comment: that is why I did not write an *answer* (thanks for clarification, but you not wanting it does not mean I don't - also maybe you are asking this with wrong premise, like assuming OP did not get the given error)

Comment: Re *"this question is not reproducible"*: It is difficult to prove a negative. Some are [still using Turbo C++](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra) from the 1990s (e.g., forced to as part of internships *required* for university or engineering school graduation).

Comment: Related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Even the top answerer seemed to admit that their answer is wrong, though.

Comment: Have you considered that both the OP and answerer have a different configuration than yours that behave exactly as described?

Comment: @MarkRansom It's highly improbable in this case and the answerer admitted it works.

Comment: You could vote to delete the question. I just did.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Should I "punish" the answerer

**No, never**

Upvotes and downvotes are a way to measure the **usefulness of content**, not a means of retribution, education, or encouragement. We vote on **content**, anything outside it should be irrelevant when considering whether to vote up or down (feel free to use the votes as you see fit otherwise, though — if you think the answer is not useful, vote accordingly).

> Should I flag it for moderator intervention

**No**

Moderators are human exception handlers. Their intervention is required for disruptive actions, acts of plagiarism, during heated disputes, etc. This is just a user posting an answer to a potentially unclear question — such a situation can be resolved through normal means (close voting, editing, commenting, downvoting [if the answer is not useful], and so on).

> Or just leave a comment, like I did

**Yes**

Leaving a comment stating that the problem is not reproducible is, of course, fine, that's what the comments are for, after all: clarifications, improvements, inquiries.

Comment: Yep, nothing to flag, and +1 for the Comment, and what about (also) posting their own Answer...?

Comment: @chivracq If the problem is not reproducible then there is no answer, because there is no real question. Thus the only reason to post their own answer would be to say "this is not reproducible" which is what comments are for.

Comment: @van dench, yep, I understand that Reasoning, but I now find the existing Answer not "very clear" after several Edits, with some stricken Content that I "understand" like "This Content/Answer was correct "at some point/in some cases" but not anymore...", maybe related to the MRE being "too minimum"..., or from using different Versions, ... but nobody in the Thread mentions which Version they are using/testing in, except indirectly the 2 'Playground' Links (with `playground v0.0.1` + `edition=2021`)...

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that the answers to the question that the OP asks about are wrong.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine "feel free to use the votes as you see fit otherwise"

Answer (score 11):

I admittedly don't know much about Rust, but in the particular case you mention, the comments seem to indicate that the top answer is wrong, and the other answer seems quite low-quality overall. (Even the edit to the top answer seems to indicate that the answerer knows that their answer is actually wrong, so it's unclear to me why they even left it up). So yes, they should be downvoted.

If a question is really and truly not reproducible, then answers will, by definition, either be wrong, not really address the question, or be to the effect of "this actually works!" Since none of those are useful answers, yes, you should downvote.

If answers are *not* of one of those forms, though, then the question probably is reproducible after all.

Also, as indicated in the other answer, votes aren't to "punish" people for behavior you don't like - they're to indicate whether the content is useful or not. (Note that my answer recommends downvoting these answers solely for the reason that the content is unlikely to be useful). The community doesn't target users, just content; if someone is behaving poorly, the moderators should be asked to step in and handle the situation.