# How to best get an answer for a downvoted question?

Tags: discussion

Please note, I am *not* asking 'Why was my question downvoted?'. Nor am I asking 'What is wrong with my question?' or any of the other things that show up on Meta so often.

What I want to know is, 'What's the appropriate course of action to take now that will actually help me solve my problem?'

Once a question drops to about -2 or so it's never going to be seen by anybody again and is basically a writeoff. It's *possible* to ask via a comment on the question why it got downvoted and see if they can be persuaded to remove the downvotes; but this is almost certainly going to be ineffective, as such a confrontational environment is not going to lead to a useful conversation. (This is covered elsewhere: [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react))

Alternatively, it's possible to rephrase the question and repost. But it's still going to be, fundamentally, the same question, which means that it's effectively posting a duplicate, which I believe is against the rules, and is certainly against the spirit of the site.

I'm all in favour of downvoting poor questions if they're not useful to the site --- but that doesn't actually help get the question answered; simply giving up is not always an option.

So what's the most effective thing to do in this situation?

Comment: It doesn't scale well, but if you're looking for trial-by-fire, you can edit a link to your question into this Meta question. Meta users are happy to oblige you with a vote, but there is no guarantee whether it will be up or down.

Comment: "Once a question drops to about -2 or so it's never going to be seen by anybody again and is basically a writeoff." That's too strong a statement. I've run into a few questions that were downvoted to -3 or lower because the OP used confusing language. Whenever I could make out what the OP actually meant, and found a good question, I edited the question, upvoted it, and answered.

Comment: @Magisch I actually deliberately didn't link to it, because I didn't want the conversation to turn into a 'You should have done X' or to be seen as an attempt to appeal to the Meta gods. Don't suppose you could remove your comment, please?

Comment: @DavidGiven If thats what you want, ok. But everyone can see this post by clicking through your profile slightly.

Comment: @Magisch I was slightly hoping that nobody would bother looking. Ha, foolish me!

Comment: The problem with this (Meta) question is that it sounds like you want an answer to your question regardless of its quality or if it's on-topic or not. "Fix the problems with your question" is the only right answer, but it sounds like you don't want to hear that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Sure! But thing is, though, that all questions want answers --- that's why they get asked. Marking a question as being bad doesn't solve the underlying problem which caused it to be asked. The situation now, in fact, seem to encourage the situation where a question being marked as bad means that it *won't* be answered, ever. This seems like a workflow failing.

Comment: We're not here to answer every question just because someone wants an answer to it.

Comment: the primary purpose of voting question down is [to prevent it from being seen and answered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601). Question with negative score doesn't get answers => mission accomplished

Comment: Every one of my questions is worse than a writeoff - it's a target for the revenge downvoters:(

Answer (score 7):

The question to ask yourself about your question is *why* are people downvoting it? Yes, ask yourself, not the downvoters. *Why* do people not think it is useful? Is it poorly researched? Am I asking too many things in a single question? [All of this stuff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Try to figure out if there is any way that you can edit it to improve it. If you can, great—editing will "bump" it and probably get some fresh eyes on it. If you succeeded in improving the question, it will hopefully get some upvotes. If you were not successful, well, it never hurts to try.

It is *possible* that a low-score question will be seen by others. For example, people that browse questions by tags rather than on the home page will still see your question. Of course, there's no guarantee that they'll click on it if has a low score. The way to encourage them to click on it is to have a really descriptive, interesting-sounding title. That's usually how I decide whether or not to click on a question.

But you're right, it is not likely. If you can't improve the question and attract some upvotes, you are not looking good to get an answer. It may be time to consider that Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask your question. You either need to go back to the drawing board, or maybe do some more research so that you can ask a different question. As wonderful as the site is, we unfortunately cannot *guarantee* you an answer.

As for the fate of the ill-fated question, it doesn't hurt to leave it on the site—someone might happen along and answer it some day. Deleting it is not necessarily an advantage to you, unless you're convinced it is worthless. Deleting and re-asking the same question again is *not* a good idea, and a good way to attract the ire of the community, as you've said.

Comment: Thanks, but I really didn't want to discuss my specific question (which is why I didn't link to it).

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Magisch posted a link, and I added the explanation before I saw your comments. Happy to remove it.

Comment: Regarding the wider issue: the trouble with this advice is that it basically boils down to 'you get one chance, then you're stuffed'. Which is fine _in aggregate_, which is a lot what SO cares about (because it's successful). But it's very unhelpful in the case of the individual question, because it basically doesn't get answered; so it's going to lead to unsatisfied clients. A set of guidelines for what to do *next* sounds to me like it would lead to an overall happier experience.

Comment: Well, that *is* sort of true. I mean, the idea is that you basically have an infinite amount of time to compose a good question *before* posting it, so we expect it to meet a certain minimum quality standard right out of the box. But you are not *completely* stuffed; there are alternatives in place. Even if the question gets closed, it can still be reopened. The chief way of doing that is to edit the question to improve it. I discussed this in my answer. I'm not really sure what other types of strategies you were *hoping* for. @david

Comment: Well, I dunno. That's why it was tagged as [discussion]!

Comment: @CodyGray I would not have edited out the part of your answer that dealt with the problems of the OP's question. The OP asks in the Meta question here "What's the appropriate course of action to take now that will actually help me solve my problem?" That part you removed from your answer highlights *exactly* "the appropriate course of action". It was excellent advice.

Comment: @louis David has said several times that he prefers not to focus on a specific question, and I see no compelling reason for me not to respect that request. The removed portion is rather specific to him, so if he wants to read it, it's in the revision history. I don't think the answer loses any general relevance without it.