# Why was my edit on adding an 'algorithm` tag declined?

Tags: discussion, edits

I saw 3 questions and added an algorithm *tag* to them.
2 of them got approved with 3 straight approves and one of them got rejected with 3 straight rejects.

I am curious, Can some look into them and see what was the difference?

**Approved Edit**

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38945332/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26395766/revisions

**Rejected Edit**

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13356908

Comment: Note: You have links to questions and not to edits...

Comment: I know, can't you just see the edit history?

Comment: *Is it possible to force iterator...to jump by two symbols* Doesn't sound like it should be tagged with algorithm.

Comment: I don't think rejected edits are in the history (at least there is no history on third question at all)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I only added the algorithm tag, which was rejected.

Comment: @BSMP but the others do look like an algorithm question? Why?

Comment: As a note, you can find links to completed suggested edit reviews, regardless of outcome, in the affected post's timeline. (URL format: `stackoverflow.com/posts/{postId}/timeline` for any that didn't know.)

Comment: Side note: "algorithm" is very controversial tag. I'd not add that myself to questions unless I'm looking for some downvotes on the question :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OK so you're saying the tag shouldn't have been added to neither of the questions?

Comment: *but the others do look like an algorithm question? Why?* Wait, why did you add the tag if you didn't think so?

Comment: @BSMP I mean that to me all 3 fall into the same category, if they were to be declined then all 3 should have been declined, what is the difference? Enlighten me

Comment: It's a lot more obvious that the third question isn't a question [related to algorithm design or looking for an abstract solution](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithm/info).

Comment: @Honey the only think I'm saying is I would not do such edit. "Algorithm" collects all sorts of questions (somewhat close to "android" :) ) and is somewhat hard to find good fit. See recent [discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332155/why-are-questions-on-the-algorithms-tag-downvoted-closed-so-aggressively/332201#332201) on it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the people doing the different reviews are not the same people. There is a known problem with reviewers who blindly approve reviews and I am guessing that the edits that where approved just got reviewed by different people.

[Approved review 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13344569)
[Approved review 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13356915)
[Rejected Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13356908)

Comment: @nit perhaps nit can explain why he rejected one and approved another

Answer (score 3):

[algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) is [a problematic tag to begin with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332155/why-are-questions-on-the-algorithms-tag-downvoted-closed-so-aggressively). A question that really is about algorithm is almost always better suited for programmers.se or computer science.se.

That being said, *none* of the edits should have been approved imho, but there are too many robo-approvers.

Going through the questions, and applying the categories from the accepted answer of the previoulsy linked Q&A, we get arrive at

A question about a **problem**, not an algorithm: [iOS - selecting second lowest number in integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945332/ios-selecting-second-lowest-number-in-integer-array)

Again, a question about a **problem**, not an *algorithm*: [Swift: what is the right way to split up a [String] resulting in a [[String]] with a given subarray size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395766/swift-what-is-the-right-way-to-split-up-a-string-resulting-in-a-string-wi)

and again, a question about a **problem**, not an *algorithm*:
[Split string by two symbols in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979657/split-string-by-two-symbols-in-swift)

*None* of these question actually have any questions *about an algorithm*.

The last one *could* be edited a bit into a good Q&A (how one can force an iterator to step twice instead of once), but then it would be about a concrete *coding problem, not an algorithm.

Finally, an algorithm is a formalism for instructions that are done in sequence. If applied too literally, every question that either includes code, or prompts for an answer that might include code, would be about algorithms (since every statement in a programming language is an - albeiot very short, and necessarily useful - algorithm.

Comment: Can you explain what question would fall into the category of `algorithm`? Do you differentiate between an easy or hard algorithm?

Comment: I am trying to find a very good meta post I read only a few days ago about that very topic, but so far I came up empty. I will update my answer as soon as I find it, but its almost midnight where I live ;)

Comment: @Honey I finally managed to find it moments after posting my previous comment, and have linked the meta discussion in my answer. I encourage you to read and and the very good answers there on why that tag leads to disputes.