# Should there be support for the same question being visible to multiple communities, to handle cases of overlap?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, cross-posting, site-crossover

A frequent occurrence with the algorithms tag is that questions get downvoted or closed by people who think such questions are better suited for *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* or *[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)*. I don't know if something similar happens for other tags since this is the main one I follow.

Where there are multiple natural communities to post a question, should there be support for built-in crossposting? E.g., this could work by having the OP or an editor with sufficient privilege tag the question for crosspost to the relevant communities, after which the questions, all answers, and all comments would show up on all communities.

Would this be desirable?

If not, where a question fits the guidelines of multiple communities, should the OP be downvoted or the question closed if they pick a valid but suboptimal community? E.g., an algorithms question that is valid for Stack Overflow, but that the person casting the vote feels would be better suited for *Mathematics*?

Comment: Also, since you don't have many meta questions, you may not be familiar with how voting works here. Please see the [Voting is Different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) section of this link if this is the case.

Comment: What do you mean by "the algorithms tag"? Is it the tag *[algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)* (40 times more questions than #2, tag *[graph-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory?tab=Newest)* (redirects to *graph-theory*))? Or something else?

Comment: "questions get downvoted or closed by people who think such questions are better suited for" Where is your justification for this claim? It doesn't matter what other sites a question might be suited for or how relatively suited it is. [so] score votes & close votes (& other responses) are according to its own protocols. Of course a response may be that it is "better" for the poster to post a question that merits downvotes and/or close votes on another site.

Comment: @philipxy Good question. Strictly anecdotal, based on people commenting about it, which is infrequent. E.g., "Also note that this isn't so much a programming question as it is a maths question. So this is kind of the wrong place to ask (for now. Once you start implementing it, and the code's not doing what you expect it to, this might be the right place to ask for help)", for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967029/how-to-efficiently-cover-a-set-of-points-with-circles-when-you-cant-access-poin/74970725

Comment: @PeterMortensen The tag algorithm.

Comment: Regarding 'algorithm' tag specifically: [Why are questions on the algorithms tag downvoted/closed so aggressively?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332155/2821954)

Answer (score 8):

Regarding:

> "should the ... question closed if they pick a valid but suboptimal community? E.g., an algorithms question that is valid for S/O but that the person casting the vote feels would be better suited for math.stackexchange.com?"

The model for this site is and has been that site users can vote as they see fit. Unless their voting is part of a voting ring, or unless they are voting targeting an individual user, I don't see how changing this model by accusing site members of bad faith in voting would be helpful or achievable.

And,

> "should the OP be downvoted..."

downvotes are on the question as a sign-post of perceived quality of the question, and they are not on the poster, again unless targeted voting is occurring.  If targeted voting is suspected, and if the site does not automatically reverse this in the expected period of time, a moderator should be involved.

> "A frequent occurrence with the algorithms tag is that questions get downvoted or closed by people who think such questions are better suited to math.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com."

There are of course two edges to this, and in fact, some *may* be better suited being posted in other communities. To best avoid this would be for the original poster to show in a concrete fashion *why* their question is best suited for this site, probably by their showing the relevant code in their language of choice, and discussing the code-specific problem(s) that they are having.

> "Where there are multiple natural communities to post a question, should there be support for built-in crossposting? E.g., this could work by having the OP or an editor with sufficient privilege tag the question for crosspost to the relevant communities, after which the questions, all answers, and all comments would show up on all communities."

My fear is that this would unnecessarily muddy the water. How would this be achieved? Multiple discussions on multiple sites? This would risk unnecessary duplication of effort, allowing a member to "spin their wheels" posting something that has already been well solved elsewhere.  Would we allow other communities to vote and contributing to data on a shared site? One of the keys to this site is to maintain a high degree of focus, and this would tilt things in the wrong way, and so I don't think that this is either feasible or desirable.

Comment: "How would this be achieved? Multiple discussions on multiple sites?" -- I was unclear. What I meant was that the question would be visible on multiple sites, not that duplicate questions would be posted to multiple sites. I don't know how these sites work under the hood so maybe it isn't feasible. E.g., I post a question on S/O and tag it as also being on Math. Then you post an answer on S/O and John posts an answer on Math. Both answers are visible on both sites, without people copying their answers to multiple sites. Ditto for comments.

Comment: @Dave: so, in that situation focus would be lost as the question would need to be on-topic for many sites and would be allowed to accept answers from all sites, meaning that we'd now have answers from the math site. Not good.

Comment: The situation is where questions are already on topic for multiple sites. If a question is on-topic for math & S/O then why wouldn't S/O want an answer from the math site?

Comment: I accept that my idea is undesirable, unfeasible, or both. I'm frustrated by how often algorithms questions get closed or downvoted by people for being off-topic on S/O, often by people with little or no rep on either the algorithms tag or the alternate site. I try to point out that algorithms are specifically allowed as being on-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Dave: no, all you're getting with my answer is that *I feel that it is undesirable and unfeasible*. Others may still feel differently, and I can accept that.

Comment: @Dave what is allowed in is unrelated to quality voting. Just because something is on-topic does not imply that it is deemed useful. Unfortunately there are a number of tags on the site which are in a grey area, you have to be lucky with the eyeballs that land on it. IMO there should be more awareness about the specific tags which fall in that region because you have to be extremely precise with your wording in such questions, but then you'd have to start maintaining lists of tags in the documentation and nobody really wants to do that.

Comment: @Gimby What would you think of a generic approach then -- something like: The close & downvote rep thresholds being calculated on a per-tag basis, or guidance that you shouldn't vote for something to be closed on the basis of being better suited to another site if you don't have some minimum rep threshold for that other site?

Comment: @Dave I think that sounds complicated, complicated things are not implemented.