# Can we make receiving a downvote a more welcoming experience?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, welcoming

People tend to take downvotes personally<sup>[citation needed]</sup>. It seems that new users are more likely than established users to feel negative about a downvote, and since new users are less familiar with site norms, it seems that posts by new users, especially questions, are more likely to attract downvotes than posts by established users. This seems to be especially true for the first question a new user ever asks.

But it seems to me that downvotes are rarely, if ever, *intended* to be personal. Other than malicious/pathological downvoting behavior (which does exist, but certainly is a small fraction of all downvotes), it seems clear that the vast majority of downvotes are directed at *content* and not at *people*.

Well-meaning users downvote content that is below the standard that we would like to preserve on this site. That's a good thing: it enables ranking and helps the quality questions and answers "rise to the top". However, users who receive downvotes rarely perceive this as a good thing, and this seems to be a key driver of the perception of Stack Overflow being unwelcoming.

With that in mind, could there be some kind of "just in time" feedback displayed to a new user the first time they receive a downvote? (Possible variations could be: first downvote on a question only, first N times a downvote is received, first N posts that are downvoted, first time a post goes below zero in total score, etc.)

As a strawman, I'm imagining a little box that says something like:

> A user has voted this post down. This is feedback on the *post*, not on *you*, so please don't take it personally! Stack Overflow uses voting (both up and down) to help us identify which questions and answers are likely to be useful to future visitors and should be archived, as opposed to questions and answers that don't need to be preserved or wouldn't help anyone else in the future. We're sure, like everyone else here, you've benefited from posts that others have written in the past, and so our reputation system is designed to help everyone to "pay it forward" by incentivizing new questions and answers to benefit as many people as possible.

Comment: can't believe that I would ever upvote a post that contains "downvote" and "make more welcoming" in the title but... there you go, have a +1 :)

Comment: ...with regards to _needed citation_, my favorite one comes to mind: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: They may sound a bit cynical, but *any* non-positive feedback is going to be taken as a unwelcoming. New user posts a question, they want an *answer* and nothing short of it. And they'll react strongly on any negative feedback. They won't know that downvotes are not personal attacks, and they won't be interested in learning that. I'd argue that the best way to avoid the perception of being unwelcoming is to refrain from any interaction. If the goal is to be welcoming to all users, then *no* feedback is better than negative feedback even if it's constructive feedback.

Comment: @Mystical: That's why I'm proposing that the *system* should be the source of the feedback (and that the downvote itself should remain anonymous). It communicates constructive feedback to the users that most need it. Even if we imagine that the vast majority of users that receive that feedback ignore it or find it unwelcoming, we still would have improved the experience for the subset of new users who actually care -- precisely the users that we want to ensure have a welcoming experience!

Comment: That brings up an interesting point. While it may be counterproductive to content improvement and somewhat counter to the spirit of SO, hiding the actual score to the new user for X amount of time may go a long way to suppressing the "unwelcomingness". When the post does get downvoted, then you throw kindly written system messages at the user.

Comment: If the user "gets it", (s)he'll edit the question and improve. If not (as would probably be the case for help vampires), let the question keep accumulating downvotes and roomba'ed. I remember Tim Post saying that the best way to get a new user to leave is to completely ignore them. In the case of vampires, you *want* them to leave. And hiding the negative feedback may just be the way to do it without being unwelcoming.

Comment: Years of discussion and, still, there is nothing between a downvote - anonymous but not optimally helpful, and a comment - possibly very helpful but has a username as a target in those other cases where the OP wants a fight.  Can we not have the nice thing of one anonymous, (not to mods/CM),  comment to explain what is seen as wrong with a question?

Comment: Do you really expect people to *read* all that? And even if they did, to feel better? If you say "don't take it personal", people tend to take it personal anyways, in my experience. And yeah, it kinda is personal, because it tells them they made a mistake - they did not do the research needed for a good question. I'm not really convinced a text box would have any impact whatsoever.

Comment: @Polygnome if someone is looking at their question and going "WHY THE F AM I DOWNVOTED?" seeing a popup with the word "downvote" might get them interested in reading the post. It can't guarantee good reception. But it is leagues better than what we have right now (nothing)