# Display a message to the OP the first time they receive a downvote

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, welcoming

Here's the feature request: When a new user receives a downvote on a question they asked for the first time, the system should display a message, only visible to that user, similar to the existing messaging to a question asker when the question receives a close vote.

The text should explain the purpose of downvotes and emphasize that a downvote is not a criticism of the *user*, but of the *content*. I suggest using phrasing that highlights that the purpose of voting is ranking the post for *other users*.

Additionally, the visual depiction of the votes for the user's post should show a different symbol (possibly an exclamation point or similar) rather than a negative numeric score. This would serve to de-emphasize the numeric score and instead emphasize the message that the post could use some improvement.

Note that this feature request is different from other, similar proposals. The proposal here is for a message that is only visible to the user who received the downvote, so it won't create clutter or replies like a comment would. Also, it wouldn't actually prevent downvotes or affect the experience for existing users who have downvote privileges.

Also this behavior wouldn't be permanent: it could be tied to just the first time a user receives a downvote (or perhaps the first N times). Alternatively, "view downvotes on your questions" could be a privilege unlocked at some low reputation score (maybe 15 or 20 rep?). Possibly we could have similar treatment for all kinds of posts, but initially we should focus on the experience only for question askers.

I expect that the text of the message might need wordsmithing, but here is a straw man proposal:

> This question has received some negative feedback. Stack Overflow uses voting, both up and down, to help us identify which questions and answers are likely to be useful to future visitors and should be featured or archived. Negative feedback won't prevent you from receiving answers, but if you edit this question you may be able to receive better answers. For more information, see the help center.

---

Background: In the discussions *[Can we make it more obvious to new users that downvotes on the main site are not insults and in fact can help them help themselves?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366889/can-we-make-it-more-obvious-to-new-users-that-downvotes-on-the-main-site-are-not)* and *[Can we make receiving a downvote a more welcoming experience?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373433/can-we-make-receiving-a-downvote-a-more-welcoming-experience)* community support seemed strongly in favor of adding this new feature. And in the [meta-discussion of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373464/meta-on-meta-when-to-change-a-discussion-question-to-a-feature-request) consensus seems to be that the right way to handle this is to create a new meta question tagged [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), so that's what this is.

Comment: I don't have any objection to this request, mod that we cannot cost it and suchlike business concerns.  Maybe link to help center at end, where you reference it?

Comment: I don't have a strong concrete suggestion for which help center page to link to. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote is close, but not aimed at exactly the same audience. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: It's times like this where I wish I could upvote twice. So many users take downvotes as a personal attack, when really they are just a metric evaluating the post and are a necessary part of moderation. Helping users understand that will enable them to focus on how they can improve their question after getting feedback in the form of a downvote, rather than them wasting time lashing back at downvoters or otherwise focusing on the downvote instead of how they can improve the question. I really hope this feature gets implemented.

Comment: @DanielPryden I was thinking the [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or the [Tour] as they both cover crucial information needed to fix most (if not all the issues) with majority of the question. The [Tour] might be better as it is more graphical and runs you through the whole process. An alternative would be to make it conditional so if they have already read the [Tour] and achieved the badge then link them to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that way if they haven't got the badge they'll unlock it and the negative feeling of the down-vote is...

Comment: replaced by the positive reinforcement of unlocking a badge and it might be a positive incentive to fix the question.

Comment: Will this feature be only for those with the 'New contributor' badge or for all users?

Comment: I like the idea, but I remember back when I started using SO. There was answers,  comments, upvotes, downvotes and badges all coming at the same time fighting for my attention. Another thing that will distract attention from the question is probably not correct. I mean most of the times the comments do try to help, but it all happens to fast for new users. A comment says "what is x?" And the downvotes start rolling in, some answers guess, more comments about "y". And the new user has no clue to edit the question and get distracted everywhere and boom! Question on hold. Not sure about it.

Comment: Not to to mention the "possible duplicate" that links the OP away from the question. I believe the "new contributor" is a good addition, but I do also understand all the comments that it's the new users that need to learn, not the old. But in all honesty, I believe it's a little of both.

Comment: I'm not a fan of hiding the post score from the user. Otherwise, full agreement.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: I don't think *hiding* is as important as *de-emphasizing* the score. Especially for a new user, the score is somewhat superfluous to them: what matters is whether the post is "good" or "needs improvement". The score really matters much more to *other users* than to the question asker.

Comment: You already can unlock viewing the actual votes on questions and answers now, that is nothing new.

Comment: Similiar/related request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362082/help-new-users-understand-why-their-post-was-downvoted

Comment: Yes, there are some structural reasons that new users are put off. These could be addressed by SO. A related one is "closed as a duplicate." When that happens the asker is, typically, immediately connected to many good existing answers that they didn't see before. But some take it negatively.

Comment: I think this is a great idea, but I can not see them implementing it, it just institutionalizes the perception of people that *feel unwelcomed* that they really are.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea, because it will make things more clearer and lets user to stay on this site as long as possible.

Comment: why not just a big fat red "-2" in achievements ? :) congratulations. You have achieved ... nothing.

Comment: I'm torn by this - on the one hand I think it's good idea to remind new users that a downvote shouldn't be taken personally, but on the other hand I remember taking my first downvotes personally even though I had read and understood the relevant help pages.  I've been thinking lately if quality could be indicated simply by the abscence of upvotes rather than the accretion of downvotes, but I'm not sure such a scheme would actually work.

Comment: I like that this would help askers understand why they're getting downvotes, but we should be careful not to trivialise the negative feedback. In particular, downvotes *do* affect the amount of answers you get (surely downvoted questions get clicked on less by people wanting to write answers?). Let's emphasise that, rather than being *too* friendly about things. I'm with all of your suggestions, + something like "Downvotes indicate that your question may not meet the [ask] criteria, and it is less likely to receive a good answer (or be helpful to future visitors) in its current form."

Comment: Why don't we implement this as a badge. "Good job, you screwed up your question, welcome to the club. (1 Gazillion users obtained this badge before you)  Here is what you can do better: LINK"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre   Typical French humor :)  or just "Jean-Francois" humor?

Comment: Downvotes never can be a meaningful criticism of content since we don't provide a way to avoid meaningless and destructive ones.

Comment: Full Ack. I would also like to see downvotes capped at -10 or so. And stressing that they are all about the question and not at all about the poster. (Although pointing out a lack of effort e.g. a simple google search should also be part of the feedback, where applicable..)

Comment: @Andreas: I wonder if something could be implemented to prevent this onslaught. Maybe a "clarification" period where votes/answers cannot be cast, leaving time for the OP to massage their question into shape before throwing it into the deep end.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. a bit of both :)

Comment: I think it would be better to enforce a comment if you downvote a question or answer.

Comment: The problem that is encountered rather often especially with newcomers is that they react adversely to it, as can, for example, [be seen on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113684/customize-a-webpage-mainly-by-removing-some-text-and-animations-by-inserting-som?noredirect=1#comment91236798_52113684). There has been sufficient feedback on why this is a problem, but the OP instead starts complaining about newcomers being treated unfairly, etc. pp. Taking these reactions into account I get the strong feeling that some people _don't want_ to understand.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Maybe... I have noticed how I slow down slightly when I see the "new contributor". Generally you should never do two changes at once, let one settle before you do the next. The "new contributor" is new, let it settle and see what the outcome is of it then we can add another change. It has changed me, maybe that is just me, and I believe we will see a slight change in the next few months.

Comment: I unwittlingly made [the same suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386434/5101046). I'd make the boilerplate message softer. The downvote is objective and impersonal, as it should be. The message doesn't need to just restate that the downvote is negative feedback. It should be friendlier, human, and communicate the things that the downvote doesn't. In plain English, what do you want them to know? What do you want them *not* to think. Dial back the formality a little bit and just say those things.

Comment: I think a message like this would help new users a lot. But I would also suggest to force the persone who is making the first down vote to also leave a comment. This way the user will instantly get information about **WHAT** can be improved. During revision I see a lot of questions with 1-3 downvotes without even letting those people know why it's being voted down. By the way, is this still in discussion, dropped or already implemented?