# Why was my comment deleted despite it being friendly and perhaps even constructive?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments

Yesterday this question was asked: [How Do I Customize My Own Status Messages for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897673/how-do-i-customize-my-own-status-messages-for-php) Obviously the question was Too Broad, but that's not the point here.

Someone answered the question using a library that isn't tagged in the question. Which wouldn't be a problem if the library was mentioned in the answer. But it isn't. I commented the answer something like this:

> "Please do not answer questions using libraries that aren't tagged in
>   the question. If OP doesn't know about this, OP most likely doesn't
>   know about jQuery either. Let alone know how to use it."

I did not receive any feedback or warning or anything. Just the comment was deleted. It was (imo) not condescending or being unfriendly at all. I think it was even constructive as in "make sure OP knows / understands that this will not work without the library".

I don't mind my comments being deleted if there's a good reason for it, but if they are being deleted for hardly any reason at all, this clearly discourages me to even bother with making comments hoping for improvements and instead just anonymously start downvoting (which I always try to avoid if at all possible). So I'd like to understand the reason behind this, even if only to learn for the future.

Comment: That comment comes across as snarky.

Comment: I think a comment like that could easily be flagged as "no longer needed". It's not there to "ask for clarification or add more information". Its only objective is to "educate" a user on how they should use the site. We do not need to keep the that comment around, it's not helpful for future visitors to the Q&A.

Comment: @yivi I'd agree if the answer was edited with the required information to make it work for OP. Answers to questions are supposed to solve a problem. Not partly solve it. At the very least the comment would inform OP about the requirement for jQuery to make that answer work.

Comment: Answers aren't just written for the OP. I personally like seeing alternative solutions though it is helpful if the reasons for such a choice are given.

Comment: So, did you downvote the answer? As you obviously don't think the answer is useful.

Comment: @rene No I did not. To me, downvoting feels like a punishment. I very rarily do it. Like only if something is just really, really bad and simply cannot be improved at all. If something can be improved, I rather only comment so the person gets the chance to improve. And after that I even keep an eye on it to see if improvements are made. If so, delete my comment and update.

Comment: @icecub that is one way to look at it. I could argue it is a punishment for future visitors if they see a non-downvoted answer only to find out later the answer is subpar. It depends a bit for  which workflow you want to optimize for.

Comment: That voting conduct only feeds the idea that downvotes are exceptional, and therefore harsh when cast. Don't be afraid to downvote where it's due.

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: @icecub and if you review later and OP hasn't changed anything,you downvote, right?

Comment: You could have also just edited the answer to include a note like: "This answer makes use of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)."

Comment: My general rule of thumb is to try and avoid the word "please" in comments; no matter how much you follow the rulebook of being nice, it is and remains the start of a request. instead, I try to phrase comments as suggestions, not requests. "If it were me I would", "Perhaps it is better", etc. etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comment was auto-flagged by our bot who looks for possible unfriendly comments.

Then a moderator chose to delete it. Don't worry, those autoflagged comments don't count against you in the system.

Personally I don't see that as unfriendly, but trying to educate the person who answers by telling them "not to do this or that" usually doesn't work too well when the answer is downvoted at the same time. Plus the OP thinks/is sure you downvoted, now you're exposing yourself to revenge.

If in your opinion the answer is bad and can't be improved, just downvote and move on.

A comment is mostly useful if the answer is toxic/dangerous or can be improved. And in those cases, be extra nice to explain the issues.

Comment: At the time (when I posted this meta) there were no downvotes. Only 2 close votes. As I said in the comments above: I don't downvote unless it's so bad that no improvements can be made. Although that answer might not have been the best, it could quite easily be improved. Hence the comment and no downvote from my side. I do however realise that, although definitely not intended, it might come across unfriendly and I should've worded it differently. Thanks for explaining it :)

Answer (score 9):

I've a serious distaste for the kind of comments that go on forever to explain what an OP shouldn't have done. It puts you, the commenter, in some sort of all mighty wisdom position which I'm pretty sure non of us here deserves. We're not good enough.

Comments that are berating a user should not be posted and if one slips through the cracks flag, either as no longer needed or rude/abusive if there is a non-welcoming tone.

Instead, answers that are not useful should be downvoted. Remember that only once a score is below zero users with deletion privileges can start to think about deleting the really gross stuff. If you are a complainer, at a minimum down vote the post.

If you still can't hold back on commenting then what helps is expressing your amazement in the form of question:

> Did you notice the question isn't tagged jQuery? If you did, I think it is wise to include that jQuery is needed as well and how they need to setup stuff in that case to get working what they have? Maybe a link to the jQuery docs is handy then?

Something like that. At least it leaves the option open that the OP indeed overlooked that fact and comes back to rectify that. And if it turns out you made a mistake, you also have an easy way out.

With *You shouldn't have posted this*  type of comments you did short circuit any option for improvement. You only offered deletion. Not a great conversation starter.

Comment: my 2 cents: your comment suggestion is nice, but it can also be read as condescending (even if it's not) because of the "shouldn't it be wise" formulation. Maybe be more direct, avoid question like "Since the question isn't tagged jQuery, you should probably specify that - for your solution - jQuery is needed and link to the documentation"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, that is a valid point. Edited a bit.